# How should we deal with a user who uses abusive words in the "About Me" section?

Tags: support, profile-page, users, offensive

I have recently visited a [user profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3490850/) with abusive words in the "About Me" section.

I feel the language is offensive. What should be done about that?

Here is a screenshot of what I am referring to:

> [image]

Comment: Is that really *abusive* in this case though? Sure, those same words can be used in an abusive manner but this seems more like a rant than *abuse*.

Comment: The user is basically begging people to down-vote him.

Comment: Also see [Offensive profiles - where to draw the line?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/208551) on the central Meta.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you find a user profile to contain strong off-color language you can flag one of the users' posts (find an answer or a question they created), choose the 'other' flag option and explain to a moderator that you find the About Me section of the user to be offensive.

Leave it to the moderation team to handle such cases.

However, note that the About Me page is given a lot more leeway in what constitutes 'offensive' language. Anything not outright spam or illegal generally goes. It is the *one place* a user can vent, within reason.

Comment: Actually, the about-me happens to be the one place where you can swear your head off as long as you're not posting anything seriously objectionable, like racist slurs, or graphically explicit images.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yeah, I was trying to figure out how to word this best.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [doing nothing](https://youtu.be/qVO85anasrA?t=45).

A user's profile page, while public, is also personal. Some people are abrasive that way. It's part of their online identity/character. As long as that user isn't offensive when commenting or answering (and hopefully, doesn't spitefully downvote) - I believe you should just tell yourself "what an unpleasant person" and let it go.

Answer (score -10):

I fail to see how that is abusive. He's not directing it at you.

Comment: In any professional setting, which is the case on Stack Overflow, "f- off" is considered offensive, with hardly any margin for debate. So is telling people to grow up. Your answer also cues people to vote based on the user's bio, which is utterly frowned upon. I invite everyone else to flag this answer without engaging.

Comment: Don't be intimidated by that bio. I agree that f off is abusive if directed towards somebody, but it's literally in his bio, not directed towards anybody in particular. Are you guys really so offended that he used the f word??

Comment: Imagine being so sensitive that you want to ban a user for making a general statement that people who downvote him should "f off". He's basically just saying "haters f off"

Comment: You say, "Grow up."  However, IIRC, that is *not* a requirement to be a member or viewer of Stack Overflow user profiles. Do we *really* want to allow minors to see such foul language?

Comment: What minors see isn't really our decision, is it? the guidance for these scenarios is pretty clear, flag it and let a mod deal with it. In most cases I'd expect nothing at all to be done, except in cases where the CoC is being violated.

Comment: @KevinB We will have to agree to disagree. Name calling, personal attacks, and unfriendly language, are all spelled out in the code of conduct, and I expect it to be enforced here, even in user biographies.