# Should political (possibly offensive) content be allowed in user's profile?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, users, profile-page, offensive

I was reading a question and I decided to take a look to OP's profile. I found his *About Me* section expresses offensive political opinions.

According to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok) political opinions can be expressed as far as they're not offensive. I also understand that different people may have different point of view about what is offensive or not (and this will also vary according to the topic) but his text is offensive because of language and content (not because someone simply disagree). Moreover they're intentionally offensive.

This is the content I find not appropriate (from an user's profile).

> The USA is a world aggressor. USA revived fascism in Ukraine. The most of mass media and policies of USA and European Union write a lie about Russia (and they know it). European Union and most of mass media are political prostitutes: they fawn to the USA.

It's not related to programming, it's not about him, it expresses his opinion but to do it he has to insult someone else. I don't feel (too) touched about that but...I think **this is completely inappropriate for Stack Overflow** (which is not his personal blog).

**Important:** I don't want to turn this question into a discussion about politics and I don't want to express any judgment or opinion about international stuff. If you have something to say about this topic please keep focus on what's appropriate for StackOverflow  (it doesn't matter what's your political opinion). I don't care and I don't want to discuss about such things here.

---

**Edit:** I found I have to clarify why I feel this inappropriate. Because some topics are *hot*. If (on StackOverflow) I write on my profile *"FIFA is best game, PES vendor is advertising slave"* then no one will complain. If I write *"My religion is X, we have good rules and we have keys to Heaven/Valhalla. Religion Y lacks of that."* then I'll be flagged and up/downvoted because of that.

```
<rant>
```

You can't see what's wrong in such text? It doesn't matter if you agree or not with expressed opinion, what's wrong is target of his insults. Let's (try) to rewrite it:

> Obama (as his predecessors) is a world aggressor. They revived fascism in Ukraine. The most of mass media and policies of USA and European Union write a lie about Russia (and they know it). European Union politicians and most of mass media are political prostitutes: they fawn to the USA.

It expresses **same concept** (if it's what you want to express) but now it's **targeting specific people**. It's **not insulting my/our/your country** any more (which is something I care about and you *should* also do it) but he's arguing with/about PEOPLE (even if with strong words but it's not such problem because it's an important topic). If he says something interesting I may even be intrigued to know more about it. I would ask that user what he would think if I wrote something like that about HIS country.

```
</rant>
```

---

How to handle this? Or even better: do we need to handle this? In short: Should user's profile respect SO etiquette policies or rules shouldn't apply there?

As side question: there is not a *Flag* button for profiles so I posted this question on meta (even if I don't feel a public discussion will help, I fear someone will up/down vote his questions and answers for this instead of their content [that's why there isn't a link to possibly offending profile]). Is this the right way to deal with that?

---

```
<rant>
```

Official guideline (according to answers) is "ignore what's inside user's profile". I would **change that**. Politic is a sensible topic, **no need to pollute SO with hate**. Please don't talk about "country as an abstract entity". <del>One</del> Two American journalists (Foley and Sotloff) recently *paid* a high price for USA "as entity" (BTW even their killer talked directly to politicians, not to an abstract Country). Of course we can't also forget **thousands** civil people **died** (and number is still increasing) in Ukraine, IRAQ, Syria...here I'm asking **RESPECT for them.**

**KEEP THIS AWAY FROM S.O.**. Let's go to a specific forum, let's go to your favorite pub, tweet your opinion. Don't put that here unless it's an ode for innocents.

It's hilarious (in my opinion) that I can't write *"PHP sucks"* in a comment (BTW nothing against PHP) but I can write *"Country X (then you) deliberately hurts people on Country Y"* in my profile.

It's a sentence that shouts for a serious mature discussion because, at least in my country, you can express your opinion about politicians - even with strong words - but **insults to a Country** - as entity - **are a serious thing**; as you can't insult God, no matters which one, even if it seems allowed on SO's profiles.

<del>Please read this as: we're programmers. It doesn't matter where we come from because we share something else (more _pure_ than politic): knowledge. A Russian programmer may answer an Ukrainian programmer question (as a programmer from Israel should answer a question from a programmer in Palestine). You may dislike some politicians but you can't hate a Country: it's made by its citizens and the only thing you have to share with them is RESPECT (if not love).</del>

```
</rant>
```

Comment: "How to handle this?" - ignore it unless it impacts the users contributions to the site. There are so many things in user profiles which are completely inappropriate for SO (depending on your viewpoint of course!), if you'd block/remove/ban all of them the site would be losing a good percentage of its population (although that might not be a bad thing). For example, I don't think religion has any place on SO, but there are many high-rep users and even SE employees linking to religious stuff in their profiles.

Comment: Plus I do not think that people should get down-voted because of their political opinion... but looking at his rep history one can notice a fair amount of down-votes in the last days (I have no idea if they are merited, but it does look weird to me)

Comment: @I4mpi If you say something I don't agree with (about religion, politic or anything else) I may simply ignore you. If to say same thing you say my country is a bitch...I would flag you (as I would have a very serious discussion with you in real life). **You don't express your opinion, you insult someone else**. To explain with an example: if I write "Italy is great" then you may agree or not but if I write "Italy is great, XYZ sucks" then I'm talking too much...

Comment: @l4mpi there's a difference between beliefs, and posting things for the sake of trying to get a reaction out of somebody for it. For example, saying "I am a Christian" is fine, but "I am an atheist and all religions are dumb, if you are religious you are dumb" is not. Back to the original question though, this is just someone who is trying to get a reaction - and they have!

Comment: @Theolodis I agree (that's why I was in doubt about this question) and I'd delete it if moderators will say it's an acceptable behavior (it doesn't matter what you write, personal profile is personal) for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Adriano "aggressor" is not exactly an insult, at least not on the same level as using swear words. Also, I'd argue that the statement "the USA is an aggressor" is maybe hyperbolic but certainly not baseless, given the amount of wars started by them in the last few decades. And please note he does not say "All Americans suck", but says that USA (as a country/political entity) is the aggressor. Unless you identify so heavily with your country that you have to take a statement about its politics personally, I don't think it's insulting to any specific SO users.

Comment: I doubt the moderators will do anything about this. Related question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251442/how-to-deal-with-user-who-use-abusive-words-in-about-me-section

Comment: @I4mpi don't judge because you agree (somehow). Imagine he was Ukrainian and he wrote "Russia is world aggressor. Russia is trying to revive fascism in Ukraina. China and some mass media are political prostitutes: they fawn to Russia.". Opposite point of view but I'd ask same question. **I think you should keep your opinions out of SO but if you don't you shouldn't express something to instigate hate.**

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I don't agree or disagree with the specific statement as I have only a very basic idea of the involvement of the USA in the Ukraine (it's certainly not black and white either). But I simply don't see this statement as "instigating hate". E.g. as a German, you could write whatever about German _politics_, say Merkel (or her opposition) sucks, and I'd have no problem with it. I would have a problem if you would write about German _people_, e.g. saying we all are Nazis. I try to distinguish between statements against a political course, and statements against a group of people.

Comment: @Adriano, I have a crazy idea -- the most constructive way to handle this, if you insist on handling this at all, may be to gather *notable* claims matching the different points in that user's profile and ask about them on [skeptics.se]. There, they could be debunked, or not, and you could point the user to the results if what they think matters to you.

Comment: @l4mpi of course (tnx God) you can. Let me explain: change country names to X, Y and Z. We have no knowledge about them but it doesn't make such statement appropriate (and I'm not such sensible, trust me). Moreover (and let me be polemical) _some_ people are VERY sensible if you say bad about their country...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi no no...I don't really care so much about that. I just would know if it's appropriate for SO or not. If it's allowed then I'll live happy with that.

Comment: @Adriano, then I would let that pass... It's far from the worst I have seen on user profiles :)

Comment: I can't remember when was the last time I actually checked on a user profile, if I actually have done this before. What's the point?

Comment: @MelanciaUK not so much important, after all. I would know if SO policies about etiquette also applies to user's profile. If, for example, you write same paragraph as comment then it'll be flagged as offensive and deleted by moderators. I would know if same rule applies in profile.

Comment: I got why you asked, I just pointed out that such thing is not important at all (to me). As Brad Larson mentioned in his answer below, they're more concerned about avatars/names, because to see someone's profile you need to reach it. It's not exposed at a first glance with the questions/answers/comments.

Comment: @MelanciaUK now I know that! :)

Comment: I have just realised that this comment does actually insult, directly, any EU citizen with: "European Union and most of mass media are political prostitutes"

Comment: @Sammaye according to comments insults to "an abstract entity such a Country" is not a direct insult to its citizens. I don't feel so touched by such sentence but IMO an insult to EU is an insult to me too. Well if I insult Putin I suppose he (SO user) will get mad and he is right because SO it's not right place for that, even in user's profile (of course in my opinion). BTW in such paragraph "EU politicians" and "EU" are both used (therefore they're distinct entities). Politicians lie and EU (an abstract thing without citizens?) is a "political prostitute"?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: What purpose does this censorship you propose serve?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: You are proposing to censor someone's profile.  You may wish to review your dictionary's definition of "censorship"---it refers to the suppression of speech that some may find objectionable.

Comment: @tmyklebu first of all I ASKED if it's ALLOWED. If it was not then it's not censorship. You're free to join a community or not but if you do it you have to obey its rules. That said (as you can see from accepted answer) I expressed my opinion: that's the rule, I disagree (but I have to accept it if I want to say here).

Comment: Frankly speaking: you live in Country XYZ (change with your own Country). If I say that your country is someone's else political prostitute and your politicians lie (with side effect of making people's life in Country ZYX harder) then...do you feel I'm talking to you or to an abstract entity? Whatever is your opinion about that...do you think it's on-topic for SO? It's like speaking about sex inside a Church...nothing bad about sex but maybe Church isn't right place to do it (it doesn't matter if you're a believer or not). Anyway this is just my **opinion**, that's what meta is for...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I would call it: appropiate language. The language used on that profile is insultive and degrading. Imagine me calling all Americans British Prostitutes...it is the same line in fact.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti basically there is a place for that kind of stuff but a programing Q&A site might not be the best place to bring insultive and degrading political ideas to

Comment: @tmyklebu my 2 comments above should actually have been to you

Comment: @Sammaye I completely agree with you, in comments I tried somehow to be _ironic_. Politicians lie (in USA, UK, Germany, Italy and even...Russia) but that doesn't make a Country bad. Country is made of good citizens that will pay the higher price for words like that (and **innocent people who died** all around the world are the evidence we must do better, they deserve our respect).

Comment: @Sammaye: You can call it whatever you want.  However, it satisfies the definition of censorship.  There's a wide gulf between disagreeing with speech and censoring it---I don't see the point of censoring this sort of "primarily opinion-based" speech in user profiles.  And you haven't really advanced an argument to do so other than "it might offend somebody"---and that argument can apply to just about anything.

Comment: @tmyklebu removing "hi" from a question can as well, does that mean it is appropiate here?

Comment: @Sammaye: I don't follow.

Comment: @tmyklebu deleting any speech of a users can be classed as censorship, the question what differs from deleting "hi" to deleting inflamatory material? Or in fact manty edits made on this site

Comment: @tmyklebu in fact what differs from this and deleting someones answer since it isn't classed as an answer by a bunch of people? I mean this site introduces cencorship all the time

Comment: @Sammaye: Yeah, there's tons of censorship.  And it's important to call it what it is.  I just don't really see what's gained from policing this stuff; it seems like there are much bigger fish to fry.  You're of course free to judge people for what they put in their profiles.

Comment: @tmyklebu my answer goes some way, it can stop splits of the user group down political lines

Comment: @Sammaye: I don't get it, though.  Why stop people from digging their own graves?

Comment: @tmyklebu I am very politically aware and I guess because of that I take that profile particularly to heart

Comment: @tmyklebu I mean if you wanna bring politics to SO go right ahead but I'd rather leave it in social networks

Comment: @Sammaye: Nobody's stopping you from treating people with profiles you find distasteful worse than others, though.  I don't see "SO splitting along political lines" at this stage and I think the mechanism where people just won't help others who are trying to use SO as a political platform will keep that in check.

Comment: @tmyklebu I agree it is not right now but my answer speaks a little in future too, assuming this is left unchecked, which seems to be the feeling here

Comment: @tmyklebu do you really think people don't care? Do you think now an Ukrainian programmer (or maybe a Malaysian one) would answer a question of that user (seeing his profile)? That hurts SO, political hate/discussion is not for this site (as cooking recipes are off-topic). You want to write Russia is damaged by international politic in Ukraine? I may agree or not but you're welcome to write your own opinion (and your statement may even intrigue me to further investigate the topic). Anything else is garbage (the same one he criticizing).

Comment: @tmyklebu as adriano says, another consideration is those in the middle of the conflict in question right now, is it really right to bring that stuff to SO? Is this really the place for it?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: No, I'm aware that people have political opinions.  I don't see why the general rule of "if you piss off the guy who's about to do something nice for you, he might not do that nice thing" doesn't apply here and disincentivise this sort of speech in user profiles.

Comment: Excellent Meta question. I disagree that anything needs to be done, but your post argues for something you're apparently very concerned about in a reasonable and productive way.

Comment: @Sammaye: The real consideration is:  Should moderators need to police user profiles that only serve to dig those users' graves or can they do something better with their time?

Comment: @tmyklebu because SO community is HUGE and it's about programming. As Sammaye said when I want to talk about politic I go to another place. Also we should be all professionals but trolls exist. I think moderators should consider that (even if - in theory - profile should be ignored _especially_ if you disagree).

Comment: @tmyklebu I guess I will just leave it that it is bringing a conflict to our user group that shouldn't be here in the first place, personal opinion only and I respect yours and I have made my point so I'll stop badgering you :)

Comment: @tmyklebu well I think they may leave things the way they are and we'll all live happy and _free_. Or. They may set some rules too keep SO strictly about programming and we'll all live happy and _free_. ;)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Again, all this person's doing is digging his own grave.  You don't have to answer his questions.  You don't have to bake him cookies.  You don't even have to be very nice to him.  Neither does anyone else who disagrees as vehemently as you with the speech in his profile.

Comment: @tmyklebu yes I don't have to but...I will. It doesn't matter his opinion, we're sharing knowledge. I hope I can help him and I hope he'll help me in future. But it's not always so easy and someone may be really offended by that...anyway c'est la vie...

Comment: @JoshCaswell probably it's too _opinion based_ even for meta. I'm against censorship but I'm for rules to keep things decent. When, some time ago, I discussed same topic with my Russian friends...they had same idea of this user but they expressed their thinking much better than him. They never ever insulted USA or EU. Our politicians, sure, but nor our Countries...

Comment: As the "target" of this insult, it seems rather accurate to me. Naturally I find it offensive, but it isn't the act of pointing it out that is offensive, it is the actions that are taken in my name by a government that purports to represent me. If you find the mere act of pointing this out to be offensive, there are entire peer-reviewed journals in the field of foreign policy that you need to stay far, far away from.

Comment: I simply cannot wrap my mind around how anything in that quotation is "offensive" to you. You say you're "against censorship" but "for rules to keep things decent". The opinions expressed there are far from "indecent". The behavior described, perhaps, but not the expression of the opinion. As far as I can tell, you are supporting censorship here. And I find that far more disturbing. The only way in which that profile comment "disturbs the peace" is that it disturbs an inner peace, a sense of utopia about the world that is in conflict with reality. That's a peace that arguably needs disturbed.

Comment: For the records, right now the score is +18/-18. Talk about faulty lines...

Comment: @CodyGray opinions are not insulting. Language is. EU is not its politicians but it's made with it citizens. Can you spot the difference? Let's rewrite such text as _"Obama (as his predecessors) is a world aggressor. They revived fascism in Ukraine. The most of mass media and policies of USA and European Union write a lie about Russia (and they know it). European Union politicians and most of mass media are political prostitutes: they fawn to the USA."_. DO YOU **SEE** THE DIFFERENCE?

Comment: And please note I still didn't write my opinion here. Would you like to talk what RUSSIA is **also** doing there and reasons behind that? Do you want to talk what we all are doing in IRAQ too? It's not to keep my/our inner peace. This isn't just right place for that, it doesn't matter if you agree or not with such opinions. S.O. is about programming, anything else if off-topic (especially this topics), is it such bad thing? Do you think it's more appropriate to talk about politic than about, let's say, servers configuration?

Comment: It's a very primitive political propaganda. If it would be a pure nonsense, like about media lying about UFO, it could be ignored, but such propaganda is used to justify military aggression - therefore killing innocent people. I personally think that war incitement should be treated as hate speach.

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt _"...war incitement should be treated as hate speach..."_. I agree but it seems that _freedom_ to pollute even SO with such propaganda (from Russia or USA, content doesn't matter) is more important for 50% of SO users. I'm proudly on the other 50% (it's not about my opinion but where and how I'd like to _discuss_ such things)...

Comment: BTW: how can someone vote to close this question as "unclear what you're asking"? Two things (that I repeat here for clarity but you can read also in text): 1) is this kind of language/text tolerated in user's profile (because it's not tolerated anywhere else so I'm in doubt); 2) If it's not tolerated then what's right way to deal with that?

Comment: @CodyGray Apart from being called an American Prostitute which has been a delicate topic in the UK since Iraq (and Russia knows it and plays it, this comment is in fact partly in attack of that and has evolved from that) the main reason is that when SO devloves into political idealogoy you can't say "stop it, SO it not a political platform" since you endorsed the opinion to be spoken here. There is a time and place for everything, SO is not a platform for political differences I don't come here for that and this seems like the start of something frankly, better to solve the problem now...

Comment: @Sammaye yes, I have to admit I would see **official rules** instead of **personal rules** from single moderators. If I won't agree with that then I'll need to ignore profiles (whatever they'll become). I'll also hope that everyone will do it because there is always a topic we're really sensible. It's not something will make a community closer. I saw it happen too many times in normal life (with pretty smart people, Germany/Italy, France/Italy, Germany/UK, Russia/some far east ex-URSS, Russia/UK, Japan/South Korea, Taiwan/China, etc etc) so I guess it's even easier in an on-line community...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti oh yeah just look at what Twitter and any political forum has become, any sort of political ideal sharing normally ends badly with splits and horrendous consequences all round, it is better normally to just not get involved and to tell the user to share those views with people who wish to get involved

Comment: @Sammaye but you can't tell them because it's allowed to share whatever they want on their profile. LOL I'll try to ignore (according to votes here: 90% don't care, 5% would limit that, 5% wouldn't)...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti oh yeah I mean official rules are exacly that though those official rules are mostly enforced by what the community sees as right or wrong as such personal opinions, if supported enough can be enforced as rules. I guess I will just wait and see as to whether I admit I was wrong or I say "I told you so" to some of the people on this thread

Comment: @Sammaye I hope such effects won't ever be visible. Maybe with some abstruse votes analysis algorithm. Maybe because of count variation/distribution in comments flagged as "offensive". If it'll ever more visible than that then I'll worry because 1) SO users will be much more stupid or 2) situation will be much more serious than now. I hope I won't ever see any of them...

Comment: @AdamBarak I didn't even see Hamidi's comment. I don't know if it's appropriate or not to delete comments in this post. Its content is not politically correct (which maybe means "ignore ignore ignore"). Well if I can express my opinion (finally) what you said is just the truth (IMO). **Ukrainian people (~2500 so far) are paying the price for USA/EU and Russia economical interests. We should respect them much more than our governments are doing.** Maybe it's not possible, most people have to hate someone to feel right. So sad.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti it appears that comment was censored, so yeah if politics ever reaches a comment it will be censored immediately it seems

Comment: @Sammaye yes it seems so. Profile is our Baccanale and it seems most of people here needs this. We told it so all we can do is to accept it as is (even I saw users suspended for more stupid sentences in their comments)...

Comment: Censorship?!  There's a difference between a government seeking to keep citizens from saying thing and a private entity having a code of conduct.  HUGE difference.  Facebook doesn't allow pictures of breast-feeding mothers.  Poor policy?  Probably.  Censorship?  No.

Comment: The way I see it is: regardless of if it's potentially offensive or not; politics is completely irrelevant to StackOverflow. The politics stack? Sure. But not on StackOverflow. StackOverflow is supposed to be a place for sharing programming knowledge - not opinions on world events and the suchlike.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[My answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267370/19679) in the post you refer to covers publicly-visible avatars. We are significantly more accepting about what people put in their user profiles, so I wouldn't go entirely by the guidelines I lay out there.

Avatars and usernames are visible on every post a user makes, and people coming here to read programming questions and answers see them. A user profile is something you have to make a conscious decision to view. Therefore, we're more strict with the former vs. the latter.

Jaydles lays out some guidelines for user profiles in [his detailed answer to a related question on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/135615), but there aren't any hard rules on any of this. For example, people flag [Welbog's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog) all the time for being offensive, and there's no way we're wiping that work of art.

My personal rules are: does this directly insult a specific member of the site or does it include something horribly offensive of the 4chan troll variety? I'll edit that. Otherwise, I leave the profile alone. As mentioned above, we're more strict with avatars or usernames because of how visible they are on questions and answers, but profiles are hidden behind a link.

For this specific case, I see no need to remove the language you highlight.

Comment: Thank you, I have no problem with that but I was watching for an "official directive"!

Comment: BTW profile you linked it's not offensive, it's a supreme example of delicate irony sketched with vivid colors to slapping our sleeping consciences. LOL

Comment: By Welbogs profile does that mean swearing is tollerated on SE sites? I mean you can't have one rule for him but then another for everyone else

Comment: @Sammaye - As stated above, user profiles are different from general content. While we try to maintain a professional level of discourse on questions, answers, and comments, user profiles are not held to the same standard.

Comment: But hate speach should not be tolerated?

Comment: How does one flag a profile, anyway? I didn't see any mechanism by which it could be accomplished... Just flagging random posts?

Comment: That is not a "work of art" and it absolutely should be wiped. It's not even remotely amusing, the language notwithstanding, so don't hide behind that either. The fact that it gets flagged all the time is a testament to that. I can't fathom for a _second_ why moderators think that's acceptable anywhere on SO.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Would it surprise you to learn that the moderators _also_ routinely decline flags on your current avatar for being unsuitable for the site?

Comment: @JonEricson: Haha really? :D Sexists. How does one go about flagging profiles or avatars, anyway?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: People flag one of your answers. Most of the complaints are because folks have guessed you aren't the person pictured. For what it's worth, they consider it exploitive and sexist. And I can see their point. Again, these flags have been declined so far.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So the difference you are perceiving is that it is *your* avatar people are offended by? "It's not even remotely amusing. The fact that it gets flagged all the time is a testament to that. I can't fathom for a *second* why moderators do not wipe it." [TVTrope: Ironic backlash](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeCarefulWhatYouWishFor)

Comment: @Jon only on the internet could a picture of a woman be deemed "sexist". Sad, really.

Comment: @Jongware: No that's not it at all. Of course not. Why would it be? A profile "about me" section that is purely a monologue of hardcore swearing is not the same as a nice pleasing family-friendly smiley image of what [in general case could have been for all people know] an attractive female software developer saying hi to the world. Though I feel at this point - since you've not detected it - I should point out that I'm not being particularly serious on this thread. That is, I'm not actually "perceiving" anything. :)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to point out something to moderators that is not covered by canned flag reasons, or something that is not flaggable, you can flag one of that person's posts and click custom reason. Let the moderator know that it is **not** about that person's post, but about something else. Then make very clear to the moderators what is the problem. In this case, point out that you find the profile of that user offensive, and point out why you find that offensive.

In this case I disagree that this profile is offensive. This user speaks about countries as an entity, and about mass media as an entity. This user does not speak about 'every single last person in a country' or 'every single last person involved in mass media', and this user does not target specific people in either of those groups. This user has an opinion about those entities. You may not agree with that opinion, but that's why it is an opinion, not a fact. [Just let it go.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0MK7qz13bU) It is just a person that disagrees with you. [You don't have to 'correct' everyone that disagrees with you.](http://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: As I said in one comment I'd ask this question even for the opposite opinion, I just would know if it's appropriate (to know if I have to flag that in future) or to ignore it. I don't agree with second part of your answer: some people ARE very sensible if you speak about their country as entity (AFAIK also Russian people). I don't want to _correct_ him (he may even be right) but I'm surprised/disappointed to see such stuff on StackOverflow. To be honest: if I was American then I'd be upset for something like that. For the first part (how to proceed) I completely agree: it's right way to do it.

Comment: Every person is sensitive to different things. That doesn't mean it is sensible to be sensitive to certain things. Moderators should not try to police everything someone might or might not be sensitive to. In this case: In how many decisions your country makes is your opinion, your vote, decisive? Someone formed their opinion on a subset of actions a country, or entity, made. Unless you are the president, you didn't have a decisive vote in those actions. Don't be sensitive about things you do not have direct control over.

Comment: That's the part I agree with you but I also have to face the reality: some people are sensible about that. If they  feel offended and they ignore your opinion (or SO all together) then it's not such bad (but IMO should be avoided, cum grano salis). If content you provide is judged because of that then you're damaging SO. IMO (as also Theolodis noted), right or not, it happens. **We have enough holy wars about languages and operating systems...I wouldn't extend them to subtle wars about opinions. In that case I'd just keep opinions out of SO.**

Comment: If someone says that they find board games boring, can I get a mod to ban them? After all, I love them, and I find it offensive if someone doesn't love them. It's my opinion, and that person DARED to ignore my opinion. It has nothing to do with programming (why should it, it is a profile field to tell something about you). Arguably you can say that your opinion is not you, so you should not put it in an about me field. Then again, opinions and their view on the world define who a person is. -- My answer is: No. I only differ in opinion with them, regardless how sensitive that topic is to me.

Comment: Also please note that you should not have discussions with people about anything that is in their about me. You cannot comment on a profile. If you bring that discussion to a random question or answer than that is (a) not intended and (b) "too chatty". Such comments should not be posted, and should be flagged as "too chatty" as they do not in any way or form have anything to do with the question or answer.

Comment: Problem is: you **must consider the topic**. If I write _"FIFA is best, PES sucks"_ then probably no one (on Stack Overflow) will complain. If I write _"Religion X is best, religion Y sucks"_ then I'd better to change name and address (even if I'm talking about an entity, not about people). **Some topics are sensitive**, we can't help with this.

Comment: Of course I won't, such discussion may be appropriate on meta but completely off-topic on main site.

Comment: The text you find offensive never ever says "X sucks". I say we will have to agree to disagree here. I have said all I want to say.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti *"PES sucks"??!?* I'm offended. PES is the best game ever

Comment: @user000001 I'll write what I think about PES in my own profile! ;) LOL

Comment: You have got to admit that some things are very hard to let go of, especially when the conflict this post is about has claimed in excess of 2,400 lives already and has caused 100,000's to flee their homes and directly attacks a group of people over it.

Comment: I mean I would imagine a Ukrainian would not be so easy to let go...nor a Beglium cit

Comment: But hate propaganda doesn't have to say that all members of given group are lyers, thieves etc. It just uses such vague claims as in cited profile. But the aim is to arouse hate against that group, and it is unfortunately efficient. I don't think we should tolerate it here.

Comment: @Donau No; they express their view on recent events in the world. You seem to have a different view on those recent events. What makes your view on those events more true than their view. What gives you the right to censor their view in favour of your view. If there are people to blame in his view of the world, he is blaming the right people.

Comment: @Sumurai8 no, he doesn't express his view on recent events. He derogates his enemies with vague accusations.  It's the difference between expressing own views and hate speech. If I write that jquery sucks, I'm expressing my opinion. If I write that most jquery users are lazy morons that sleep with their dogs, it's a hate speech. A subtle, but important difference. Please note, I haven't said 'all', you can't even feel offended ;)

Comment: "Moron" is a term without any content other than to express that someone looks down upon something. It is different from, for example "liar" or "thief", in that these words have specific meanings: Someone is not truthful, or someone steals. The quoted user does not use empty terms such as 'moron'. The last phrase is colourful language for "they do whatever [the USA] wants". The other phrases are observations you can, or cannot agree with. You can agree or disagree with such a view or you can dismiss these observations as "shortsighted" as you find no evidence for these observations.

Comment: For the love of god: If you disagree with my viewpoint, stop bothering me in comments and write your own answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

When I wrote up my PhD thesis, I had to stay professional and broadly sensible throughout (quite hard for me...). The one exception was the  acknowledgements section at the beginning, where I could put more or less anything, up to a point: drift off topic, talk nonsense, and basically muck about. But only up to a point: I couldn't have included a personal or political rant, even there.

I would expect something similar for profiles: significantly more licence than elsewhere on the site, but not carte blanche.

Obviously determining whether something crosses the line is to a certain extent a matter of opinion; but SO already has an excellent model for dealing with that in question posting (community flagging, collaborative removal of inappropriate questions, more control for those with higher reputation). I don't see why this would be more problematic in profiles: it's not as though there's a huge number of inappropriate profiles to deal with that would eat significantly into a moderator's time.

Comment: Yes, in my POV...why not? We lack of rules (if community thinks we need them), not tools (BTW it may also be a very long process, it's not such problem, after all).

Comment: Again this comes down to not denying free speech but for certain speech to be done in the right place, SO, like a PhD thesis is not the place to spark political idealology. Like I was commented, profiles are like shirts in a library, but I if you wear a shirt that distresses individuals or disturbes the atomsphere you will fairly quickly find yourself kicked out (at least in the UK). As everyone knows political spur does not end with one profile, I am geniunely worried about over politisation of SO, might as well just do SO on Twitter in that case

Comment: I still think my T-shirt analogy is a really good one. The acknowledgements section of a thesis is another good example. I've never been to a library where they would kick you out just because you had something printed on your T-shirt, even if it was *utterly offensive*. I've never been to the UK, but from what I understand, you Europeans tend to have even more liberal interpretations of free speech, etc. than we do in the United States.

Comment: I don't have any such shirts, but I'll bet that if I walked into the university library tomorrow with a T-shirt on which a racial slur was printed, all I'd get is a bunch of dirty looks. I wouldn't get kicked out. Like with what you put in the acknowledgements section of a thesis and with a personal profile here on Stack Overflow, objectionable content just makes the *user* / *author* look bad, not the entire site. It is not a reason for you to dismiss the arguments/evidence presented in the thesis. An editor would suggest you remove it, but it wouldn't prevent you from graduating.

Answer (score -10):

What I state is my own personal opinion, it does not reference rules or official...whatever.

It is all well and good saying this is free spreech but as many will understand there is an audience for which free spreech is considered "free" or "hate".

A programming Q&A is the last place I expect to be called a political prostitute frankly and this creates the first problem.

STACKOVERFLOW IS NOT A POLITICAL DISCUSSION FORUM.

However, if you allow this profile without censorship there are three concerns:

- Creep of others doing this and politics playing a greater role in SO
- profile being discussed in answer/question comments (I have seen profile discussion in question/answer comments before now, it is not that rare, and a controversial bio like that could cause a tip)
- Material within the bio being used to discriminate against said user unwillingly.

I mean if I said: "If you wanna call me a prostitute then, f*** you, I ain't answering your questions". You may say: "Fine, free will" but think about it again, SO user base is now being split down political ideals and soon this small crack will turn into a huge crevis of...unawesomeness.

The moderators have no hope of putting out the fuse.

Now it is not because the user has stated they think the West is wrong that this could occur, more that they have actually insulted and attacked all Europeans directly. As such Europeans (such as myself) may feel obliged to defned themselves.

There are many forums this user could be pointed to post their ideals: Twitter, Facebook, Menshin and about 20 gazzilion more, but not SO, SO is a programing Q&A not a political ideal bulletin board.

I talk abut politics on Twitter all the time but I leave that stuff on Twitter, I do not bring it to SO, SO is the wrong place for it.

In my view, when you come to SO you leave that stuff on other networks, we don't care if your Russian here, we don't care what Race you are, Colour etc etc.

All we care is that you have a problem that needs solving or know how to solve another persons problem, however, this bio has a possiblity of bringing politics and discrimination based on them to our user group.

STACKOVERFLOW IS NOT THE AUDIENCE TO STATE SUCH VIEWS. WE DON'T WANT TO HEAR YOU INSULTING AND/OR DEGRADING US ANYMORE THAN YOU WANT TO HEAR ME PROVE THAT RUSSIAN MONEY IS DIRECTLY RESPONSIBLE FOR DEAD SYRIAN CHILDREN.

PLEASE DO NOT ALLOW SO TO DEVOLVE INTO THIS.

Unfortuantely to keep the peace, as we have learnt in the UK, free speech requires some...repsonsbility and threads attached (in fact this is LAW in the UK); i.e. you say what is appropiate to your audience. For example, what I said above in capitals was not appropiate and I apologise however, I had to get a point across in order to allow people to understand.

I personally see the moderators as having two choices:

- censor now before political splits start to occur in the user group
- let it fester and try and cut the buds of the poison ivy off but never go for the root.

Personally I would censor and direct the user to a political discussion forum mentioning that SO is a programming Q&A, that his bio is off topic for here effectively.

Comment: I **completely agree**. @BradLarson's anwer is still accepted one (because I was looking for an official guideline from moderators, it doesn't matter if I agree or not with that) but I share your thinking about what/how SO should be.

Comment: There's quite a lot of shouting in here for a high-rep user `;-)`.

Comment: @halfer I just sooooo angry ;) I thought abouit bolding it but I find bolding patrenising so yeah...

Comment: _/me briefly imagines Sammaye hopping up and down._

Comment: So your position is that we shouldn't have "about me" sections in the user profile, right?

Comment: @CodyGray Not really, more that you shouldn't attack other people over a conflict which has laid waste to eastern Ukraine, killed in excess of 2,400 and made 100,000's flee their homes in your bio. I mean SO isn't about that is it?

Comment: @CodyGray I could extend this a bit further and say then it is fine for me to say that USA commited war crimes when they dropped the A bombs in WW2 in my bio. If course I know from the last guy who spoke publicly in that way it results in a public apology. It is just about getting the right sensitive subject, this subject is not sensitive enough for you. But it is the same, it is attacking a certain group over politics, something I believe should remain on social networks and the like, SO should be about programming and the such, we should not draw political conflict to this site

Comment: They undoubtedly did. I'll make that claim without any apologies. There was absolutely no justification for dropping an atomic bomb on Nagasaki, that was just blatant posturing by the United States with no redeemable war aims. I'd support that being in your bio. I'd fight for your right to make that statement publically. I'd also fight for the right for you to argue the *converse*, whether I agree with it or not. This is not an "attack", it is making a political argument. I can't see anything wrong with making political arguments.

Comment: @CodyGray If this were Twitter or another social network I would not argue with you, I guess I just see this as not the audience to say such a thing

Comment: But if you are opposed to users being able to put *certain* things in their "about me" box, then we shouldn't let them put *anything* in there. The only logical solution is to remove the feature entirely. Because otherwise, who is going to be the final arbiter of what is "appropriate" and what is not? That's just a slippery slope of censorship. Do the moderators do it? Oops, what if they're all citizens of the West who want to silence the opinions of the oppressed? At any rate, the point of the "about me" box is anything goes. It is not part of the Q&A aspect. You can choose not to look at it.

Comment: @CodyGray Well I would consider attacking people as wrong on a bio on this site, that is the only place I draw the line. I mean there is a lot of difference between twitter and SE as I said, on twitter have as much fun as you like in my opinion, that site is designed for exactly that, but SO...in my view it isn't that's all

Comment: @CodyGray I guess one place I also liken this to is comments on this site, don't talk too much about the answer in comments without censorship; you should use a chat room for that, since the audience there is appropiate, it is just noise otherwise that needs to be deleted, a.k.a censored...

Comment: @CodyGray I mean you can even compare this to real life, you wouldn't go screaming and shouting into a library as if you were in a night club would you? It is the wrong place for the wrong activity, that is my personal opinion about this too

Comment: A better analogy is that you can wear any T-shirt you want into the library. The about me section is like the T-shirt you have on, this site is like the library.

Comment: @CodyGray too bad I was once thrown out of a library for wearing an explicit Nirvana shirt :)

Comment: @CodyGray you can discuss if dropping atomic bombs has military reason (even if it was the propaganda of terror to break the spirit). But it's not acceptable to write that Japanese have deserved it because (here the long list of arguments) which is what effectively Russian propaganda is doing now. 
The profile mentioned by OP doesn't try to discuss anything, it's a purely aggresive propaganda with vague claims (most are lying etc.).

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt I hope everyone can see it's propaganda (Fascism in Ukraine? Seriously??? Lies about Russia? Which lies? They know it? Of course else they were not lies. Isn't Russia lying too? Any evidence about who dictate rules and where? Any evidence at all?). BUT. It's his opinion and I don't care to discuss that. I'd just keep that discussions out from SO. Honestly from (many) answers and comments it seems that people discuss about opinions instead. I had to "clean" text as "X is world aggressor. X revived fascism in Y..." and so on. Maybe they  can be more objective

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti it is not total lies, many extremist right wing flags are now flying in part of Eastern Ukraine taken back by the Ukrainian army and they have a much bigger part in the country now but it is false that West are solely to blame, Russia makes for the perfect ground by supplying and allowing its troops to fight in rebel ranks. It was no different in Libya, disorder creates the pefect breeding grounds and if you feed that diorder it creates evil

Comment: @Sammaye I see that pretty different from "USA **revived** fascism". They'll disappear when war will disappear. Anyway yes what makes me _mad_ about that text (even if I should keep my opinion out) is that it's something I thought I may read only in schoolbooks about WWII. THEY are evil, we're are completely innocent. Damn, people die and governments are playing their "stupid" economic/political games. If we can't stop that at least I thought we can SEE that. I may "smile" if it's said by gov (or _some_ medias, I saw hat UK newspapers that painted a ridiculous image of P) but from people...

Comment: @CodyGray: _"A better analogy is that you can wear any T-shirt you want into the library"_ No you can't. If I walked into a library with a giant swastika and an Eagle plastered all over my chest I would absolutely expect to be asked to leave.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Trying to apply such a rule universally is patently absurd.  What next, take [Jack](http://www.amazon.com/Eagle-Has-Flown-Jack-Higgins/dp/1439194319) [Higgins](http://www.amazon.com/The-Eagle-Landed-Liam-Devlin/dp/0425177181) off the shelf?

Comment: @BenVoigt the problem is your trying to compare apples to oranges. That book, for one, is fiction, not a very good example of controversial and potentially insulting content. Though on another topic I notice there is actually a spelling mistake in the abstract of that book on Amazon "receivs". A better example would have been: http://www.amazon.co.uk/In-The-Shadow-Of-Sword/dp/1408700085/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top which basically denounces Islam as a fake religion. But even then you are still comparing apples to oranges

Comment: Who said a shirt containing an eagle and swastika is necessarily supportive of objectionable ideas either? One could imagine that book cover being made into a shirt, complete with reference to the book.  A library where you are simply asked to leave without considering the overall message would be crazy.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's not a "rule" — it's the freedom of other library users to react with anger towards me if they hold a strong opinion against the design of my T-shirt, coupled with the fact that a vast majority would hold a strong opinion against the design of my T-shirt. That applies itself automatically! I picked the example out of thin air so perhaps it wasn't as strong as hoped, but I can certainly imagine a scenario where I walk into a public building and encounter serious resistance to my continued presence wearing an offensive message. The point is that you can't just do whatever you want.