# How can I undelete an answer after improving its quality?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer, self-promotion

There are many questions related to Phonegap; some of these were asked quite a long time ago, but nobody answered them.

As I happen to have the domain knowledge and have found a good solution recently, so I answered these questions, and mentioned my own solution on Github.

But it was regarded as self-promotion by a moderator, and all the answers were deleted.

Now I have removed the "self-promotion" links and improved all the answers, and also notified the moderator to review.

Now I'd like to ask:

1. May I refer to my own solution or Github source code, if I am confident that I am giving the best solution so far? Or, should I just keep the question open, until others refer to my solution?
2. How long will it take to undelete or recover the improved answers?

---

The questions I answered:

- [Admob or Ad plugin for Android available for Cordova/Phonegap 3.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002524/admob-or-ad-plugin-for-android-available-for-cordova-phonegap-3-3/25419580#25419580)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650368/intel-xdk-integration-with-admob-is-it-possible/25459619#25459619
- [How to implement admob ads with Phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679896/how-to-implement-admob-ads-with-phonegap/25497761#25497761)

and 10 others:

- [Cordova admob plugin, new google play services SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236024/cordova-admob-plugin-new-google-play-services-sdk/25215077#25215077)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467822/android-phonegap-admob/25567704#25567704
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731709/phonegap-admob-ads/25578841#25578841
- [Google Play Admob integration with Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383967/google-play-admob-integration-with-phonegap/25581135#25581135)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810768/use-new-admob-phonegap-plugin-with-android-application-crash/25581414#25581414
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858885/add-new-admob-google-play-services-in-phonegap-3-4/25581455#25581455
- [Cordova - Android. Admob doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092864/cordova-android-admob-doesnt-appear/25581487#25581487)
- [PhoneGap Cordova Admob plugin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490781/phonegap-cordova-admob-plugin-not-working/25581519#25581519)
- [How to use Admob with phonegap in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595302/how-to-use-admob-with-phonegap-in-android/25581549#25581549)
- [Admob with Cordova 3 and Google play services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002424/admob-with-cordova-3-and-google-play-services/25215027#25215027)

Comment: This is still self-promotion: [`BTW, the most simple way is using a mature admob plugin, just google "cordova admob", you will get one or two.`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858885/add-new-admob-google-play-services-in-phonegap-3-4/25581455#25581455) . . . {edit} Apart "mature plugin", at a first glance answers seem to have improved, kudos for that and for coming for support.

Comment: sigh ... the question is about cordova/phonegap admob, why google "cordova admob" is self-promotioin? already avoid giving the links and let the user find the answer by google, is it recommended by stackoverflow to google before asking ...

Comment: Use your profile for all the self-promotion you want. Providing quality answers will give profile clicks and draw attention to your projects. {edit} Because your plugin is `https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro`

Comment: ok, i will remove the website in profile and self-intro ... being anonymous, is that ok ?

Comment: No! **Add** the website and all you want in your profile :)

Comment: ok, i understand what you mean, thanks for your nice explanation. :-)

Comment: i have removed "mature", and keyword "cordova admob" instruction for google, though i don't think it's a problem, but the rules really make me quite sensitive now ...

Comment: IMHO, if you're not repeating everywhere "google admob plugin", I think it's ok. . . . . I'm composing a detailed answer.

Comment: unfortunately, none of the answers are undeleted even they are all improved carefully. it seems that after answers deleted, no need to improve them again. it just wastes time.

Comment: Did you flag one of them asking for moderator attention? Please, don't abuse the flagging system, but if you send another flag, add the link to this meta so you can have mod feedback.

Comment: Yes. I have flagged 2 of them a week ago, but nothing happened. It is demotivating (i see some similar examples, see link below), but really thank you for the patient answer.

Answer (score 19):

If all/most your answers are talking about your own site/project, this is considered self-promotion. Things to consider:

- Answers with only a link are deemed low quality and are subject to community deletion.
- If the question solution is *exactly* your plugin, then it's ok to explain **why** it solves the problem. Even if briefly, explain **how** it solves the problem. And state clearly *"I'm the plugin author"*. Every other similar question that you find, you should flag as duplicate of the first one, don't repeat the same answer. Better yet, try to find the *best question* on the subject and post your answer there, remember that you'll be judged by a higher standard for using the site to talk about your product.
- Provide quality answers showing your technical knowledge of the tags in question. Don't mention your plugin. The person who asked and future visitors will click in your profile link to know better.
- And, there, in your **profile**, you can **promote everything you want** about your project. Links, images, even self-praise! Or if you like, use your profile to talk about [geopolitics or write a Bukowski poem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270347/should-users-profile-respect-so-etiquette-policies-or-censorship-shouldnt-ap) :)

This is what [the Help Center says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior):

> **Avoid overt self-promotion.**
>
> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

Regarding your edits and undeletion:

- I don't know if batch undeletions are possible. Maybe you'll have to flag one by one. Only a moderator or employee can tell.
- Make sure to check the guide [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
- Now that you are trying to improve all your posts, I'd suggest to revise your edits once again based on this feedback.

Comment: i had to google Bukowski poem, pretty cool guy

Comment: It's a reference to the profile that's always flagged mentioned in Brad Larson's answer ;)