# Post deleted by mods for "self promotion" : should I vote to "undelete" the post after complying?

Tags: support, spam, vote-to-undelete, self-promotion

I created an open-source Swift library for parsing PDF, after having faced the problem myself. I thought it would be useful to let people know about it, and so I replied to people asking for a good way to parse PDF in Swift by mentioning it.

I got flagged for self-promotion because I failed to mention the fact that I was the author of that lib. Now that I fixed the answers to add the disclaimer, should I vote to "undelete" the answers, or will the moderator do it naturally ?

EDIT: this question isn't a duplicate as I'm not asking about self-promoting. Just how to "undelete" a deleted answer.

Comment: Ideally you should also explain how you actually did it, if not include the complete code to do it, in the answer itself. Related: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: And make sure you didn't just copy/paste your answers. If the exact same answer exactly answers multiple questions, there's a good chance those questions are duplicates. We'd rather have one answer on one question with the other questions closed in that case. Otherwise, tailor your answers to the questions themselves.

Comment: Project spam isn't that much better when you mention your name.  Just don't spam, keep it in your back pocket when you happen to run into a question that *might* benefit from said library.  Most important detail is that you also mention the disadvantages of the library and compare against other solutions, then it isn't spammy anymore.

Comment: I choose to answer only question specific to "how do you parse a pdf in swift". Those questions are there because there are very very few resources for doing so. It's the reason i created the lib in the first place...

Comment: If a diamond mod deleted the answers you will not be able to undelete them.

Comment: Make sure that your answers answer the question though. The questions you answered (and that have been undeleted so far) are asking for very specific things, like the meaning of certain method or an issue about pointers. Neither of your answers address those issues.

Comment: Quite possibly a duplicate of this question: [How can I undelete an answer after improving its quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270390/how-can-i-undelete-an-answer-after-improving-its-quality)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should flag the post for moderator attention, explaining that you've fixed the problem that you feel resulted in its deletion.  They'll either undelete it, or explain to you why your edit isn't sufficient to restore the post.

Comment: But I'd also make sure those really are answers to the questions, and the question themselves are on-topic

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would it be better to flag for mod attention than voting to undelete? Obviously the mods insta-deleted it, but assuming the answer is good the reopen queue should just be able to handle undeletion right?

Comment: @Tas I believe mod-deleted posts require a mod to undelete.

Comment: @Tas how would the reopen queue play a role here? And anyway it's straightforward to show the post to a mod before doing anything (even if it were possible to undelete), since it was a mod in the first place who decided the post was spammy.

Answer (score 32):

You didn't post the answer once, but at least three times:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537203

> Here is a port of PDFKitten to swift, with some modifications to the way the string searching / content indexing is done, as well as support for truetype fonts.
>
> [GitHub link]

... to a question asking about `CGPDFScanner` callbacks. So your answer basically states *"Don't use the standard object and don't care about callbacks, use my library"* - without any explanation whatsoever how that library solves the problem at hand.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537258

> A little off-topic, but i did the exact same thing (porting PDFKitten to swift) and released the result as an open source project on github. I also did some modifications to the way the string searching / content indexing is done, as well as support for truetype fonts. You may want to look into that if you're planning on doing the same thing.
>
> [GitHub link]
>
> [Disclaimer : lib author]

... to a question about a specific piece of code, where the OP is asking how to iterate over a byte pointer pointing to a string. Not an answer to the question whatsoever.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537229

> This is a pretty intensive task. There are libs like PDFKitten which are not maintained anymore. Here is a port of PDFKitten to swift that i did, with some modifications to the way the string searching / content indexing is done, as well as support for truetype fonts.
>
> [GitHub link]
>
> [disclaimer : lib author]

... to a question asking how to get the page contents from a `CGPDFDocumentGetPage`, which apparently again is about something with pointers.

In all cases, you're just spamming a link to a library you wrote. Sure, you're proud of what you built, and probably rightfully so. But that doesn't mean that you should write a boilerplate answer and post that to even tangentially related questions.

Make sure your answer **answers the question**. None of those three answers do so. You're just pointing them to your library, without showing any code that would solve the problem at hand. Merely adding *"[Disclaimer : lib author]"* doesn't make your answer better or eligible for undeletion (even though it already happened in two out of three cases).

So no, don't vote to undelete and don't flag for moderator attention until you've made sure that your answers answer the question.

Comment: Will it be better if "author of library" posts those exact contents as comment than answer? Or will it still considered spam somehow?

Comment: No, that isn't any better. It's still unsollicited self-promotion, and doesn't help the OP any further.

Comment: Oh..Ok. But with the comments, author clearly bypass other issues (those are applicable for answer) like off-topic question, not answering the question, low quality/link only etc. And I guess, it will be hard to moderate comments. I hope SO has some way to handle this.

Comment: @AmitJoshi It's handled the same way as with posts, flags.  It happens infrequently enough that it'd just require a custom flag rather than a more specific flag.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback, i'll explain more in details why what looks like a simple function (search a pdf for text) is in fact a huge thing to accomplish. Then i'll point to the lib. Does that seem like a good idea to you ?

Also, i don't think it's unrelated at all. The three posts were made be people trying to do exactly the same thing i did (parsing a pdf). They asked a detail question because they faced a first wall while trying to do so. I'm just saving them a lot of trouble. One of them even mentionned porting PDFKitten, which is exactly what i did.

Comment: @BenG I have no doubt your library is useful, *but* just posting a link to it, even with disclaimer, is not an answer. What you could do instead, for example, is actually answer OP's question with a snippet of your code and explanations (like: "here's how I solved this specific issue in my library") - and then, in this case, you could also add a link to your library and it wouldn't be a problem.