# Several posts with my OSS contributions were bulk deleted by a moderator

Tags: discussion, support

I contribute actively to open source, and when answering questions on stackoverflow.com sometimes I'll mention projects that are hosted from [my github account](https://github.com/wimglenn/).

Eleven of these posts were bulk deleted by a moderator with the following message:

> Hello,
>
> I'm writing in reference to your Stack Overflow account:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim
>
> We noticed that a substantial proportion of your posts seem to exist only to promote your product or website. Per the help center:
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details.
>
> Any type of "astroturfing" promotion is not acceptable. It brings down the overall value of genuine recommendations for everyone on the site.
>
> If you can stay within the above guidelines, and offer questions and answers of genuine benefit to the community which happen to mention your affiliation or product in context -- and with full disclosure -- then your future contributions are welcome.
>
> As for the currently deleted posts, you can edit your posts, update them and flag for undeletion. A simple disclosure is enough.
>
> Regards,
> Stack Overflow Moderation Team

Please consider: I currently have **2,557** posts and it does not seem that 11 posts is a "substantial proportion" nor a "huge percentage" (0.43%) of those.

These deleted posts are all positively received, on-topic to the question, and at the time of writing, only [one of these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52268128/674039) even had a downvote. [This deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780018/674039) **did** mention authorship but was deleted anyway. So did [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48939268/674039).

Ironically, several of the posts accused of astroturfing had even [started out their life as answers to stackoverflow.com questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40248310/674039) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36586925/674039), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780018/674039), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41599695/674039)) and were published on github *afterwards*, having deemed to be sufficiently useful to be worth packaging and releasing.

I agree with detecting (and possibly deleting) posts that are obviously *promoting products*, however, my github account does not advertise any product, and I've earned exactly $0.00 from my open source "affiliation".

Contributing to open source is something many developers do in their spare time, for free, to try and give back to the community. Being told "*our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details*" is frankly a bit of a slap in the face. If this flagging is coming from an automated process, **could it be toned down a bit to not flag OSS stuff hosted on github?** Or perhaps actually take into account the votes on the post?

[image: cap]

Links to the deleted posts:

[Is there a way to list pip dependencies/requirements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49472328/674039)

[Splitting a Python list into a list of overlapping chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36586925/674039)

[PyYAML : Control ordering of items called by yaml.load()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257318/674039)

[python mock - patching a method without obstructing implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41599695/674039)

[How to get groups of numbers separated by commas in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49861504/674039)

[pip - Installing specific package version does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51866815/674039)

[Can pip list its binary wheels?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780018/674039)

[Python3 preparing packages for PyPi not including submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52121935/674039)

[Generate requirements.txt from uninstalled wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52649556/674039)

[Can PyYAML dump dict items in non-alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52268128/674039)

[YAML python array object order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48939268/674039)

*Note:* I've since done the manual task of editing all those posts to explicitly attribute my projects. Check the edit history to see original context.

Comment: Wim, we all know you're here for the right reasons and are a wonderful contributor to Stack Overflow. I can't imagine why on earth you got this warning.

Comment: So, you didn't have attribution/some sort of disclaimer before?  Am I reading that last statement correctly?

Comment: That's quite unwelcoming. And it's not just the inherent difference between open source vs. commercial products. None of these posts were even remotely close to link-only answers or ["excessive"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow) self-promotion. I'd argue even the lack of explicit disclosure (AKA "look at MY repo!" attention whoring) does not warrant a mass deletion.

Comment: The flagging is not coming from an automated process, users had flagged your posts, and I handled it. The Meta FAQ makes it clear that [any product commercial or otherwise should contain disclosure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57516). I did not delete the ones where you had a disclaimer. I am also not a fan of that rule stating that "no disclosure" implies spam, and I've voiced it vocally many times, but unfortunately that rule hasn't changed. Which is why I had clearly mention in the moderator message that you can flag for undeletion once you have edited the post.

Comment: @BhargavRao Are you saying this is not automated? Then what was the reason for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780018/674039) deletion and the other ones which already had attribution in them? And what's with the text about "Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details", are the moderators suggesting I should purchase ads for my open source libraries on stack exchange?! It seems like a canned message to me.

Comment: That one was my mistake, sorry about that. I undeleted it. I missed the "my package". I did leave most of the answers that already had attribution. And yes, the starting part of the message is canned.

Comment: @Daedalus  Some did, some didn't. I don't always think it's necessary. Imagine if every sqlalchemy question zzzeek answers he has to write he's the author, or every flask question davidism answers he has to mention he's the maintainer - not really relevant in open source, and can be easily discovered anyway.

Comment: @wim, if those were flagged, we have to handle it in the same way. Earlier I used to edit in the attribution in the answer myself and send just the message. But some users rolled back my edits, and those were again flagged. That's why I now delete them, and ask the users to themselves edit the post and flag for undeletion.

Comment: @BhargavRao Perhaps you could take the time to edit the auto-generated message, which starts out like: "*We noticed that a substantial proportion of your posts seem to exist only to promote your product or website.*" **It is not true, and is somewhat insulting** - I've spent years carefully curating my Q&A content on stackoverflow, ensuring it is kept current and up-to-date, and then I am accused of being a spammer and asked to buy some ads on stack exchange? wtf?

Comment: Sure, point noted. I will remove that from the future messages that I write. I know that you're a top contributor of the tag. In fact I've personally been inspired by your answers. I have sent that same canned message to several top users, and have usually received a reply to the same message stating that they had updated the answer, and I had undeleted them. I didn't feel that it was insulting, but now that you mention it I will certainly take care from the next time.

Comment: @BhargavRao  All answers are undeleted now. Thank you.

Comment: And also thank you for letting me know that the  was coming across that way! :)

Comment: @BhargavRao, you said: *if those were flagged, we have to handle it in the same way.*  Why is this true?  Does wearing a moderator hat, mean removing your judgement? Are they going to fire you as a moderator if you refuse to be a jerk to people who are very obviously positively contributing to the site?  If so, this is insanity.

Comment: @Stephen, the issue is not with the moderator hat. Meta has decided that a flag has to be handled in a particular way, which I did. I'm really sorry if you think I am a jerk. I don't like the way spam/self-promotion is handled on Stack Overflow at all. In fact, I've seen people advocate on meta several times that any link to a personal project should be flagged as spam. In my opinion, spam should be used only for posts that are obvious spam. If I had declined the flags stating this, there again would have been a meta post stating that I went against the rule, and I would have to be sorry again

Comment: It is nothing about that I’ll be fired as a moderator, and I am not that kind of a person who is so clingy that I remain silent every time. I have pointed out that the Non English chat rule on SO is also silly https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7116824#7116824, but in the end it is the consensus that counts. Sometimes even during burninations, users decide to burninate a tag which I don't like to, but I will take part in it anyway. ... I hope you get my point ... and I am again sorry if I came across as a jerk. I really did not intend to be one.

Comment: see also: [Post deleted by mods for “self promotion” : should I vote to “undelete” the post after complying?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371612/839601)

Comment: @wim, The canned message is a bit blunt. You were **not** over reacting. Those message didn't containt attribution and Mod deleted them. The hardest part is that one was going throuth your answer and flagging them as spam. By the rules the flag is "helpfull". That's the hardest part. Connecting with 3 notifications: answers deleted, rep loose, blunt canned message. I hope those hit were not too hard. I have the feelings that comunitiy is with you on this one.

Comment: @BhargavRao You're always polite and fair as far as I've seen, so don't worry about coming across as a jerk. Although the canned message was really strange (I had actually thought this was some automated process), those posts are now fixed and the damage has been undone.

Comment: @wim, thanks, that is reassuring.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the duplicate. Not only this user is on a good standing. Their answers weren't low quality copypasta. I personally don't care if you happen to make something that directly addresses the question asked. You are answering the question, darn it! You don't need to not have bias.

Comment: @Braiam I took a close look at the duplicates as well, but I ended up concluding that [Brad Larson's answer to the link that Cody added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306542/603977) was a good fit. The first link, I agree, was not the best choice.

Comment: @Braiam The question that was the linked duplicate had nothing to do with `low-quality copy-pasta`, so why do you suggest it did?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, thanks for your contributions (including these); I'm not a regular Python user but on the occasion I come across your answers they're always top-notch.

Now, this appears to be an unfortunate case, as I'm sure no one would argue you were intending to "spam" (by the letter of the definition, anyway... Bhargav's already mentioned the problem with the current definition), but luckily it's a case that was quickly rectified (and should be easily avoidable in the future); thus, a win for everyone.

However, this is the internet, so I do have a few nits to pick:

> Or perhaps actually take into account the votes on the post?

The votes on an answer are (and should be) irrelevant where disclosure of affiliation is concerned, just like they are irrelevant when closing a question that's off-topic. I'd be more concerned if the answers were just deleted with no comment from the moderator team, because they *are* good answers that contribute to the general knowledge base this site strives to be.

> my github account does not advertise any product, and I've earned exactly $0.00 from my open source "affiliation".

The rules on advertising apply to promotion *in general*; users promoting free or open-source things aren't off the hook there; it doesn't matter whether the thing you're advertising is commercial, or whether you're earning revenue from it... if you're affiliated, you *have to say so*.

All of the answers you linked (with the exception of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779616/can-pip-list-its-binary-wheels/46780018#46780018) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938664/yaml-python-array-object-order/48939268#48939268)) lacked any such explicit attribution, and thus were correctly deleted, in my opinion. While this may seem abrupt, the deletion and accompanying moderator message *did* provide for adequate recourse: edit the posts to provide the required attribution, and flag them for undeletion.

It looks like you provided these edits, and it looks like the answers were just as quickly undeleted. As a bonus, this discussion also seems to have led to Bhargav improving the canned mod message's language somewhat, so thanks for pointing out that concern!