# Accepted norm/process for handling references to offensive usernames in comments

Tags: discussion, comments, offensive, display-names

Yesterday, through some random navigation I came across a user name that was distasteful and offensive. Though the username used Latin script but was either a hindi/urdu phrase and a translation of which was obnoxious. The username I was concerned with was [HawasKaPujaari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5173426/hawaskapujaari) which translates to Worshiper of Lust. This was just an example but a bad precedence for a highly regarded site. I immediately flagged it for moderator attention and had been aptly handled and I am just grateful for the prompt response.

Looking back to various of his posts, I see various references to the same user name either as another answer to the same question, the particular user responded or as a comment. This hurts seeing a recurrent use of such filthy words scattered throughout the site every where the user had trodden.

Some examples I would like to refer to give an idea how filthy it looks once you are aware what the meaning of the particular username is

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32825635/977038
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32800580/977038

Is there a particular way of handling all such references and doing a global replacement to the default username of the user?

Comment: Hmm. At first glance, I'm not even sure the user name should have been changed in the first place. We traditionally have a *very* high threshold of offensiveness before acting on somebody's user name. "Worshiper of Lust", really doesn't sound like something that we would have censored if it had been in English (I realize cultural connotations are a tricky beast). Just how obnoxious is this? And, most importantly, who gets to decide when it affects a non-English-speaking culture?

Comment: Saying `A site as global as SO should take into consideration sensitivity across cultures` is opening a *much bigger* can of worms. Because then *anything* is potentially offensive. There are, for example, Christians here, Muslims, Atheists, and homosexuals. Any act of self-expression of any of these groups (like a user name, or a profile quote, or a gravatar) could be offensive to the others. The solution is to either shut down all such self-expression, or to allow most of it and tolerate what we don't like. As a big fan of the Americans' First Amendment I tend to lean towards the latter.

Comment: @Abhijit `How would you decide what is offensive and what not?` but that's exactly the question. What if a Muslim or Christian or Hindu decides a [Richard Dawkins quote](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/1194.Richard_Dawkins) in a user's profile is offensive? Or a sura from the Qur'an? Or a Bible verse? etc. etc.... we may have to live with *some* degree of offensiveness in order to keep the peace. What that degree is, I can't authoritatively say, either, that is the job of the community and ultimately, the site owners I suppose.

Comment: Anyway, yeah, you're right @Cupcake, that's the core question - will check whether there are any precedents

Comment: Related (but not a solution): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237199/deleted-via-flag-posts-from-users-still-can-leave-offensive-remnants

Comment: This question is distasteful and offensive, as are some comments.  I don't care if anyone else disagrees, I am right because they violate the basic tenets of my religion of free speech.  I want this nasty question removed and I don't care about what anyone else might think.

Comment: Hmm, a Western web site tends to apply Western sensibilities.  Nothing offensive about "Fidel Castro" or "Worshiper of Lust" in that neck of the woods, they are merely silly.  The moderator should not have changed the name.  But there was more wrong with this user, looks like he applied his localized sensibilities to voting.  Perfectly normal there, a grave infraction here.  Western rules applied.

Comment: @Abhijit You could drop the hyperbole if you want to be taken seriously - calling this a "very sick message" is nonsense. You think something is offensive, other people don't. Could you explain why, in your view, you're implicitly right, and others are implicitly wrong please? That part seems to be missing from your OP and comments

Comment: `you often refer back to usernames while commenting or answering so you want it or not, you end up using a phrase that you or a section of people may feel offended` that's a fair point. It's just that "worshiper of Lust", to most of us here, simply doesn't play in the same league as, say, "Kill all (insert ethnic group here)" - which would be immediately removed, and rightly so. That's also why I think your Osama/Hitler/American  comparisons don't apply - if I chose a user name that goes "All (insert country Abhjit is from) are dumb" that would also be subject to instant removal.

Comment: I'm asking you to explain why _your_ opinion of what's "offensive" overrides another individual's opinion of what's offensive. I would find the removal of a non-offensive phrase like "Worshipper of Lust" an offensive act in itself, so in the interest of fairness, I would also be able to flag your flagging of that phrase as offensive, and the action would be reversed, no? Or are you genuinely trying to say that if a single person claims that a single word or phrase is offensive, they should have the right to get it banned instantly, with no other person's input?

Comment: I also notice you didn't answer the main question I posed, maybe you can address that in your next comment? Otherwise it's hard to see this conversation going anywhere, it's just "I want this because I want it, you're all wrong"

Comment: Yeah I know what the words mean, I understand you're telling me that somewhere in the world those words in that order are supposed to be offensive - I'm asking you why that affects a globally-orientated site. Why would we discriminate against the portion of the world which does not find that phrase offensive, and will be confused when it's unilaterally removed? I'm not necessarily saying we shouldn't, but this is your question - the burden of proof is obviously on you. I personally don't cotton to "I'm offended, remove it", I want some sort of evidence that this phrase is harmful

Comment: I speak both Urdu and Hindi and I can confidently say that Abhijit's problem with this username has more to do with culture than with actual offensive degree of the username. In South Asia, any reference to sex no matter how remote is considered obscene. (Which is ironic when you know this is the region which gave the world Kamasutra). I don't think that name was offensive or obscene. Users from other regions might feel likewise and some users from south asia might agree with Abhijit's sentiments. At the end of the day, it was basically your opinion.

Comment: No, that personally wouldn't offend me, I have quite a thick skin. I can understand that would upset a number of people, of course, because the actions of <Hated Personality> will be empirically documented, and I can see that for myself. I have no literature to turn to for how the phrase "Worshipper of Lust" ever made the world a bad place for millions of people. By all means provide me with that literature, I'll cheerfully change my position. But forget all that, you're still missing (or ignoring, can't tell which) the point. Read @NSNoob's comment, that sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, I have reservations about this specific name change. A good writeup on what is tolerated in user profiles is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270347/should-political-possibly-offensive-content-be-allowed-in-users-profile).

But to answer your question:

Traditionally, searching for a specific term and mass editing it from posts is highly discouraged.

However, if a user name is so offensive that it is removed by a moderator, I suppose this *might* be a case where editing out the remaining offensive references is justified, especially when you already have editing rights (= have more than 2000 reputation).

In the case of comments, the only thing you can do is flag them, and explain the situation to a moderator.

Comment: You can't edit a comment. You can just flag it and this will end up burdening the moderators.

Comment: @Abhijit edited to cover comments.

Comment: Regarding what's allowed in usernames, [I found a few hits on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=offensive+username), including [Possibly offensive usernames](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117596/163250).