# Why was this answer to a call for questions mod-deleted as "not a question"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, moderator-election

For 10K users: [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309753/fall-2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/309766?noredirect=1#comment268607_309766).

[image]

So what's up with that? My post sports a well formed English question ending in a question mark. How is that not a question?

Given my experience with other SE moderators whose moderation behavior I did not like, this is not a fantasy question. I will vote based on what people answer. You may not care, you may not like it, you don't have to upvote it, you can even downvote it if you want other questions asked.

But can you please explain why you needed to exercise your mod powers to remove it?

Comment: I can see where your confusion lies, as it is, in all technicalities, a question. However, having seen your answer in the wild, it read a bit more like a rant (much like this question does) than a real question for the candidates. That could have something to do with it.

Comment: I don't see it as a reasonably answerable question. Clearly, the number of close votes anyone casts would be solely dependent on the number of questions they saw that they considered close-worthy. What possible benefit would a wild guess into what unknown quality and content of questions you might see in the future provide? I can't predict with any reasonable certainty how many close votes I might cast in the next week, and certainly can't predict how many I'll cast in the week after that, or after that (repeat until your fingers get tired).

Comment: Well, I removed the part where I dislike other peoples behavior and I made it an open ended question (more or less?). I really don't know how I could ask for this information anyway else. Any suggestions?

Comment: Read again what I wrote. There is no *meaningful way* to answer this question.

Comment: Or use a more concise question: `Being a moderator you will able to close questions on your own and override other community votes.  Will this change how you vote to close questions?`

Comment: @Ken I want to know if they are more careful with their close-votes, now that a single vote is irrevocably binding. Maybe that's hard to understand if you don't visit a site where basically no question is actually closed by 5 people because there's always a mod around. But I find it interesting.

Comment: @nvoigt then ask that question.

Comment: For me, it looks like a good question ....

Comment: @ryanyuyu But that question is loaded. Do you really think that if I ask "will you be more careful...", someone in his right mind would answer "no"? Your question sounds nice, if you don't mind, I will take that.

Comment: @nvoigt sure that's fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My mistake; I thought you were quoting someone else's question and commenting on it. I've edited and restored your post.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had posted the alternative suggestion already, I have deleted that one and wrapped it up in one single post.