# Can Stack Overflow's logo be changed temporarily to a Support For Paris logo?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, logo

On June 26, 2015, a user requested [the logo be changed temporarily](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow) to show support for a then-happening situation. The request was granted.

The logo was altered on many websites. A similar show of support is now happening for the victims of terrorism in France. [Many](http://www.cnn.com/2015/11/14/world/paris-attacks-tributes-irpt/) [other](http://fox8.com/2015/11/14/facebook-allowing-users-to-support-paris-with-profile-photo-filter/) [websites](https://www.youtube.com/) are showing support at this time as they did then with a temporarily altered logo. Can Stack Overflow temporarily alter its logo as well?

<s>I do not have a logo to offer, but I'm sure someone better graphic design than me could put one together quickly.</s> Thanks to [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) being so easy to use, I have created a suggested logo by using the [official flag colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_France) (though I'm sure someone else could make it better):

[image]

Comment: If SO decides to use that logo, I'd suggest reversing the color order. I think that would better match the flag's ordering, if you read them left to right.

Comment: @resueman I think you might be right. I did it based on the way the flags hung in this picture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_France#/media/File:Drapeaux_fran%C3%A7ais.jpg . . . but I realize the SO logo is "overflowing" from the bottom-up. This is not my expertise so I'm all for letting an expert decide :)

Comment: Did you *follow* that second link and see "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here."? You might also want to consider whether you have members who *support* Islamic State (or who are anti-gay). I'm neither of those two (and I'm fully disgusted at what's happened in Paris (and let's not forget Lebanon, BTW)) but there's a *reason* corporates don't always like supporting certain issues, regardless of how much individuals support it.

Comment: Keep in mind, I'm not saying this *shouldn't* be done but perhaps it may be worth allowing individuals to choose (such as with the last "hats" party). I see many people on Facebook are watermarking their profile photos with the French flag colors.

Comment: Just updating my comment on individuals watermarking their avatars, it appears some are already doing this (or more precisely, just *changing* their avatars the the couleurs français). Look for (at least) MrsEd and Undo, though there are no doubt others.

Comment: Are we then also going to change the logo whenever an attack of similar dimensions happens in Iraq, Pakistan, Kenya, or Lebanon (i.e. more or less weekly)? If not, why not?

Comment: I voted against the rainbow logo, because I think changing the logo for any such events is a sliding scale. And here I am, thinking that since the logo was changed then, it should also be changed now. Or maybe the SO staff just doesn't care as much about France as about America, which would be quite a political statement by itself.

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's irrelevant because all policital issues are completely arbitrary, there's no fairness. Either the community blindly votes on such changes or staff decides when they want to use the logo to advertize their favorite issues. Or, my personal favorite, the site votes on permanently locking itself from political influence.

Comment: I'm French. I know people in Paris that could have been hit. Hell, I also could have been in Paris if it were not for some other past event. And I wouldn't want this. I hate all the meme happening after such a terrible / disgusting / horrible event because I feel it actually hides the terrible part under a pile of unusefulness. It's Charlie all over again where people added "JeSuisCharlie" everywhere. There's a big difference between showing support and blindly changing logo, just because. If you want to show your support, organize a demonstration in your city or something.

Comment: @GolezTrol: the previous temporary logo change was not a community choice (suggested, discussed, upvoted, then implemented) but a personal decision of the site owners. Whether you agree or not, since we are guests(1) in their house, it's kind of hard to argue with that. (1) With all the criticizing on their choice of wallpaper and carpets.

Comment: Guests in their house, or freely adding value to a thriving (and profitable) community? I came here to help developers developing, not to help the site owners make political statements.

Comment: If the CEO doesn't like it, it wont happen.

Comment: That logo would be perfect for [Stack Overflow en français](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106477/stack-overflow-in-french).

Answer (score 52):

I don't agree with this.

People are free to use their profile and avatar for this purpose.

I don't think StackOverflow itself should be in the position of evaluating which events are worthy of commemorating in this manner.

Why would the French attacks be singled out but not the Sinai plane crash that killed 224 people for example?

What objective criteria could be used?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I respect your views. Do you think commemorating the previous event I referenced in my question was the correct thing to do? If so, at what point should a distinction be made between commemorating and not commemorating?

Comment: @TomDworzanski -  At the time I was quite happy with the SO decision to commemorate this event. In retrospect it was probably a mistake though precisely because the distinction between commemorating and not commemorating is impossible to draw in a way that will make everyone happy - and SO is a programming site not a political one.

Comment: _What objective criteria could be used?_ I see your point, but I am disappointed that there are not enough subjective reasons.

Comment: @TaW - Unfortunately there are many atrocities happening in the world. On the same day as the French attacks [41 people were killed in Lebanon](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-34805466) Should SO commemorate all of them?

Comment: I can't  make this judgment for you; if you think young men going into a concert and mowing down a hundred concert goers with machine gun is just the everday atrocity, then well, business as usual.

Comment: @TaW - "I can't make this judgment for you". Precisely. If you feel particularly touched by this world event feel free to put a Tricolore in your avatar. Other people may find the plight of the Yazidis more upsetting, or the incident in Kenya. Or people being blown up buying bread in Lebanon or returning from Holiday in Egypt. This is not something the Site Owners can decide for you.

Comment: The argument doesn't do it. Same could've been said for last time!

Comment: @Zizouz212 - What exactly are you proposing as a criteria for an event being commemorated (or not commemorated) in this manner then? And why does the site need to do it rather than individual users? (and yes I have come round to the point of view that last time was a mistake too as same applies there)

Comment: Little late to the party, but let me add: No matter what the community agrees on, Stack Overflow (the company) has every right to ignore the community's agreement on this matter. Same with the rainbow logo- Had the community been 100% against that logo, they still had every right to change the logo the way they did. If they choose not to here, it could be for reasons argued here (Where do we draw the line on what tragedies to support?) or it could be because they saw the last logo change was a mistake. Or it could be they just don't want to. (A lengthy way of saying I agree with this answer.)

Comment: @MartinSmith RE "SO is a programming site not a political one", I beg to differ: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand

Answer (score 16):

I agree with [Pekka 웃's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310241/can-stack-overflows-logo-be-changed-temporarily-to-a-support-for-paris-logo#comment270885_310241) and [Tunaki's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310241/can-stack-overflows-logo-be-changed-temporarily-to-a-support-for-paris-logo#comment270905_310241) on the question.

So, if there are going to be attacks anywhere else, do SO/SE have to keep changing their logo to support for that cause? That'd be really terrible/awful. Support comes from the heart (inside); no such show can equal that.

[BTW, there was an attack in Kenya (147 died in Garissa University assault) on April 2nd, 2015](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-32169080).  I am serious here; not comparing, but just wanted to convey that every such incident is terrible.

SO and others shouldn't become a platform for useless things. We all have condolences for these attacks and changing the logo and avatar doesn't do any justice. Let it be pertinent where that is required, not everywhere. Those who're doing that, it is Ok. Those who aren't, are not against that support.

Comment: Are you asking where was I personally or is that a rhetorical question? If that's a rhetorical question (for everyone), that's fine. If it's directed at me personally, I don't think it's very appropriate.

Comment: @TomDworzanski - Don't take it personally, but, my intent was to tell everybody here that justice be done for every such case, not only at a specific incident!

Comment: Okay that's fine. I just want to say I am open to your views and other views. The tragedy in Kenya was very tragic and I appreciate the point you are making. Thank you.