# (Optionally) show national flag in usercards?

Tags: feature-request, user-card

Having read recent [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440) and [blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/Developers-without-Borders-The-Global-Stack-Overflow-Network/) posts, I got to thinking how I, like the Labor Day user mentioned in the blog post, never really consider the multicultural aspect of life here on Stack Exchange - I make the assumption that the majority of users (and all those who use pseudonyms) are American (and this despite being British myself).

I believe this subconscious bias would be reduced (both here and elsewhere) if I was constantly reminded of the array of nationalities present here. I'd suggest that this should take the form of a [national flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_sovereign_state_flags) (opt-in of course) next to the username, but I'm sure others can come up with better ideas.

I'm aware there will probably be a few objections to this:

- It could lead to *more* bias towards/against questions/answers with specific nationalities rather than less.
- It's clutter that doesn't aid with Q&A.
- Some people may want a country that is not [widely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_with_limited_recognition) [recognised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_micronations) - where do we draw the line?
- Some people [will lie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/why-have-so-many-users-given-1920-as-the-year-of-birth) (partially mitigated by making it optional).
- We're already a pretty tolerant, unprejudiced bunch here - what do we need this for?
- etc.

But I thought it was worth a discussion.

*Apologies if this has been asked before, but it's really hard to search for questions about this type of flag.*

Comment: I think this would be cool to see on hover of the expanded usercard once the user hits 1k, along with a 'mind map' of their top 3 tags.

Comment: As far as where to draw the line, I think using the United Nations list of 206 world nations list is probably reasonable.

Comment: So, I'm not against it at all, and actually would myself like the feature. But for the greater good of the community... isn't that just a risk of seeing racist behavior? You say we are tolerant, but a lot of women don't expose their gender here to not get negatory remarks.... so maybe we don't look racist because it's simply hard to know someone's nationality... no?

Comment: @Patrice I second that.  Lets just stick to rep and badges.

Comment: @NathanOliver actually I personally would love it. I am always amazed at meeting people from across the world and love that. I also would like to think I am not racist at all, so I know I wouldn't act on any flag I see (besides maybe being proud when I see my homeland somewhere lol). However, I can see the potentially disruptive nature of exposing this. As much as I would enjoy this... I think the site as a whole would suffer :(.

Comment: @Patrice That's a fair question but I think we'd need to see some data before we assume the worst. Stack Overflow is very strict about enforcing its 'be nice' policy, and nothing prevents users from including their gender in their profile's 'about me' or uploading a picture of their face as their avatar. Already a user's chosen name can provide a big hint as to their nationality (or at least regionality). Any offensive comments or answers addressing that are very quickly dealt with already.

Comment: @TylerH Well considering the potential can of worms this could be and how badly a sudden inrush of racism would look for Stack, I think we are better NOT trying to get that data. Anyway, going back to my point about women hiding their genders... isn't it virtually the same thing here? Women say they are men so they don't see sexism. I can see how the parallel can be drawn between that and the risk of exposing nationality

Comment: @TylerH to address your edit. You are right that this would indeed be quickly acted upon if it ever happened, and I truly believe the community as a whole would prevent anything from escalating too far. I just see only very little benefits into exposing this, and a lot of risk

Comment: Note that this means taking a stand in political issues all over the world.  If you don't have a flag for a particular country, it could make people upset that you don't recognize it as an independant nation.  Add a flag for a country that others feel isn't an independant country, and you make lots of people upset.  Have an incorrect or out of date flag for a country and you offend people, and people get upset.  It's both a lot of work and a rather touchy subject to get involved in.

Comment: @Patrice I'm not saying *we* have to gather that data, but that you can't make the supposition that "it will end badly and in racism" without some evidence; that's fearmongering. I think the logistical argument is far more convincing than the 'potential racism' one.

Comment: @Patrice That's largely an issue because speaking in English often forces you to assume a gender, because gendered, rather than genderless pronouns, are generally used in common speech.  Nationality doesn't have that issue.  The people don't need to constantly state an assumed nationality of other users.  They may have an assumption, but they don't need to *state* it to others much at all.

Comment: Aren't there Unicode symbols for flags? Users could append these to their user name if they wanted to do so.

Comment: @Servy As a French native, you made me giggle with English being gendered (I know it's true... but yeah, not as much as French is). You are 100% right there. There is definitely that difference. But if people choose to expose a different gender via pronouns (or whatever) to avoid some of the frak that comes with stating your gender, I don't think assuming a similar reaction will happen with nationality is far-fetched.

Comment: @Patrice I'm aware that other languages use gender in speech to a greater degree than English, but as SO is English only, I stuck to that.  How do you think a similar problem is going to happen with nationality?  Where do you see people stating an assumed nationality on the site?  I very rarely see people assuming someone's nationality in general?  I've only seen it a few times, and they were entirely off topic, not things that would be avoided if a flag was in a profile.

Comment: @Servy (yeah, the comment about gendered language was more of an editorial, not a point I was trying to make :P. You are entirely correct there) what I meant there is that, if I look at what is happening with people wanting to hide their gender to prevent frak is just that there is that risk. Currently we see no racism because, as you say, it's hard to assume someone's nationality. If we go with this proposal, we won't have to assume anymore. I just see the risk between both things. Considering the slim benefit I can see in these flags, I don't think that outweighs the risk.

Comment: Who's interested in some user's nationality? If something, the time zone would sometimes be useful to know.

Comment: I mean there is a location option on the user's profile so you could add it as an option you can add your nation's flag so you don't have to say if you don't want to for me, I think it would be cool for myself but not necessary and wouldn't complain if it was not added.

Comment: Remember that feature request about being able to block users based on location?

Answer (score 8):

The location field is just text, so it would be really quirky trying to accurately pair it with a country flag if the user provided the information. It is *much* easier to account for all possible locations folks might want to list by leaving it freeform text.

Folks can include it if they want in their fly-out user card ([visible for users that have over 1k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)), but both the standard and expanded user cards are *really* tight on space, so if we're going to cram more in there somehow, it probably has to be more future related than informational.

It's not a bad idea, it's just touching two rather tricky places at once :)

Comment: I agree that using the existing location field to decide on a country is a bad idea. If this were to be done (and it's sounding a lot like it won't), it'd need to be a new field, selected from a list. This also helps to keep it opt-in.

Comment: also if the flag was only gotten from the location, this could cause issues if the user's didn't associate with that nationality

Answer (score 6):

I think having this information in a user card would cause more problems than it's worth.  Stack Overflow is focused on getting good answers to questions.  Having more obvious national boundaries can only get in the way of answering a question.  It's distracting and irrelevant.  The typical user interaction simply does not need national identity at all, especially if we truly trying to be a programming community without borders.

Sure, many people include this kind of information in their profile, and certain usernames or styles of English suggest areas of origin.  But I think adding something as evocative as a national flag next to an actual post puts too much emphasis on national pride.  On Stack Overflow, we should be citizens of this community first.

Answer (score 4):

First, if you hover over a user's avatar you see a popup user card, which contains their location in text.  So this information is already available and, if not first class, really close to first class - you don't have to click anything to find out a person's nationality or location if they make it known. True, location doesn't always provide nationality, but they are so closely related that it's not worth separating the two for the purposes of this service.

Secondly, Stack Overflow already provides many ways for users to display something important to them through their user name and avatar.

Unicode is starting to include flags as characters.  If a user desires to show their nationality as part of their user name they can use a unicode character in their username.  They also have the option of simply using a dash and the name of their country.

The avatar is also free form and undefined, and they can use it to freely display nationalist symbols if they desire.

Encouraging users to do this may lead to divisions and factions - and not merely political ones, for instance during worldwide sporting events users may, consciously or not, allow their team affiliation, or that of their rivals, to affect their posts based on the flag that showing.

In short, this is something that is already well supported for those who wish to make it known, and encouraging it would present problems that aren't outweighed by the possible benefits.

Comment: For instance, here's the US unicode flag:  which displays as characters on most browsers, but displays as a US flag on many mobile devices. It's not ideal, but as systems adopt these users will be able to display flags or similar nationalist symbols as part of their username as first-class information.