# Someone just deleted their answers and ragequit over the navbar redesign. Can we make sure we undelete their answers?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

In the comments at http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation, *AndryDude* claims to have ragequit after deleting their top answers:

[image: Screenshot of ragequit]

Assuming that no automatic system will have caught this (which might be false), can a member of staff find out who this user was (via IP logs or something) and undo this act of vandalism?

Comment: *sigh*. Of all the things to throw a tantrum over. If they are really killing their posts, us mods will get an auto-flag.

Comment: Currently, I see no evidence of anyone actually doing this, so this may just be a troll post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters would deletion of a small number of top answers (what it sounds like) be autoflagged / detectable via whatever means you just used to check? A troll post seems like an entirely possible explanation, but not necessarily the true one.

Comment: Yes, we get auto-flags for as few as 2 posts deleted, depending on the exact circumstances.

Comment: Seems the mis-spelling of his name got this on the wrong foot.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Look on the bright side - at least it's a change from a certain politically charged meta post...

Comment: Of all the things to rage quit over indeed... There is a point to it though. Is it really super-important for SO to re-design things of very peripheral significance, such as the top bar. To me, it just stinks of "oh we must follow the hype fashion and use ugly, user-unfriendly, one-dimensional, monochrome icons, because everyone else is doing that too!" Everywhere I go, devs seem to be fanatic about shittifying their icons in this manner just to follow fashion, turning their UI far worse. Looking at these new icons, I can only tell what 2 out of 4 do. "Click ugly grey blob to see what it does"

Comment: @Lundin: please do read the [blog post on why the design was changed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/). This isn't a fashion fad change.

Comment: @MartijnPieters although the reality the blog post reveals is worse than a mere fashion change. Given that the objective of the change is *explicitly* opposed to the goals and preferences expressed by users in their testing group - anonymous users said that they ignored the navbar because they were only here to read content, and the designers responded by deliberately making the navbar intrude on users' reading experience so that it would be harder to ignore - it's not difficult to understand it annoying users. It certainly annoyed me.

Comment: @MarkAmery: yet the *behaviour change* shows otherwise. But we are digressing, this is OT for this post.

Comment: @Lundin: Drop the hyperbole and attacks and people might listen to your feedback. I certainly can't right now. If you want to vent unconstructively, do so somewhere else.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I believed that meta was a forum for constructive feedback, I would give it. All such delusions died [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This appears to be a troll post.

Normally, moderators are alerted when someone deletes a number of their posts (or vandalises a series of their posts). I've not seen any evidence of anyone actually doing what "AndryDude" is claiming to be doing however.

But if someone really was doing this, rest assured that we do undelete posts in such cases (as well as suspend accounts temporarily if necessary to limit the damage that needs repairing).

Comment: Additionally: There are also a couple of bots that report this kind of vandalism. Cases like these usually get handled rather quickly. (Like @Machavity just linked ;-) )

Comment: SmokeDetector will generally [catch self-vandalism](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35675648#35675648) and it gets rolled back

Comment: @Machavity Smoky doesn't catch deletions ... and the vandalism rollback is still a manual operation.