# How should we handle deleted users with intentionally destroyed questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-users, vandalism

I was working with some data from the SEDE and happened to notice that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70534950/11659881) was edited by the OP to contain just the text

> EDITEDITEDITEDITEDITEDITEDITEDIT

I've now rolled back the question to the previous version, but I can see this user is deleted and I suspect that they may have similarly destroyed any other questions that they may have asked. Is there any appropriate action that I should take in this scenario? If I could access the user's profile I would just quickly look at their questions and rollback edits as necessary, but in this case, because the user is deleted I would need to notify a moderator to investigate, but I'm unsure how to do that. Flagging the original question and saying "look at other questions" feels like it would just be rejected / would waste the moderators' time, but I can't think of an alternative.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [How should we treat posts that are vandalized by their original authors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106807/348196)

Comment: DIY https://www.bing.com/search?q=user13418565%20site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Somewhat related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343902 The answer there suggests that multiple instances of vandalism will alert moderators automatically, although it's best not to rely on things like automatic flags being raised. As mentioned in Henry's answer, if you see something problematic that only a mod can handle, go ahead and raise a flag.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "vandalizing" the post. It's an unseemly edit, for sure, but it isn't "vandalism". Many people add "**edit:**" to posts; this seems like no more than an inopportune choice of emphasis mechanism.

Comment: @einpoklum See the linked question. It didn't *add* "edit" to the post, it *replaced* the post entirely with the word "edit" repeated multiple times. That's definitely vandalism.

Comment: Would it be useful to use SEDE to look for questions that were edited by OP after an answer was accepted?

Comment: @cigien interesting is it vandalism if it belongs to you? If I build a house then crashed it down is it vandalism ?? To me, it looks like the OP wanted to delete the Q because it's embarrassing for him to get 4 down votes this is typical SOF toxic community behaviors or am I readying too much into it?

Comment: @ShifraSec Yes, in this platform there _is_ such a thing as [self vandalism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372007/should-we-say-vandalizing-to-refer-to-defaced-content). All posts are licensed to the site, so even if you posted them, Stack Overflow has the right to keep the version before it was defaced. There is nothing toxic in that, although a lot could be said about people equating downvotes with toxicity.

Comment: @E_net4-MrDownvoter "There is nothing toxic in that" not in the vandalism yeah I was talking about down-voting a Q because to you it seems only for beginners indeed I see that as gatekeeping but I guess we see things from different lenses.
Nice Username btw seems fitting for this community.

Comment: @ShifraSec Notably as well, everyone has access to the revision history, so editing the question still means the older version is accessible to anyone who actually views it.

Comment: @Kraigolas yeah this is what I was thinking, it's not trying to ruin the community but someone who got down voted for asking a basic python pandas Q and felt embarrassed for it. What I'm saying I don't think this is out of malice. The fact he doesn't know about revision history further proof it's a beginner.

Comment: @ShifraSec Please read [what exactly amounts to being nice to new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379704/what-really-amounts-to-be-nice-to-new-contributors). Your hint that users should hold their votes to content posted by new users is detrimental to the site and does not do the beginner any favors in the long run. Don't get the impression that new users are at a natural disadvantage, veterans also receive downvotes in their posts. By the way, your comment about my display name says more about you than it says about me or the community.

Comment: @ShifraSec Yes, it's vandalism. No one is claiming that it's malicious though, I'm sure the user just doesn't know the site rules. Also, this is covered above, but posts don't really belong to a user as much as they belong to the site. To use your analogy, a post is more like building a public park for your neigbourhood, rather than building your own home. Pulling down the park would be vandalism, at least more so than pulling down your own home.

Comment: @cigien yeah that analogy makes more sense to this situation

Comment: @ShifraSec first off: there is nothing toxic about gatekeeping in general, and in fact gatekeeping is *essential* to building anything of value whatsoever. In my experience, prominent public opponents of "gatekeeping" universally are happy to gatekeep the hell out of their own communities, and are usually motivated by some weird identity-politics agenda (i.e., ultimately trying to imply that someone else's "gatekeeping" is a manifestation of bigotry, but their own "moderation" is putting them on the right side of history).

Comment: Second: it is important to understand that it is **not part of Stack Overflow's mandate** to help the asker to solve the problem that originally motivated the question. That's only a side effect. We care about **the question**, and **the code**. We downvote **the question** (not the user) because it does not meet our standards. It **does not matter** to us who asks the question; *only the quality of the question matters*. We want the question to be as good as possible - because *answer quality directly depends on question quality*, and because we are trying to *build a reference library*.

Comment: For more information, see [any of the countless previous questions on the theme](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvote+beginner).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "there is nothing toxic about gatekeeping in genera" but are we talking in-general?? No we have a specific case on hand; on a site that should answer Q but because certain people believe a Q is too easy and not worthy to be asked they result to gatekeeping, how does that exactly build more value? That's an interesting way to look at think I guess

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "We downvote the question (not the user)" when did I imply anything other than that? I have been saying it that from the beginning go back and read my comments. Down voting something cuz you believe that it's so easy and shouldn't even be asked as an experienced in a topic is gatekeeping newcomers I fail to exactly see how that help improve the site over all? if many people with wrote articles and made videos many in-which are respected seniors have similar opinion to mine again I'm helpless to see how your view is for the best of this site.

Comment: "when did I imply anything other than that?" That is the effect of continuing to insist that "gatekeeping newcomers" is a problem *because they are newcomers*. It's also the effect of phrasing it like that. Just as we are downvoting questions, not users - we are gatekeeping content, not users.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> Flagging the original question and saying "look at other questions" feels like it would just be rejected / would waste the moderators' time, but I can't think of an alternative.

I disagree. Cases where regular users do not have access to the information to be able to handle the situation is what mod flags are *supposed* to be used for.

Normal users cannot reasonably<sup>1</sup> track down other posts by this deleted user. Mods have access to the list of posts created by the deleted account.

When flagging things that normal users (with various privilege levels) might normally handle themselves, it is important to make it clear *why* this needs to be handled by a mod. But I would be *very* surprised if a mod declined a flag along the lines of:

> This user [vandalised their post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70534950/2) and it was not caught or fixed until [I rolled it back](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70534950/3) just now. Since this user has been deleted, I cannot see if there are any other cases where they vandalised their posts before the account was deleted. Would you please take a look and see if any of their other posts need to be rolled back?

---

<sup>1</sup> Through the stock Stack Overflow UI. There are several ways to find these posts through alternative means, but I don't find that mods *expect* users to use alternative means (like SEDE) to solve these problems.

Comment: *"(I believe) mods have access to the list of posts created by the deleted account."* I confirm that this statement is correct.  It's a bit manual without [scripts](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md#deleted-users-helper-), but we can view posts by a deleted account via (for example) https://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts-by-deleted-user/13418565.

Comment: In this case, just to head off anyone taking your good advice for this specific account, they have three additional questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67664920), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67501134) - self-deleted, [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61843611)), none of which have been similarly vandalized.

Comment: Re *"...track down other posts by this deleted user"*: For mere mortals, older versions of [the data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-dump/info) contain (some of) the information. The version just before the user  account was deleted (probably) contains the most information. This requires some foresight, though. And sufficient bandwidth and sufficient high monthly caps (if any).

Comment: A [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1618196?OwnerDisplayName=user13418565) for accounts without a User Id and a matching display name works fairly well. It depends what information is needed.

Comment: @HenryEcker I modified your query to search for unclosed, undeleted questions by deleted users over the past year and couldn't find any other examples, so this seems to be a rare occurrence.