# Can't access this website from Syria any more, recent issue

Tags: support

The website used to be accessible before, but in the last couple of days I'm no longer able to visit *stackoverflow.com* without using VPN.

I noticed the issue about three days ago (along with the visual changes). I started getting `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` and some random `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` every once in a while.

On both my Android phone and my PC.

#### My Question is:

Was this caused by a change done intentionally (maybe as a part of a new policy)?

Are we welcomed to use the website or are we at risk of losing our accounts and/or get blocked?

Comment: I doubt that Stack Overflow would be blocking the request, it is possible that your ISP is the issue.

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` that's a firewall blocking it. Your ISP is actively blocking Stack Overflow (and probably the rest of Stack Exchange). You might be able to get around it by changing your DNS servers.

Comment: I'm using Google DNS, I use VPN at first but then found out using https solved the issue. Our ISP offer no support when it comes to blocking and monitering, sadly

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I am an employee of Stack Overflow and can say that we do not block Syria or any other country unless they pose a technical threat or abuse to the millions of other developers who use our sites.

You may want to check with your providers to see if there are any blocks upstream of your connection.

Bottom line, you are welcome here!

Comment: And from what I can see in the moderator tools, it doesn't look like any of the Syrian IPs they came from recently have been subject to spam or trolling blocks.

Comment: our ISP is controlled by the government and IS known to block certain words and websites. an example is the word "proxy", if it's present in a page then we get an empty response. I just don't know what caused the recent change! I just tried using https and it worked. so it must be interrupted by ISP I guess. thank you so much.

Answer (score 15):

Trust me<sup>1</sup>, The people who run Stack Overflow would not block Syrians from the site.  In fact [they were very upset about a block of immigration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) that was put in place.

Not sure where this issue is in the chain from your place to the SO servers but Stack Overflow is not the culprit (well unless there is some weird bug or you were IP banned for bad behavior).

> are we welcomed to use the website or are we at risk of losing our accounts and/or get blocked?

Yes you welcome to be here as long as you follow the site [polices](https://stackoverflow.com/help).  That basically boils down to [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and don't be a [spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)/[plagiarizer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

<sup>1. I am not an employee of Stack Overflow</sup>

Comment: I'm always fascinated by the community here but thought they had to do it due to some legal complications. it seems many services had to deny us access to comply with US sanctions and laws. thank you for the answer.

Comment: @MaherFattouh FWIW, one of the reasons we're rolling out `https://` to all sites in the network is to address issues like this. It's not the main driving force, but it's a definite win. Expect Stack Overflow to go default `https://` in the next few weeks.