# User level upgrade! High level's shouldn't answer all easy questions!

Tags: feature-request, new-users, users

I would love it if high reputation users were blocked from answering low reputation users questions. At least for a period of time, then if it remained unsolved a high rep could step in with an answer. With their knowledge and typing skills its extremely easy for them to type a nice answer and gain more reputation faster than low rep users can (from my perspective).

I use this site to attempt answering questions so I can learn something new. It's difficult to research (look up certain methods, etc) and answer questions fast enough before 1-2 people chime in with an answer off the top of their head :-/

All I ask for is a simple time delay on anyone over a certain reputation. Or possibly a limit on answering questions over 1000 reputation below you or something.

I love this site and appreciate everyone's willingness to answer questions. I just want a piece of the pie. I wan't to help and learn! I'm trying, but apparently not hard enough? Is anyone else feeling this?

Comment: How does reputation determine typing speed and knowledge?

Comment: It was generalization. I only know what I see, and when I'm working on solving someones problem (that I know I can solve) 2 answers are posted before mine. That's how this site works is it not? You are rewarded for your knowledge?

Comment: Then maybe you should get quicker? Why does everyone else have to slow down?

Comment: Tiny Giant chill. Just wanted to give new comers a chance and a decent start. It's discouraging to be on this site with such great coders

Comment: But you're asking us to remove the competition part of the game. That's one of the main parts, beside questions and answers.

Comment: Is this site meant to be a competition? It just seems to me, that's what it became. Not what it was meant to be.

Comment: In [the Forth tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forth) you have plenty of time to answer. Use [the RSS feed](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=forth&sort=newest) to discover new questions sufficiently early.

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[Six simple tips to get reputation fast on any Stack Exchange site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204)*

Comment: Why does a site like this have to be so discouraging? Are there too many coders in this world?

Comment: @gnat. I think this topic deserves a revisit every once and again. Trump is president now after all.

Comment: Let's assume that higher reputation users have 'more knowledge' and 'type faster' (that's absolutely not the case). But if we assume that, you're basically saying you're happy with less knowledgeable users posting incorrect answers creating a blind leading the blind situation, merely so you can get a little bit more reputation?

Comment: [Time to take a stand?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342440/839601) :)

Comment: @Rob. You are saying on average high rep users have less knowledge and type code slower? I kindly disagree..... Like I said it would only be a time limit thing for high rep users. (Or time limit for high reputation difference). When the timer runs out higher rep user may post a better answer or address some things the lower were wrong about. Everyone wins

Comment: Most importantly, the point of the site is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers. This would hurt that aim, by preventing people from giving great answers at a time that is convenient to them.

Comment: @Klynicol Everyone wins except for SO, which is designed to create a repository of knowledge and high quality answers to solutions.

Comment: @Jon that was a typo on my part. read it again

Comment: @Klynicol: I've removed my response to that part - but I'd say that editing a comment to have the precise *opposite* effect to make it look like responders aren't reading properly is pretty rude. This idea still works against the primary goal of the site though: providing high quality answers to high quality questions.

Comment: You have a point

Comment: @Jon a typo is a typo, I only fixed it when I saw it

Comment: I understand the motivation, but as others have pointed out, this would have awful consequences for askers and the community in general. It's no fun asking a question and then seeing those *most likely to answer it well* being blocked from answering it.

Comment: Recommended reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Bergeron

Comment: @Pekka :) I'm reading slaughterhouse 5 right now

Comment: @pekka. You're right, I'm now realizing that. Back to the drawing board. There must be a way to involve new comers!

Comment: @Klynicol yeah. It's never wrong to think about ways how to make things work better for them.

Comment: @Klynicol: A typo is a typo, but when it's already been responded to, it's better to leave it as it is, IMO and just add a comment afterwards. In this case I was able to edit my comment that had become a non-sequitur, but only because I *happened* to be around. I wouldn't mention it, but it affects how questions are asked as well - far too often people ask a question, then when it's been answered they change it in a way that invalidates answers.

Comment: @Jon I was in the middle of editing when I saw your comment pop. As I said, I'm not a fast typer. Many apologies

Comment: We all start with 1 rep and have to gain rep in the same way. I disagree that we should impose a restriction on allowing higher reps to post an answer, after all they know what the site is about and often create very solid answers. I also don't look at higher reps as competition. When you've been around a bit longer you'll see that often these people are here to help. Also once you get a few solid answers in, you have a base to use that code again and it can come in handy when answering similar questions.

Comment: Is this proposition just a way to stop Jon from being able to answer altogether so someone can FINALLY catch up? ;)

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure; it is a Q&A site, so you sure will find [the fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) people. IMO, you can find your niche in which you can answer comfortably, and you will gradually be able to answer quickly. There is [an unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) tab too in every tag if you want to fill your part.

Make yourself comfortable with [Markdown](http://www.markdowntutorial.com/) too.

Comment: My interest right now is PHP. You're right, I could step away from this site, get better at PHP and come back in a few months and start answering questions. That keeps me away from this site, thus not contributing or driving traffic..... What I'm proposing would not hurt any high reputation users there are plenty of difficult questions that need answering, they could focus their energy on making the knowledge database even stronger instead of needlessly getting more internet points for themselves

Comment: Lets be honest, most questions are duplicates (to an extent) and high rep peoples might have answered the same question (or extremely similar ones) many times over.

Comment: First currently not every high rep user gain rep by answering question every minute there many high rep user who are gaining rep by their highly viewed answer and as you said you are interested in php there are at least 150-200 questions asked per day there is still very high chance you can answer a question which might get upvoted.

Comment: @Klynicol: Questions that *are* duplicates should be closed instead of answered. Yes, I'm sure many of us have inadvertently answered duplicates instead of closing them, but that doesn't mean that's a *good* thing.