# Why are comments closed on the latest blog post?

Tags: discussion, blog

The [latest blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/04/3-ways-can-ally-women-tech/?cb=1) has comments disabled/closed.

Just curious as to if this is on purpose or an accident.

[image: blog]

Comment: As a moderator, looking at this question title, my first thought was "need you even ask?" Which just makes it all the more sad.

Comment: @BoltClock That seems like circular logic. "There is a problem with women in tech. See? The comments are closed on an article about women in tech! That proves it!"

Comment: @Houseman: It's just that anyone even remotely familiar with the topic should be able to connect the dots immediately when they notice that comments to an article about the topic are closed. Kaitlin's answer - and the ensuing discussion under her answer - only solidifies this.

Comment: @BoltClock The dots can be connected in different ways. Your 2 comments could've been made word for word(except 'As a moderator') by [@Philip Kirkbride](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357455/1398418).

Comment: @BoltClock To Oleg's point, the obvious answer _for me_ was that there's misleading points that the author doesn't want the comments to make obvious.  One of them, that I pointed out in a comment on an apparently-deleted answer here, was trivial to find:  The linked source doesn't say what the blog post claims, even though that claim is the basis for a full paragraph.

Comment: @Izkata: Ah, I see where you and Oleg are coming from. By the way, that answer was self-deleted. My guess is the author decided their opinion wasn't worth keeping around. Which of course isn't true, but as much as I'd like to see it stay up I'm going to respect their decision and leave it deleted.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This was on purpose (I personally closed them).

We were already receiving abusive comments on Twitter about this post, and I didn't want to deal with that on our own platform.

This follows a familiar pattern for us: when we've written about women in tech before, however benign, we get flooded with abusive comments. Not only is that unfortunate in and of itself, it also means that otherwise constructive, thoughtful comments get lumped in and thrown out with the abuse.

Comment: oh wow, okay :(

Comment: I understand the trouble of having to deal with abusive comments, but I find it rather useless to post a blog and disallow discussion by the readers.

Comment: @Stijn You're more than welcome to start a discussion on Meta as a new question thread.

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things :-(

Comment: @Stijn: "*I find it rather useless to post a blog and disallow discussion by the readers.*" Do you really go to blogs for the comments section?

Comment: @NicolBolas The blog post itself is the main reason of course, but sometimes the comment section has quite useful/interesting content, so I tend to read it.

Comment: Stackoverflow's unwillingness to allow open dialogue is not good

Comment: @JamesWierzba - You're posting on the site where Stack Overflow hosts more open dialogue about themselves and their policies than most sites out there. You have plenty of places to make your voice heard.

Comment: I assumed this was the reason. I'm sad to hear that confirmed. I'm upvoting this because I support your decision to close them.

Comment: I'm all for open dialogue, but I don't blame you. I read the replies on Twitter, and some of them are just bizarre.

Comment: You could give yourself a male avatar picture and male alias and nobody would notice. Many males go as women in the web and for emancipation reasons the opposite should also be true. ... If not, there must be some law that forces women to do so - otherwise equality is broken !!!1!!!11!eleven

Comment: Abusive or just argumentative?

Comment: I take issue with the implicit assumption in the article that a disparity of *outcome* is the problem for which "it’s clear that there’s work to be done."  Is there also work to be done to "handle" the gender disparity in the construction industry?  Or the teaching profession?  Or the race disparity in professional basketball?  **I agree there IS work to be done,** but the work to be done is to handle **prejudice and bigotry** in its many forms—NOT *just* to get women a lot of jobs in STEM fields. I'm not talking about under-representation, I'm talking about *bigotry.* I've seen it. It's ugly.

Comment: In my opinion, this is why the blog should allow only SO user comments, as opposed to allowing trollish content there. It is unfortunate that we as a community cannot voice support on the blog while anyone who wants to open an oauth account can post vitriol.

Comment: What on earth does basketball have to do with women in tech? That's whataboutism in practice. It's perfectly possible to write about **one** problem without having to simultaneously mention every other perceived problem.

Comment: @ivarni It's not, race disparity in professional basketball is **not** a problem and nobody perceives it as such. It's brought up to illustrate that lack of women in tech is also not necessary a problem and might be caused by sexual dimorphism. So in fact it's the opposite of whataboutism.

Comment: @Oleg - Are you trying to state that women are biologically incapable of being developers? That seems to be the indication when you draw the distinction that it isn't disparate because of any other factor other than the fact that they are biologically different than men. Which is true, they are like a zepto percent different, but there is no reason to think that difference is in favor one way or the other.

Comment: @TravisJ No, all I said is that there are differences between men and women and when you see a difference in outcome the most likely explanation is that it's caused by those differences. Your interpretation that it has anything to do with what women are capable of only shows your personal hidden beliefs and if you think men and women are zepto percent different an elementary school biology class is in order.

Comment: @Oleg - So, since you can identify one difference between two groups, that one difference must then be the source of all other different outcomes? That is absurd. Moreover, while there may be a difference in physical properties, the ability to develop has nothing to do with muscle structure, bone structure, or reproductive organs (which is where nearly all of the 1.5% difference arises). People are more than just your visual interpretation of them.

Comment: @TravisJ No, there are countless identifiable differences. And once again the only one who said anything about ability to develop is you. You keep bringing it up so I'm starting to think that you really think women can't develop. You should try to discover your hidden biases and work to overcome them. Misogyny is really a terrible thing.

Comment: @Oleg - I don't think that flipping this around is really working for you. Did you misspeak when you stated that a lack of women in tech "might be caused by sexual dimorphism"? From my personal standpoint, which you can find in other places here as well, I think women are entirely capable of developing software or technology or *anything* else as good or better than *anyone* else. Creating software or technology isn't limited to any group of people.

Comment: @TravisJ I beg to differ, I'm quite pleased with how this is working so far. What made you think that when I mentioned sexual dimorphism I meant capabilities? The only reason I see is that it's because you're projecting your own hidden beliefs. I certainly never said anything to that extent.

Comment: The blog post is not about lack of women in tech. It's about "3 ways you can be an ally to women in tech", and there's no point in allowing comments on it just so a bunch of dudes can complain because they think people _shouldn't be_ allies to women in tech.

Comment: @Oleg - Your use of the phrase is indicative of a broader narrative that is common online. You do not have to say everything you believe without it being glaringly obvious.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, only you completely misunderstand that narrative, it does not include the ridiculous claim that women can't develop, quite the opposite it actually treats women as equals. The narrative that is pushed by this blog and by you treats women as if they have special needs.

Comment: No, needing to not be treated poorly by your peers is not a "special" need.

Comment: So much for closing the comments on the original post. The conversation just moved, eh... here.

Comment: The reason why the entire movement to get more women to be coders annoys men is that women already have a clear advantage in terms of getting hired. There are a lot of big companies that have different standards for men and women, women being lower. It's a fact. Check reddit cscareerquestions for more info (only behavioural interviews for women vs men getting both behavioural + technical etc). All the coding meet ups that are "coding for women" (but men can still join.. even though as a man you would probably be unwelcome), are simply gender-specific clubs to get better opps. for women.

Comment: I'm all for women for getting jobs, but it needs to be done fairly, so that both men and women have equality of opportunity (people go through the same interviews, same level of standard). I do NOT support equality of outcomes (what companies like Facebook and Google are doing), people getting hired to fill some arbitrary quota that women in tech should be  x% of the workforce, and thus lower their hiring standards.

Comment: I think this above discussion should be posted as an answer as to why the comments were disabled for the blog.

Comment: @Rob I don't see why we shouldn't encourage healthy discussion. As long as both sides can be reasonably amicable in terms of trying to see each other's point of view. I think the problem is trying to shut out all discussion. That's when rage in my opinion seriously festers on both sides.

Comment: @programmer321 This isn't healthy discussion, though. Neither are the participants being amicable.

Comment: @Rob These comments are very civil and talking directly about the issues. Is this issue only discussable if you share a particular view?

Comment: @Rob No it's not healthy at all, nor it's abusive. kcpike claimed that she disabled comments to prevent abusive comments so I don't understand how the above discussion can answer the question. Those kind of comments belong to that blog post, they don't belong on SO or meta.SO and it's a shame this discussion happened here.

Comment: @Oleg My point was that these *very comments* are the types of comments that caused them to disable the functionality on the blog post. I wasn't being serious, though. Just pointing out the irony that this question spurred the type of behaviour SE was trying to prevent.

Comment: @JustinMeiners A couple of the comments have been deleted since I last commented. I never mentioned my view, so I'm not sure what exactly you're implying.

Comment: @Rob I never mentioned your view either. You brought up these "types of comments" so I was curious what makes them negative. They don't appear to abusive to me.

Comment: @JustinMeiners I fully agree with Rob, this are divisive arguments that ruin the community, this site should be only about programming. I really would've been much happier without the exchanges I had with Travis and Don'tPanic. Ideology should be kept out of SO if the company wants to promote some ideology on it's blog some measures need to be taken to prevent it from appearing here.

Comment: @Oleg I completely agree. I am here to program.

Comment: @m69 Just argumentative.  I've been in a couple of them, they tend to be pretty level-headed and go along the lines of Travis and Oleg's conversation right after your question (assuming it's not been removed by the time you see this).

Comment: If you don't wish to engage in ideology @Oleg, then perhaps you should refrain from posting it. I would definitely agree you would have been happier had I not shed light on the rather untowards comments you made towards women.

Comment: @Izkata - Here moderation is easier (as Jon Ericson also notes). On the blog it is much different. While comments here may be argumentative, abusive comments can be dealt with quickly and efficiently. Moreover, I would assume that users here are more apt to not want their accounts suspended whereas on the blog, suspension isn't an option. This is what my first comment here said as well, that it would be nicer to just have SO users comment on the blog, or as Jon states perhaps just move all blog discussions to MSE.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The blog title may be about "3 Ways You Can Be an Ally to Women in Tech" but it obviously about a lack of diversity when in the first paragraph `According to the National Center for Women & Information Technology, only 26% of professional computing roles in the workforce in the US are held by women. Within prominent companies in the industry, the numbers tend to be even lower. It’s clear that there’s work to be done.`. Also the blog post links to Gizmondos version of James Damores memo which you could argue is biased...

Comment: @TravisJ What I wish is for ideology to stay out of SO, when I see ideology I despise being promoted here you can be damn sure I will engage. The only one of us who made untowards comments towards women and claimed they can't develop is you.

Comment: @TravisJ Sorry, mentioned the notion that women can't develop, you didn't actually claim that, that was poor wording on my part.

Comment: @Soapy that is cited in the introduction, but if you continue reading the rest of the post, you'll discover it's actually about three ways you can be an ally to women in tech.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The introduction sets the tone for the whole piece. You can't just ignore it.

Comment: @TravisJ Exactly, on the harder-to-police disqus comments it's still almost all argumentative, not abusive.

Comment: @Soapy I'm not suggesting you should ignore it, but I'm not talking about tone. I'm talking about what it's actually about. The title isn't misleading.

Comment: It reflects poorly on (generic) you if you post something like this and then refuse to put the effort in to actually have a conversation about it.   This is what people mean when they talk about the regressive left.   Willing to make statements about what they think is right, but not willing to have a conversation about it.  You just want your (again generic you) safe space so you can plug your ears and go LALALALALALALA in your echo chamber.   I don't necessarily disagree with the contents of the blog post, I just find it insufferably intellectually dishonest.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sure if you look at it at face value then the title reflects the contents.
The issue is about the tone of the blog and that tone *is* about a `lack of women in tech`. This is okay but the post only represents one side of the argument and pushes it as the only side. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Soapy Why not look at it at face value? It's not about getting more women into tech. It's about how to deal with the women who already are in tech being treated poorly by their peers. It's a related, but separate issue. I'm honestly not sure what argument you're talking about. Is the other side "there isn't really a problem?"

Comment: @programmer321 where did you get the idea that Facebook is hiring to a quota? That's patently not true. All FB is doing is making sure we remove biases when hiring and employing people. **We will hire the best person for the job** and make sure that in that process we didn't miss out on the actual best person because of some perceived short-coming based on sex or religion or skin colour. Please get your facts straight before making sweeping accusations.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh really? https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-01-10/some-tech-companies-are-trying-affirmative-action-hiring-but-don-t-call-it-that some quotes: `Facebook rewarded its recruiters extra for “diversity hires.”` `At Facebook, recruiters in 2015 were told to prioritize finding "diversity candidates"` `Companies want to discuss equal opportunity without the terms "quotas" and "affirmative action,"` `some are redefining “best” to factor in diversity.` So yes you do hire the "best" person for the job and there are no quotas, when you redefine words you can say anything.

Comment: @Oleg: rewarding recruiters to bring more diversity into the funnel != hiring to a quota. I happen to see the other end of that process, and our training material. I note that part of these quotes are from 2015, and out of context. Recruiters being frustrated that their diversity candidates weren't hired also shows there is no hiring quota there. And the redefining 'best' quote is about the industry in general, not about Facebook specifically.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's also != "All FB is doing is making sure we remove biases when hiring and employing people" Facebook is doing all it can to hire diverse candidates i.e. hire less white and Asian men i.e discriminate against them. Luckily for the shareholders the final word still goes to the engineering team who hires people based on merit(at least for now). Other companies mentioned in that article do literally hire people only because they are women.

Comment: @MartijnPieters They are indeed as the article shows, prioritizing diversity hires. Heck they even have a chief diversity officer (what the hell is that lol?).  Facebook also has special internships created specifically for minorities at Facebook University. Quote from Facebook's chief diversity officer "we're very direct in having Facebook University (FBU) be a special internship at our Menlo Park headquarters that says very clearly to underrepresented groups that we have a gap that we want them to fill." http://www.businessinsider.com/facebooks-2016-strategy-for-improving-diversity-2016-1

Comment: @MartijnPieters Even if you look at Mark Zuckerberg's comments: "So it’s important that we do better on diversity, not only because it’s the right thing to do for the country and for people...” http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/entry/mark-zuckerberg-on-lack-of-diversity-in-tech-thats-our-problem-to-figure-out_us_58c6d61ee4b0598c66986ef6.  He states that they are trying to improve diversity numbers. These quotas (goals) might not be etched in stone, but nonetheless shows that FB has goals in trying to get their workforce to have x% of minorities (who really knows what the "right" number is).

Comment: @programmer321 yes, we are trying to improve the talent pool from which we can hire. Because *for some reason* certain minorities are underrepresented, because of biases and western culture that denies these people the changes white privileged males get. Are you saying that FB should not try to improve that situation? And we are *still not hiring to a quota*. All we are doing is make sure we *can* hire people at rates that reflect our society. When 50% of the workforce is female but you have a workforce that is < 25% female **something is wrong**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Like I said before, by "quota", I meant goals that FB has. From Zuckerberg's comment, I don't think you can really deny that FB doesn't have goals to make their workplace more diverse. I don't believe FB should be actively promoting hiring minorities. That only leads towards hostilities towards them, many people seeing them as "privileged" (not saying that that's warranted, but nonetheless, it is still caused by affirmative action practices). If women go through the same process as men (no special treatment), I strongly believe most of the hostility they face will cease.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also, I would disagree with your assertion that there are "privileges" that white males get. Women get the same opportunities men do (think back to access to CS courses in high school and CS degrees). Now they actually have better opportunities (FBU, etc.) than men. I think we need equality of opportunity (my post mentioned above) NOT equality of outcomes. We need to ensure that every person has an equal opportunity, not skew the process to fit some arbitrary goal of diversity.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In what way women are a minority? Why every job needs to be done by the same amount of men and women? What makes you say that the cause of this imbalance is some biases? This situation doesn't necessary needs an improvement because it's not necessary a problem. And even if Facebook wants to change the current situation they should do it without discriminating other groups. If you want to give your place to a woman be my guest, a junior white male with the same qualifications should have the same chance to get hired as a woman.

Comment: @Oleg A diverse team is critically important to the innovation, design, and execution of products that impact and serve all people. An example of a lack of diversity is the initial design of airbags. (http://leevinsel.com/blog/2013/12/30/why-carmakers-always-insisted-on-male-crash-test-dummies) another example is for voice recognition software (https://makingnoiseandhearingthings.com/2016/07/12/googles-speech-recognition-has-a-gender-bias/). If you need better articles on these examples, I can try and find others.

Comment: @Oleg - Your comments just reinforce the point that you think this isn't a problem. Your bias is clear from your previous inflammatory statements, but let's break down some of the common ignorance that you and the claims you represent seem to have. This isn't about women getting jobs.

Comment: While women may be underrepresented in technology (the term you were looking for here is ["minority"](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/05/19/opinion/sunday/how-to-be-a-woman-programmer.html) - women account for [roughly 5%](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2016#developer-profile-gender) of the developer workforce), 17% at google, 15% at facebook. they generally do not have a hard time obtaining a job when qualified.

Comment: They are also not "taking your place" in the workforce, if anything people like you are [forcing them out](http://money.cnn.com/2016/07/07/pf/women-engineering-computer-science-degrees/index.html). **This is about women staying in technology**. [Women leave technology at an alarming rate due to poor work environments](http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-women-tech-20150222-story.html). Women don't just "quit because they don't like it" as you state, they quit because of a hostile workplace.

Comment: That is what this blog was about - how to make work environments more welcoming to women. Simply stating as you and others do that it is just because there are gender differences and there is not a problem is just building on ignorance. Given that women in technology are in the minority, doing things like being a mentor, recognizing successful work, and being inclusive, is not just the right thing to do ethically as well as bringing the work environment together, but will also reduce turnover and enhance teambuilding.

Comment: @Wimateeka I applaud you for actually making an interesting point. The airbags case is quite bizarre but they were fully aware that they were testing for men only, they just didn't care about women safety. That was a business decision and having more women on the engineering team wouldn't have made any difference. The voice recognition as explained in a comment was caused by more men *using* the system. In general those kind of issues can be solved by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_factors_and_ergonomics engineers. Thanks, interesting read, now I need to respond to mr Travis ;(.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm going to ignore your personal attacks and only disprove your factual claims. About [20-25%](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/616) of software engineers are women, SO users are in no way representative. This is similar to the less than 2% women in opensource while about 1 woman for every 4 men is interested in working in software engineering only 1 compared to ~20 actually loves to write code. I don't care about people gender,race, age or sexual orientation. I always treat everybody equally and judge them as individuals so I don't understand how exactly I'm forcing them out

Comment: @TravisJ You can look [here](https://www.usnews.com/news/articles/2016-04-08/study-women-leave-stem-jobs-for-the-reasons-men-only-want-to) for some different reasons as to why women are leaving. The article basically says that men and women are treated completely the same, women are just not willing to endure it. What the big(and small), ideology driven companies are currently doing is actively hiring people based on their gender and not qualifications and this practice does cause women to take the place of white and Asian men. This is discrimination only they call it "diversity programs".

Comment: @TravisJ The blog post first paragraph is a feminist tirade, mentioning the despicable firing of a google employee as something good. The actual 3 ways that follow are completely gender neutral, this is some good advice as to how to treat any junior colleague. Being a junior is hard both men and women equally struggle. If you care about people because of their gender and want to only help women, fine do that, claiming that those issues are unique to women is ridiculous.

Comment: If discussions about women in tech are to be treated as unapproachable and dangerous topics that need to be cautiously controlled or avoided altogether, then what does that say about actual women in tech...

Comment: @Houseman That they are unapproachable and dangerous?? Is this the answer you are looking for? I have no idea what you meant, it went over my head. The real answer is of course nothing, it says absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Oleg I mean to say that locking the comments down makes it seem like the topic of "women in tech" cannot be considered normally, reasonably, or rationally. It sends a message that this is a delicate, controversial subject and that adults are incapable of having a conversation about it.   

Speaking about controversial subjects in the workplace is generally frowned upon, isn't it? But I agree, it does not say anything about actual women in tech. I should have been more precise.

Comment: @Houseman: When honest attempts at rational discussion under this very answer are dismissed by some saying the participants aren't being amicable notwithstanding the actual vitriol (I'm talking name-calling and F bombs) that has also been posted and since deleted by moderators, I feel like the message already speaks for itself and there is nothing we can do to change it.

Comment: @BoltClock When the conversation starts from a neutral point it's certainly possible, see https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/2875/2149 for a good example, I said the same thing and people responded with actual arguments and not "you hate women" that question is about a controversial topic and yet people managed to maintain a level of discourse worthy of SE. When the conversation starts with "Men are to blame for lack of women in tech and if you disagree you're an evil person" all you're going to get is people shouting their ideology at each other.

Comment: @Oleg: That's good to hear. It seems to me that the only way for a conversation to start from a neutral point and remain constructive is if it's completely academic - once you exit that domain, in some sense there's no longer such a thing as a "neutral point" because then it becomes about opinions, views, ideologies, even if they're backed by facts.

Comment: @Oleg - A few points with regards to your response. The NSF numbers are based on company employment, which means that women represent 20-25% of tech, but not of actual developers which was the statistic I had used. Regardless, if you are going to argue that 25% does not constitute a minority then I am not sure there is any rationale that you can accept in any situation.

Comment: As for the usnews article, the claim that men and women leave for the same reason was vaguely alluded to by a contractor, and never supported with any fact. The main statistic used in that article states that women leave tech twice as fast as men. While your argument may be it is "just because they don't like it", I find that to be absurd and unsupported by fact. It is that type of attitude that makes these discussions hard to have, and while you may be soft spoken about stating such claims that does not mean you are not reinforcing the negativity of others with your statements.

Comment: @TravisJ The statistic you used is of SO users, it's in no way representative. martin said "certain minorities are underrepresented" to which I responded "In what way women are a minority?" it's clear that we both talked about the general population. Please explain to me how you managed to get from that "25% does not constitute a minority". The claim in the usnews article was stated by the president of the consulting firm that conducted the study it's supported by the same study which is based on surveying 3200 people.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm mostly surprised that comments were ever enabled on that post - perhaps it's not possible to disable them before publishing.**

Any post about women (in tech) is going to attract trolls. 
Explicitly referencing things like the Google guy's internal memo and firing is going to make things worse.
Having a buzzfeed-esque title (X things you can do to Y [more Z]) is going to make it worse (at least from me, since I am growing steadily more annoyed by the style.) Yes, cutting comments will stifle the non-troll opinions both for and against, but the moderates would probably be overrun anyway.
*Why not just be proactive and close the door before the crap flows in?*

Maybe the article could change to be more moderate and considerate of different viewpoints (see point 3 of post in question), but I don't think that would help.
There are just too many trolls, too much negative energy floating around from the Googler's internal memo, and too much unavoidable conflation with the current views of feminism - 
it's just not possible to be perceived as neutral by everybody on this topic at this time.

(I *do* think it was a mistake to call the Googler's internal memo a 'tirade'.
The memo was controversial, certainly, but that should key you in to the fact that a lot of people agreed with it or at least didn't find it to be tirading. I suspect that most of the trolling and vitriol found on Twitter made reference to the memo.)

Answer (score -2):

It is not hard to understand why the comments were closed.

The people who published that post, closed down comments, and moderate this site, believe their position to be the right and moral one, and other's positions to be the wrong, offensive ones. Namely: that equality of outcome is valuable, and that men lifting women up "empowers" them.

You might not agree, but you're not the one with the "shut it down" button.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker He never did that. He didn't even complete his answer and explained why the comments were closed. I believe my position to be the right and moral one, and the other position to be the wrong offensive one and yet I will never prevent  the opposite side from speaking.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I didn't get to see the comments, but if by "abusive comments" you mean offensive levels of wrong-think and disagreement with politically correct narratives, then [*maybe it's time to grow up a little.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticks_and_Stones)

Answer (score -16):

Because StackOverflow wants to promote a one sided political agenda based on "Diversity", or as it's actually known, repressing men and white people for the sake of promoting other "genders" and darker skinned people, because, according to their own logic, they aren't capable of getting positions through hard work.

Anybody that goes against that narrative or points out the logical fallacies in the blog post, are usually demonized as some form of troll or some form of mysogynist, KKK\Nazi extremist and are either banned or publicly shamed so they can't get work.  (Usually anybody that's even a little to the Right of Karl Marx gets this treatment.  It's what happened to James Demore when he published the Google memo several months back.)  The original writer will say they are getting "harassed" when they are just getting salty comments they can easily block on their social media page.

It's a huge problem in the Tech industry, because a lot of social justice activists fresh from college have infiltrated the industry using buzzwords and doublethink\newspeak about "Driversity" and Feminism.  They're usually called Social Justice Warriors (SJW's) and are essentially the radical Leftist version of the Alt-Right.  Even using the same logic like White Privilege, which is a concept that white people have power and privileges that darker skinned people don't have.  White Privilege is a belief in White Supremacy, because within their mindset white people should use their privilege\supremacy to help lift up darker skinned people (or "People of Color") to positions of power.  It truly is another form of bigotry, but there's incredibly low expectations about other races.

Comment: You're assuming an awful lot of motive for a simple blog post. Why does every single time diversity is mentioned have to be part of a grand extreme leftist wave? Where do you get that "everybody that's even a little to the right of karl marx" gets oppressed from just a blog post? It's a blog post by stack. Have some perspective, this isn't a malicious act and your hyperbole in use here doesn't lend credence to your argument at all.

Comment: No, I've seen a lot of blog posts like this "we promote women and Diversity".  (Many tech websites are full of these.)  "Diversity" IS an extreme Leftist idea where certain people HAVE to be discriminated against in order for other people who aren't qualified to get a position without earning it.  It's Equality of Outcome, not Equality of Opportunity like it should be.  As for the "to the right of Karl Marx", look up the James Damore Google memo interviews on YouTube.  He's very Centrist and a leveled headed person, but was fired because he brought up ideas that don't "promote Diversity".

Comment: This type of stuff IS malicious, just not from your perspective. We need to get good coders in the Tech industry. Promoting someone based on their genitalia because they're being kept out of a job because "oppression", "discrimination", or some other invisible force like women are somehow being kept out when it's the most diverse its ever been, isn't a good idea.  And because Diversity hiring isn't based on their ability to make good code, this is how you get overbloated, sloppy projects where you're being held back because your Diversity or token hire wasn't qualified for the position.

Comment: Truly a misguided point of view here. I guess this is what comes of people thinking they can bypass education and just learn a trade skill, or just bypassing education in general. Diversity hiring is simply the act of not discriminating against well qualified people. I could give numerous examples of people highly qualified for jobs who would not have had the opportunity due to discrimination, because there are millions if not billions of them. There is a rich history here. Sports, science, military, governance, you name it, it has a history of discriminated entry at some point.

Comment: I know you're calling me an uneducated rube, but you do show off the reason why college is partially worthless in learning a trade these days.  In many Universities and Colleges, they teach people like yourself concepts of Social Justice activism by teaching you the double think that Diversity Hiring is trying to fight discrimination, by discriminating against certain people.  Say people who are straight, white, and\or male?  Because there are so many other "oppressed"\discriminated people in the world that survives to this day, even though we do have anti-discrimination laws.

Comment: Anybody who's an Egalitarian who believes in the idea of a work ethic and equality of opportunity, won't discriminate in favor of or against someone because of superficial characteristics. The best person gets the job, no exceptions.  Which is why I'm against this constant push for "women in tech".  If women want the job, they have to qualify for it and not scream they're being "discriminated" against and demand the position because they're women.

Comment: @TravisJ Can't you make a single comment without a personal attack? What education has to do with it? Richard Spencer has a masters degree and was a PhD student, do you agree with him and respect him because he is educated??? I won't respond to the rest and let Jimmy explain to you why the current diversity programs are discriminatory. He went a little bit to far with his answer but mostly makes good arguments.

Comment: @JimmyCougar - Being discriminated against does not mean that someone is unqualified. If you don't get a job and someone else did, that is because they were more qualified. The whole point of not discriminating is to let the most qualified person get hired.

Comment: @Oleg - I find it telling that would be the person that first comes to your mind.

Comment: However, once hired, as the issue here, is a different story. This issue revolves around tech culture, not tech hiring practices. Pretending that a non White male got hired because they fit a quota and are not qualified is basically the mantra that leads to workplace hostility. That you simply display the traits here shows that it is still a problem.

Comment: @TravisJ What does it tell you? Please complete your thought.

Comment: @TravisJ - "Being discriminated against does not mean that someone is unqualified."  So you're saying it's all about sexism and racism in the tech industry culture as if it's rampant? Every Western country has anti-discrimination laws and they're 30-40+ years old. They can sue for discrimination or go to the Press. (It doesn't always work because we do get game developer Manveer Heir, who's a very open black supremacist and the Press doesn't report on his anti-white Twitter rants.)

Comment: Tech's been overtaken by PC culture in the last few years and a lot of them want to "clean up" the internet and the tech world. If it was a toxic, you wouldn't hear of James Demore being fired for his "anti-Diversity" memo (the Press' words), Google firing him, and publicly apologizing. Mozilla's CEO wouldn't try to fire an anonymous employee of theirs on Reddit who complained of a woman that everyone walked eggshells around. Or a Blizzard dev admitting they aren't putting out DLC for OverWatch because of their game's "toxic culture". Trying to re-engineer human behavior isn't going to work.

Comment: This site posting a blog about needing more female Diversity hires, people ARE going to suspect their new hires are there to fill seats and parade their new hires to show they're not sexist.. by being sexist and using women as props. I'm not toxic like you're implying, I use logic and can see where your own ideas are coming from. It's from this 3rd\4th wave Feminist idea that women can't do it on their own and needs activism or institutions to be put in positions of power. It's belittling to women who want to get there by hard work and don't want to be seen as a victim needing constant help.

Comment: Google didn't publicly apologize for Damore. Demore is a bigot. He has a bad track record, you can see it from his antics in University, to his actions at Google, to his support of KKK titles. Gaming culture is also completely different than tech culture. However, all of these *tangents* miss the main point that this is about being inclusive towards coworkers. If you cannot get behind that, then yes, you are toxic.

Comment: Google apologized and I'd like to see your evidence that he's some form of bigot. Otherwise, I'm seeing here is you trying to morally grandstand that women and minorities are oppressed, can't get jobs in the tech world\are shunned away, and anybody that disagrees with you is some toxic bigot. You're not for inclusiveness here, you're for ideological conformity and the soft bigotry of low expectations in the workplace. I have my evidence why PC culture is toxic and bigoted. (Amazon even recently sent out a email with the title "Dear Diversity Hire".) Where's your evidence?

Comment: @TravisJ 'his support of KKK titles' this is the most ridiculous thing you said so far, all he said was that they sound cool, which they do. I'm waiting to see how you can outdo yourself. I'm still waiting for you to explicitly accuse a Jew of being a Nazi, so far you only did it implicitly. But even if you do that it will be less ridiculous.

Comment: @Oleg  Reminds me of Ben Shapiro being called a Nazi at one of his recent speaking engagements.  The guy's a religious Jew and wears a Kippah on national television.

Comment: Google never apologized to Damore. However, many people have had to aplogogize *for* him and his behavior. Google's CEO Sundar Pichai said that Damore was fired for "advancing harmful gender stereotypes" in the memo. Harvard had to issue a formal apology on his behalf. There is no fact that you cite here, your points are solid conjecture.

Comment: @Oleg - Clearly you are a toxic person. I certainly wouldn't want you in a team environment. Not once have you addressed the topic here, instead you seem to prefer grandstanding. There is no respectful discourse possible when your belief structure is so jaded.

Comment: @TravisJ Oh god no, I would rather starve then be part of your "diversity team".

Comment: Political correctness was part of a movement to stop people from calling other people the n word and such in the 80's. PC is defined as "the avoidance, often considered as taken to extremes, of forms of expression or action that are perceived to exclude, marginalize, or insult groups of people who are socially disadvantaged or discriminated against." It is clear from your point of view that you would rather marginalize, insult, or exclude groups of people.

Comment: "Google never apologized to Damore. However, many people have had to aplogogize for him and his behavior." - Semantics. That's correct there. However, your arguments are pure conjecture since you make the claim that women and minorities need institutional power to be hired, and you have no reason to back them up other than "there aren't enough women and minorities or inclusiveness."

Comment: @JimmyCougar - Your arguments that they just don't need it, that there is no problem, and that these groups aren't marginalized smack of the same type of arguments made against allowing women to vote and desegregation.

Comment: The reason I am using toxic is because it is a good description of people in communities who are actively harmful to those around them and the to community at large. It is a perfect description of your outlook here.

Comment: @Oleg The reason he's using "toxic" as his buzzword of choice is that he's trying to otherise and shame us because we're disagreeing with him rather than trying to argue.  It's similar to how social justice activists and religious fundamentalists chant "shame! shame! shame!" as if that would help.

Comment: That you would rather discuss a single word instead of the substance just reinforces the point here. Any time the actual subject comes up, being inclusive to women, you arm wave and get back into a third person dismissal of the topic.

Comment: @JimmyCougar - How would you suggest encouraging team building where a woman is 1/10? Do you think that is the same as a team with 10 men?

Comment: @TravisJ Political Correctness is a form of censorship where saying things that are outside of a certain political mindset can get you insulted, shunned, fired, or have violence done to you.  "It's authoritarianism in the guise of manners", pretty much.  Since you're a big proponent of it, I'm sure people are afraid of you a lot and walk eggshells around you in the workplace to not 'offend' you in any way so they won't get fired.  You claim you do it for the marginalized, but you're using it as a stick to beat morality and fear into others with.

Comment: @JimmyCougar Not even sure that it's that "deep" after seeing his comment about Damore and KKK I realized that he has no idea what he's talking about, he just regurgitates some points he doesn't understand. Actually trying to have an intellectual discussion with him was a complete waste of time. By the way I just saw an article by an extreme left wing Israeli newspaper claiming that Ben Shapiro and I quote the title is "as Alt-right as a Jew Can Get" the regressive left has gone completely insane(they always were now they don't even hide it).

Comment: @JimmyCougar - It isn't censorship to hold people accountable. When you spout hate, there are consequences. If you cannot be accountable for your actions, then choose different actions.

Comment: @TravisJ "That you would rather discuss a single word instead of the substance just reinforces the point here."  HAHAHA!  No, I'm actually trying to point out how stupid you sound calling people 'toxic'.

Comment: @Oleg Pretty much, but it's both frustrating and fun seeing how much his arguments and ideas can be deconstructed while he still tries to defend it.

Comment: You haven't refuted any of my arguments, or even addressed the topic here. Probably because your post, and point of view, revolves around the conspiracy theorist mentality. Go ahead, try to address the topic this time.

Comment: For example, "How would you suggest encouraging team building where a woman is 1/10?"  Treat them like part of the team?  I think he's trying to go for something where men and their 'toxic' behavior keep women from working in team based environments.  Anybody who's a good partner and works as good as her other team mates will be accepted, despite the sex or race differences.  Camaraderie through struggle.

Comment: \Jimmy Yeah, I took him seriously at first, and tried to actually address his arguments and that was pointless, having some fun is definitely possible. @TravisJ You mentioned the n-word. Currently blacks can say it but whites are not allowed, please explain how it's not racist.

Comment: @Oleg - I am sure you enjoy reading extremist articles considering the people that you raise as examples. However, I am not sitting here with some random online crap talking points. My point of view is built from studying actual history, the past, and past discussions on these types of issues. Civil rights may seem like an extreme movement to those who would rather keep people oppressed, but it is morally and ethically the right thing to pursue.

Comment: @Oleg - I am sure you would love to have that word back.

Comment: @JimmyCougar - It was an honest question, not a trick question. This whole topic was about inclusion. That was the contents of the blog post. What are some constructive ways of treating women like part of the team? I wish the answer to this was what you had posted here since that was the overall topic.

Comment: @Oleg  The idea that always makes me confused is "how can a race own a word"?  It doesn't and black people don't.  I think Left wing racists and PC people do that because they think black people need some form of power over their white oppressors.  That's the best explanation I got.  Otherwise, I'm for absolute free speech and believe white people should say nigga and nigger in certain contexts.  People do know the difference and one is still a highly offensive insult.

Comment: @TravisJ Still waiting for you explanation how the current situation is not racist. \Jimmy Yeah definitely, they like having that power(I don't blame them who wouldn't?) the regressive left wants them to have it as part of the larger idea of bringing people down instead of raising them up.

Comment: To be honest, I am not really surprised that you guys took this route. To the point, no one should use that word or a list of other equally offensive words. Clearly you understood my reference earlier. And to note, it wasn't about one word (again with the one word fixation and missing the overall point), it was about the concept of not marginalizing, excluding, or insulting groups of people.

Comment: "it was about the concept of not marginalizing, excluding, or insulting groups of people." Nobody is being marginalized, excluded, or insulted within many of these companies. Especially not under the law. They're coworkers there to do a job and get paid for it. They have to get to know and like their coworkers or avoid them if they don't. If someone doesn't pull their weight, they're looked down upon. If they're a token hire, people will be angry because they didn't work as hard to get a position and was discriminated in favor of their skin, genitals, or even politics. That is my entire point.

Comment: That's the entire concept against diversity hiring and the original StackOverflow blog post. Discrimination is still discrimination, except when it comes to Diversity hiring because the concept is disguised as helping "oppressed" minorities.

Comment: @TravisJ You're last comment is actually good, I disagree but as long as you claim that nobody should use them it's a valid self consistent point so have a . Still after your comment about Damore and KKK I'm not capable of taking you seriously so I'm out, have fun with Jimmy.

Comment: The whole point of diversity hiring is to remove discrimination from the hiring process, in either direction. Hiring someone who is underqualified is unfair to others. Marginalizing someone because they are perceived as being hired for something other than their credentials is part of what leads to the types of situations that were addressed in the blog post.

Comment: "The whole point of diversity hiring is to remove discrimination from the hiring process, in either direction." Where's the evidence? Strong claims need strong evidence that Human Resources departments or the leaders are looking at resumes, sees they're a minority and turn away. Where is it? If you did, it'd be grounds for an easy victory in a Civil Rights trial.  As for marginalizing someone because they're probably hired for being a Diversity Hire, don't make blog posts or post ads that you're looking for token Diversity hires, and don't make people go to Diversity seminars.

Comment: You cannot answer that there's some form of conspiracy because you are pulling it out of your ass and pretending like you care about people when you're trying to religiously moralize.

Comment: After the whole Monica controversy, it's clear that you're right.

Answer (score -22):

It's common for mainstream media and large websites to shutdown comments when a political agenda is being pushed.

Stack Overflow wants to encourage the narrative that the ideas of third wave feminism and [radical opposition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) to the current USA president are generally accepted in the development community.

Allowing comments on this article and others like it may go against the narrative they are trying to cultivate with blog posts.

Comment: Minority groups in general need help integrating. The attitude displayed here is a great example of how women in tech feel dismayed when trying to integrate. There is absolutely no crazy agenda associated with attempting to be more civil to women in the workplace, or in tech specifically; nor is there one associated with being a mentor or attempting to be more inclusive during discussion.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a demonstration of why comments are closed on the blog?

Comment: @BilltheLizard If it is and it was closed because of comments with similar content to this answer it proves the content of this answer. There is nothing abusive about it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Are you suggesting that the particular policies being advocated are so right that they can't even be discussed? This definitely sounds like pushing a viewpoint.

Comment: This answer has been flagged, but I'm not gonna delete it. For one thing, it'll probably reinforce your (mistaken) belief we are censoring people based on their political views. For another, it seems not so much rude as incoherent. The question you liked to has 44 answers and many of them are highly critical of Joel's position. Blog comments are frankly miserable to moderate and I'd much rather have people comment here anyway.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: Of course it can be discussed. It _is_ being discussed all across the internet. Unfortunately, there are idiots who love trolling this sort of blog post to waste peoples' time with pointless arguments. In addition, blog comments are so annoying to moderate, I'm pushing for them to be turned off for _every_ blog post. If people want to talk about the blog or specific posts, they can do so on meta. (Probably better for MSE, however.)

Comment: @JonEricson I understand that with anonymous public comments you can get a lot of garbage coming in. That makes sense.

Comment: @JonEricson  It is being discussed all across the internet **except** here (until now) can't we keep it this way and let SO be only about programming?

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride I think your answer is about as politically and socially charged as the blog posts and meta question you mention. You might make your point more convincingly and professionally by toning it down a little. Perhaps you should write up a more thoughtful meta question with references and post it on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), requesting more balanced and neutral blog/meta posts from SE? That might help you get taken more seriously. SO meta is probably not the right place to discuss these issues, although you were not the one that posted the question here.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: No; the other (deleted) answer that was posted since your comment is a far better (?) example. I don't read any abuse from this answer; just dissent.

Comment: @BoltClock exactly my concern. I don't buy this "third wave feminism" idea, but there is no abuse or trolling here.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride: It's funny how supporting the status quo is not considered by some to be a "political agenda being pushed."

Comment: @NicolBolas Don't know what status quo you're talking about it's not even an applicable term to the content of the blog post. In any case an agenda doesn't have to be unpopular in order to push it. The first thing any totalitarian regime does is taking control of the media and shutting down conversation. The Soviet Union pushed the same agenda for decades, most of the population believed in it and they needed to continue pushing it to maintain that believe.