# Why has Stack Overflow been publicly silent about race issues?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

With a diverse audience and a corporate culture that makes claims such as “Diverse teams build better products,” why has Stack Overflow not publicly shown support for the Black Lives Matter movement?

As a programmer and long time user, I’m surprised and disappointed by the silence.

The Stack Overflow Developer Survey clearly shows people of color are underrepresented in our industries. We need to take action and start to fix this.

[image: Results of question about ethnicity from survey]

Why has Stack Overflow not made a public statement that supports the Black Lives Matter movement? What will Stack Overflow do to help end racism and promote diversity, inclusion, and equality in our industry?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215633/discussion-on-question-by-mark-why-has-stack-overflow-been-publicly-silent-about). If you have something relevant and constructive to add, whether for or against, please post an answer below. Otherwise, take the discussion to chat.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would prefer them to [make donations to specific causes](https://twitter.com/MakotoTheKnight/status/1267164472407232513) as opposed to a statement on Twitter.

I'm not convinced you're going to see much more on the matter, honestly.  Stack Overflow has, as previously established, [had a rough patch with political statements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand), even though I felt fine when they wanted to support that cause anyway.

You speak to more holistic problems with the industry that no one's really been able to solve.  Just by saying "we need more diversity in tech" greatly overshadows and understates the level of effort and energy required to start motivating those kinds of people into this industry.  Stack Overflow can't accomplish much there since it doesn't have any sway into how well funded schools in Black and Latino neighborhoods are.  Nor does it really have the ability to grapple with the very real plight that many homes have to deal with - a single parent working to make ends meet who has other priorities for their kids' time as opposed to letting them mess around on the computer.

I would know - I lived that life.  But I still decided to go on into tech since I knew I didn't want to do anything else.

But hey.  At least if Stack Overflow donated to some causes, they'd be able to accomplish more than some tweet that barely has more likes than memes.

Comment: I realize it was an overly simplified statement. I am not a social activist. Just someone who wants to see change. And when I see industry leaders sitting, seemingly doing noting, I want to know why.  Thanks for your response. I wanted discussion to be started.

Comment: "Effective immediately, we are donating $50,000 to the Equal Justice Initiative and the NAACP Legal Defense Fund in order to support these organizations in the important work they are doing to end systemic racism " [(blog)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/10/stack-overflows-stand-against-racism-blm/?cb=1). We'll never know if they were reacting to you, or if they planned to do this and were just slower to say so than the Tweet, but whatever the case good call on specifying on Twitter that they should donate.

Comment: @DavyM:  The worst thing is that I can't prove or disprove that this was [Twitter-driven development](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/318341#318341), either.  But in this case I'll not let my feathers get ruffled over that and be grateful for the action.

Answer (score 10):

While the recent circumstances do reveal a disgraceful state of human affairs, and appeals can be made to one as an individual to act upon it (education, donations, and so on)... This is Stack Overflow. The one political stance that we should be investing on is to uphold the *quality standards* and *community values* of the site. With this, we are already doing our part helping the lives of so many developers worldwide, of which include black lives.

As already pointed out, making a substantial stance for certain politics is a slippery slope towards a potentially biased discrimination of complicated subjects. This house may be on fire, but several others are too. Stretching the domain of concerns is bound to either attract heated arguments and/or trolling, neither of which were left unnoticed when our code of conduct was last updated. This calls for a *very careful* evaluation of how important an adjustment to our policies would be, for the stance to be justified.

In the end, I won't be upset whether the company or the rest of the community decides to make such a political statement... So long as that does not compromise the ultimate reason why we are here in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for starting this conversation. This is a very important issue to us, and one that we’re committed to taking on, which is why we took some time to listen, educate ourselves, and set a foundation to work to make a lasting impact to the movement, both internally as a company and externally as a community. In addition to [our tweet last week](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1267149866809143296), you can read more about how we’ll act on our words through our short and long-term initiatives [in this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/10/stack-overflows-stand-against-racism-blm/).

Comment: Good work! If people use the volunteer program, could you encourage them to share their experiences, perhaps on the blog? I'm interested to find out how others positively contribute to the cause as software engineers.

Answer (score 2):

I personally am extremely relieved and frankly surprised that StackOverflow has not "expressed support for the Black Lives Matter movement".

Black Lives Matter is a highly organized political group, with clearly defined leadership, and a stated, detailed platform.  As such, it is very much like a political party.

StackOverflow, and in my opinion, no similarly broad-based non-political platform, has any business taking a position of "support" for a group like that.  The group has given themselves a catchy name and have succeeded in co-opting a phrase that most people would feel uncomfortable "disagreeing with".

But that is highly disingenuous and unfair.  It gives a political group the power to manipulate people into supporting it just based on its name.

Clearly most of the open source world has acceded to that linguistic tactic and shown their "support" by such methods as adding a banner reading "Black Lives Matter" to their websites and even their source code.

As someone who strongly opposes the political organization that goes by that name, I feel like a political ideology that I do not support is being imposed on me when I am forced to read these banners just to do my job.  I am grateful to StackOverflow for resisting this trend.