# Questions migrated to meta should not be rejected when closed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, closed-questions, migrated-questions

Questions sent to meta usually belong on meta. Can we please not reject migration for questions moved from main to meta if the question is closed? Questions like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397498/6296561) (deleted; 10k) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398117/why-is-stackoverflow-silent) belong more on meta than main, regardless of whether they're closed or not.

I also flagged the first one for mod attention to get it deleted. It was marked helpful, and I got this response on the flag:

> helpful - Sigh. Returning posts from Meta to main is a bug.

Leaving the question on both main and meta just causes more work. The one on main has to be manually deleted (if it has answers, otherwise it can roomba, but it usually gets explicitly deleted regardless), while, from what I can tell, the one left locked on meta requires mod intervention to deal with.

Can this please be fixed so closure on a post migrated to meta doesn't cause migration rejection, but rather normal closure? Let's deal with it here instead of on two sites when it has been migrated correctly in the first place.

Comment: Absolutely agreed! I have been meaning to post this bug report for literally years, and just never managed to do it. I'm glad someone at least reads my flag messages. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Anyone who knows you could tell from your way of writing that this was you :p

Comment: Just a heads up that this is on the product team list to revisit. Agree this could be done better.

Comment: @JonChan Any update on ETA/discussions for this? as we've had [another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400837/stackoverflow-does-not-show-code-snippet-as-it-should) fall victim.

Comment: @Nick It's status-deferred, so the ETA is 6-8

Comment: @Zoe Yeah, 6-8 10ths of a day it seems :p

Comment: @Nick One might say I [didn't expect that](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/men/2017/07/10/monty-p_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqqVzuuqpFlyLIwiB6NTmJwWbp1l2q0aHTOqWKb8l_dEA.jpg?imwidth=1400) :P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This change has been made and is now live: If a question from a main site is migrated to the associated meta site, and is then closed on the meta site, it will remain closed on the meta site and will **not** be marked as `MigrationRejected` and returned to the main site.

---

> post wrong for main,
> migrated to meta site
> closed? keep it right here

Comment: The first line in the haiku should be "post wrong for main site", as "post wrong for main" is only four syllables.

Comment: Also, this change unfortunately has a side effect, as such questions aren't eligible for Roomba (whereas they were in the past as rejected migrations): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347703/can-migrated-closed-questions-be-considered-for-automatic-deletion-by-the-remove

Comment: Except in cases where OP self deletes on meta after migration, then it'll be migration rejected