# Why did a user running for a moderator position approve this edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

**TLDR**: Had it been just anybody, I wouldn't have cared enough for a meta post. It just so happens that this specific user is running for a moderator position. I don't think this kind of review is fit for such a user.

---

**For the "You should have contacted them beforehand" people.**

You are right, but I didn't. I can't change the past, so I've tried to contact them since.

I [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27040410#27040410) [twice](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27079936#27079936) in the candidate election chat room (which they [haven't visited](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik?tab=general) *once* during the whole election process).

Just now I [pinged them directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310356/fall-2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/310383#comment275485_310383) on the answers to the questionnaire, because the nomination posts is locked. Rene had already [linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310356/fall-2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/310383#comment274334_310383) to this question when it was asked.

None of this have been answered. Sotirios's [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310795/did-a-user-running-for-a-moderator-position-really-approve-this-edit/310818#comment274390_310795) also have not been answered.

If you guys have other useful hints on a way to contact them, please tell me what they are.

---

I was just reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10288633) edit, which should not be applied because it:

- Leaves plenty of bad stuff in the question.
- Leaves the title bad.
- Is actually an edit to a **really** bad question, in fact not even a question.

What surprise when going back in the history to see that a candidate on present moderator elections *approved* the edit without even removing the presentation.

I, for one, would prefer moderators that do not let such a question be bumped to the top without at least removing the crap and at best close it.

**I would like to know how this can actually be considered a good edit, or else a simple confirmation that someone was not really paying attention**

From ryanyuyu's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310795/did-a-user-running-for-a-moderator-position-really-approved-this-edit#comment274259_310795):

> This meta post is merely trying to dig up dirt on another user. This should be closed because it is not trying to discuss anything.

I am trying to discuss a thing of utmost importance in our lives as SO users: the people who actually will be moderating the site. Would the community really be comfortable if moderators would approve such edits on a daily basis?

To be clear, I'll cite Pekka's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310795/did-a-user-running-for-a-moderator-position-really-approved-this-edit#comment274264_310795), because I wholehearteadly agree:

> For the record, I think "oops, overlooked that" is a perfectly valid answer to this, it would make me immediately forget the whole thing

---

I went over to the election chatroom to ask about other candidates opinion on this post. [They were not as judgemental](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27040410#27040410) as commenters seems to be.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am looking for an explanation on why did a person running for a moderation position would approve the edit. Please click the link and read who approved what. My question is clearly not on what course of action should have been followed, I know this has been discussed a lot.

Comment: And that is precisely why, having been discussed so much, this is very surprising

Comment: Singling out users is generally not welcome on meta... Again - what constructive answer you expect from community about behavior of specific user?

Comment: Again, this is not only a specific user, this is a user running for moderator position. I expect an explanation on why he approved the edit.

Comment: They were robo-reviewing, spending no more than 15 seconds on a question.  Obviously a crucifiable offense, nobody does that.

Comment: This meta post is merely trying to dig up dirt on another user.  This should be closed because it is not trying to discuss anything.  "_Would it have been anybody, I wouldn't have cared enough for a meta post._" so don't make the meta post.

Comment: Yes @ryanyuyu, it is trying to discuss things that will have great influence on our very lives as so users: people who actually moderate our site. I wonder as to how this is not clear? I mean, would you be comfortable if moderators approved such edits on a daily basis?

Comment: @ryanyuyu there is arguably a difference between a normal user and one currently running for moderator. Our moderator election is not "political" in any way but candidates' review decisions are a valid thing to talk about, and call them out on. That's one reason why the system is so transparent, no? (For the record, I think "oops, overlooked that" is a perfectly valid answer to this, it would make me immediately forget the whole thing)

Comment: @Pekka웃 fair point, but to counter that, do we really need a meta post about every bad decision a moderator candidate made?  Singling out a specific candidate for a single issue is extremely unfair to the candidate.  If this showed a pattern of bad decisions by the candidate or provided a forum for posting mistakes by all candidates, then this very different.

Comment: That is also a fair point @psubsee2003, I now realize how this can be seen as unfair. However, searching every candidates record for errors would not be better, I think. I was merely doing reviews, and realized a candidate did indeed review somewhat fastly (probably). A common place for discussing debatable candidates actions and hearing out explanations would indeed be a good idea.

Comment: `This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community.` I thought I did: "I would like to know how this can actually be considered a good edit, or else a simple confirmation that someone was not really paying attention" (true that @rene)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier IMO, a question on a specific edit is fine.  The problem (and reason i voted to close) and the focus of your question was not on the edit, but on a vote of a specific user (even if he is a mod candidate).  Phrased differently, it is completely on-topic

Comment: I would point out that this is not some old edit decision. This happened today. This user is running for moderator, **now**, and made this bad, careless editing decision, also **now**. It certainly gives me pause about having this user as a moderator. Moderators have great power. If elected, will this user suddenly become more careful? It seems unlikely.

Comment: @TomZych yes absolutely you make a good point.  But how many of the other candidates made bad decisions in the last 2 weeks?  Do you know?  Why give pause to this candidate when you don't know what actions the other candidates made?  (and to put this in perspective, I didn't vote for the candidate in question, I voted for others, but I do not want to see 1 meta post skew results).

Comment: @psubsee2003: Well, we could review all the candidates' edit decisions, if we had time. I don't, myself. What we do have is Félix usefully calling this one data point to our attention. Anecdotal data? Certainly. Therefore, worthless? No. We now know that this particular candidate did something careless, something we wouldn't want to see a moderator doing. It will affect my vote. It's worth discussing. It should not be dismissed.

Comment: I came across a bad review from a nominee. I wondered if I should do anything about it. I thought this post was about the one I saw, but it is a different person. Moderators make mistakes. New Moderators get a lot of support. And we can still expect them to make mistakes. During an election, they get no support, but they are out there and standing on what they say and do. Making a mistake during such a high-profile period at least tells something. Bad mistakes, however, say something else, and now the two I've seen have both been bad. I think you were correct to post.

Comment: @BillWoodger that's my whole point.  You now have info that no one else has  - another candidate made a bad moderation decision but we don't know the details (although I'm sure someone determined enough could find it by reviewing the entire history of every candidate).  Would it influence voters if you chose to disclose it.

Comment: Completely agree with @TomZych except it is unlikely the candidate will become more careful. I believe he will indeed become more careful after this post. We all learn from mistakes and that's why it is OK to point them out as Félix did.

Comment: This situation makes me wonder: can the system give a moderator some kind of ban if he fails enough audits? And had that ever happened?

Comment: @Roman since a mod can unban him/herself, no, they can't be banned

Comment: One easy thing we **can** do, without too much trouble, is to simply look at how many reviews each candidate has, compared to how long they've been around. I see two candidates with 7 years' tenure and fewer than 300 reviews. I see two others with 2 years' tenure and over 8,000 reviews.

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes, but if the nominee had got this far, I'd have posted it. Yes, I agree it would be better, much better, to have a specific place to post it. It's an election. Stuff comes to light about one candidate, the same light is then shone on all (if someone does the legwork). If all candidates make crap reviews, then it doesn't matter. If only one or two do, then people can decide if that should affect their own vote - if they know about it in the first place. Rather than 20 meta posts, one is a better way to make these things known. Everyone who wants, can read in one place.

Comment: @TomZych but that can mean nothing. I do loads and loads of skips. Nothing counts those. I probably have at least as many skips as I have reviews. I skip the dross "formatting" edits, my attempt to blunt the robo-reviewers, who waste their already-wasted reviews on those, and try to impact other things. Now you're going to count that against me?

Comment: @BillWoodger: Yes, now that I'm looking at the reviews in detail, I'm wondering whether low reviews is a bad or good thing. The ones with few reviews seem more careful; I saw one person, 7 years and less than 300 reviews, who was very careful with their edit reviews, sometimes in opposition to the less careful majority. Whereas our friend who is the topic of this posting has many thousands of reviews. I'm thinking quality > quantity.

Comment: @TomZych They even reviewed one of yours :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger: The one about the simulated ASM? Yes, I noticed :)

Comment: Go to their nomination post and see the last comments. I brought up similar issues with some of their latest answers. They either didn't want to answer or the nominations page was locked before they could.

Comment: This is the most ridiculous post I've seen on Meta in a long time. It must be wonderful to be you, perfect in every way, never making a mistake, and being so loud in bringing a single possible mistake by someone else to everyone's attention in a public forum. Bravo for you.

Comment: Why @Ken, your sarcastic dismissal has opened my eyes. Yes yes, clearly there is no need to pay any attention to this issue, because no one is perfect, and therefore there is no point in judging anyone, about any action, ever. Clearly it is inappropriate to point out a person's mistakes in public, even if that person is running for a public office. Yes yes, ridiculous indeed. Kids these days.

Comment: @Sotirios: Thanks for pointing that out. I see the last comment in that thread was posted nearly three days later. During the intervening period, the candidate performed over 200 actions on SO alone. So I don't think it was lack of opportunity.

Comment: Come on, this is just in poor taste to single someone out during an election, and especially with nothing indicative of any pattern of similar behavior. Moderators are human beings, just like all of you. They make mistakes, have bad days, days where life is distracting them from their focus. It should be obvious how unfair it is to single out one candidate because of a mistake that the others might as well have possibly made, only they weren't under the scrutiny of the edit police. The issue is not with what was noticed here, but with all the others issues could have been missed.

Comment: Tricky thing here is imagine the guy had that rare moment where his wife or kids were distracting him and he misclicked. Now his mistake is broadcasted on meta. Which is what I mean by being a little more discreet. We might be making a huge deal out of the rarest anomaly. We can't know -- since we went ahead and put the spotlight on him before we ever investigated further.

Comment: The things is, this could be dispelled very easily, with a simple "yeah, I overlooked that one". Really. Any doubt about the user would be removed.

Comment: Yeah, but that's one of the troubles with media and PR and all that. People are quick to judge, even if you don't... which is why we should handle these matters delicately.

Comment: Well, I realize you're just trying to do the right thing -- making the actions of the moderators more transparent. Trouble is that we ended up just putting a magnifying glass on only one inadvertently. It's mostly an issue with sensitivity -- and the unfortunate kind of things that happen when you put a spotlight on this kind of thing -- which could be the most innocent mistake.

Comment: The correct thing was to approve the edit.  There isn't a "minor edit" reject reason anymore.

Comment: I really don't think so @ChristianStrempfer. At the *very* least a reviewer could have improved the edit to remove the other bad parts of the question, but the correct course of action towards the question was to flag it for closure.

Comment: I'd be a lot more worried if that user didn't reject 1/4 of the edits they look at.   That strongly suggests a single mistake, rather than a pattern of them...

Comment: Is this a pattern of approving bad edits? Or a single mistake? If you have no evidence or any indication that suggests it's a pattern, then this post is unjustly defaming a candidate.

Comment: That point has been said (and countered) many times already @Fermiparadox. Anything new to add to the subject?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Where exactly do you show a pattern or an indication of a patter? I must have missed it. As for "being countered" please provide a link or two.

Comment: I won't really be making a resume of the numerous comments, especially since this is addressed in the question itself. This is not defaming a candidate, this is a valid thing to discuss.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier **Not true**. Nowhere in the question nor the comments did i find you or anyone else proving a *pattern* of bad edit reviews. You can prove me wrong with a link. I might have missed it despite reading everything two times, since I have concentration issues.

Comment: @Fermiparadox `This is not defaming a candidate, this is a valid thing to discuss.` Your whole pattern thing is to prove that I am defaming a candidate. I am not, for numerous reasons. I don't know how I can be clearer.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier You still didn't provide a link to indication or evidence of a pattern of bad edit reviews, so I assume that there isn't such indication or evidence. `This is not defaming a candidate, this is a valid thing to discuss`-This is not a valid argument. When someone reads your post he could be negatively predisposed towards the candidate. Therefor you unintentionally defamed him. Also the reasoning: "he made a mistake so he might be making more mistakes" is flawed. **One** mistake is not indicative of anything at all.

Comment: @Fermiparadox `This is not defaming a candidate, this is a valid thing to discuss` <-- I know this is not an argument. The [comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310795/did-a-user-running-for-a-moderator-position-really-approve-this-edit?noredirect=1#comment274264_310795) [about](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310795/did-a-user-running-for-a-moderator-position-really-approve-this-edit?noredirect=1#comment274353_310795) it are. As for proving the pattern, that's not my point, you brought that up. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier One comment states that [anecdotal evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdotal_evidence) are not worthless. When a possible (and much more probable) explanation is a "misclick" then they *are* worthless. The other comment is countered [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310795/did-a-user-running-for-a-moderator-position-really-approve-this-edit?noredirect=1#comment274331_310795). No need to thank me :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95945/discussion-between-felix-gagnon-grenier-and-fermi-paradox).

Comment: @KenWhite Do you even realize your comment is the perfect example of what you're accusing me of?

Comment: @Fermiparadox I don't know about edit reviews, but I've seen and brought to light what I think is a bad pattern of answering off-topic questions and not voting to close where appropriate. I just want the comments to be addressed.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: I cannot see the history of the deleted question, but if PHP is the correct tag, then the best action would have been to approve the edit *and* flag the question. Whereas flagging is a *should* not a *must*. Rejecting would be incorrect.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer You can see the edit. The best action would have been to reject and edit, to teach the user that presentations are to be removed. But I disagree, on such question flagging is not *optional*. Even the system identified it as crap. How come someone who wants to moderate the site did not take any moderating action on it? If they don't moderate this utmost crap, what will it take for them to moderate something?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: Wait. Where did I publicly create a post on Meta accusing you of being irresponsible for making a single mistake loudly in the title of a Meta post? Please provide a link to that **post**, because I certainly don't see it in any of the questions I've posted here on Meta (or anywhere else). My comment is simply that - a *comment* on the total unreasonable nature of your post. If you'd spotted a **repeated pattern** of such behavior, your post might be appropriate; making it for a **single** possible error is not IMO; it's an irresponsible accusation.

Comment: @KenWhite I'll have to admit a comment doesn't amount to the same attention. Apologies.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: "The best action would have been to reject and edit, to teach the user that presentations are to be removed." Teaching isn't part of the review system, you're making something up here. The rules are clear, if it improves the post you should approve it. If there are other flaws, you should click "improve edit".

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer "If there are other flaws, you should click improve edit" happy to read that we finally agree that they should not have simply approved it.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: I'm happy that you accept that your rejection of the edit was wrong. Besides that, it's ok to just approve it if you don't have time to improve it. Especially when it already has downvotes which will get it closed soon.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Do we want our moderators to have a perfectly unblemished reputation? Well, of course we do - but let's be more realistic, shall we :)

People are free to vote for whoever they want. If they (we!) want sloppy, uninterested, careless moderators - or, equivalently, if we do not care enough to actively *not* want them - then we may end up exactly with who we voted (or not-voted) for.

But does a single error rule out a candidate? And should this be brought forward in a Meta discussion? Should we go on a hunt for bad behavior? (Definitely not! Who goes digging for mistakes made some time in the past most likely *will* find what he's looking for.) And sure, a moderator electee should be doing his/her very best in the weeks and months immediately before an election, if only to present a positive face to his potential constituency!

We want our moderators to be fair, objective, honest, and true to the laws and spirit of Stack Overflow. If you find a candidate is lacking this, you may want to ask him/her directly, as (so very unlike the Real World) SO allows and encourages direct interaction with the candidates. Ask why this one edit was not handled as it should!

Maybe that day keys were lost (again), trains were late, and the dog had been doing its business not in a publicly acknowledged proper place. And maybe the moderator electee confesses he actually can't be bothered with a mere lowly review and actually wants to focus on things he finds more rewarding for the good of the site.

Comment: I can just about imagine the downvoters covering their ears and going "I can't hear you, nope"

Comment: I have not been digging for any dirt. I stumbled upon the review while reviewing edits.

Comment: No. What's wrong with a public question? If I ask a private(-ish) question I may not know enough to know that the answer is not a full one. In public, there is a better chance that someone else will. What's the problem? If one of the new Moderators makes a mistake, it'll mostly turn up here.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: apologies-I did not want to suggest you did (or others should). Rather the other way around: it's great that looking at a list of reviewers had your spider senses tingling right away! (Ed.: I changed that sentence)

Comment: All other aspects aside, "*And maybe the moderator electee confesses he actually can't be bothered with a mere lowly review and actually wants to focus on things he finds more rewarding for the good of the site.*". Well, *not* doing lowly reviews is a viable option. Participating in reviews in a superficial/counterproductive manner is not. Not just mods, but anyone with the necessary privileges. If you do it, do it properly; nobody is forced to take part in it.

Comment: I only object to the use of "dirt" here. I'd rather adjust it to, `"Who goes digging for misclicks most likely will find what he's looking for, somewhere in the past"`. That should add the appropriate tone on the gravity of this situation, until we find something more serious.

Answer (score -3):

This is a terrible question for Meta.  In fact, the title question is rhetorical and not a question at all.  The answer to it is implied and already given in the question - Yes, a user running for moderator really did approve the edit.  Which leaves me thinking that you are really just trying to use Meta to diss a moderator candidate.

In edits, you added a real question to the body of your text: "Would the community really be comfortable if moderators would approve such edits on a daily basis?".  But again, that is just a diss and unjustified.  "On a daily basis" implies that you have seen this user approve such edits **on a daily basis**, not just once.  Can you provide other links to all these copious, wrong edit approvals?  If not, you are turning a single mistake into a larger issue, and escalating it by bringing it to Meta.

If you really agree with Pekka that "Oops, overlooked that" is a valid answer that would make this go away, then you should have first gone to that moderator and pointed out his mistake.  He probably would have given that very answer and we'd not be bothered with this on Meta.

Comment: "Which leaves me thinking that you are really just trying to use Meta to diss a moderator candidate." Stop implying that you know what my thoughts are. I had no (and stil don't have) prior emotions about that user. I might have been unconsiderate, but accusing me of wanting to diss a candidate is not really better.

Comment: I did not say that you were wanting to.  I said that you were trying to.  Trying is about your actions, not your thoughts, and your post clearly attempts that action.

Comment: Non sense. Trying is about thoughts. Trying to do something implies an intention. I had no such intention.

Comment: Trying to do something does often carry an intention, but not always, and not always the most obvious one.  Our actions and our motives do not always line up.  If that was not your intention, then from many of the comments and from the answers you got, understand that your execution was very flawed.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier What you may have intended and what it may look like to others can easily be very different. And I would have to agree making a big post like this about a single review mistake is strange when we have seen many moderators admit to mistakes in the past.

Comment: Than why aren't they admiting their mistake?  @JoeW

Comment: Yes, it was flawed @AgapwIesu. But still, I wasn't trying to diss someone. Inconsiderate, quick to act and slow to think, alright, but not downright wanting to diss someone.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier HArd to say, in the end the review was handled correctly so it doesn't really matter, and you normally see moderators talk about mistakes when they caused a bad outcome. If a moderator candidate has to come and admit every mistake they have made in the review queues we would be seeing a lot of posts about mistakes.

Comment: The review was handled correctly because of the attention this question brought on it @JoeW. And we're not talking about coming out to justify any error. Questions like these doesn't happen often. Yet the user did not come out *once* to speak about this, even after this whole mess and me asking twice in the election chat room. I'll invite you to read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310795/did-a-user-running-for-a-moderator-position-really-approve-this-edit#comment274390_310795). Not answering seems to be an habit of theirs.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Just because someone who is running for a moderator position is singled out for a single action as the election starts doesn't mean they have to or should respond.

Comment: @JoeW again, please read the linked comment, the related comments on the nomination post and understand that I have been asking twice in the election chat room. (which is what my detractors are telling me to do)

Comment: One of the downsides of being a moderator, is that your actions are more closely watched by the community. There was a [question proposed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309767/189134) for the moderator questionnaire dealing with *exactly* this situation. A moderator needs to be willing to handle such such users, lines of questions and the added scrutiny.