# A community "forum" for Q&A / discussion on prospective moderator actions at election time

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-election

This is inspired by the circumstances surrounding [Why did a user running for a moderator position approve this edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310795/did-a-user-running-for-a-moderator-position-really-approved-this-edit).  In the post in question, a user called a specific moderator candidate out for a single moderation action,

I disagreed with the specific post because of the approach focusing on just 1 action by 1 candidate, however the (recent?) moderation actions of moderator candidates should be very relevant to the election process if done in a fair and impartial manner, and allow candidates to know where they can explain their actions.

For future elections, do we need a specific location for discussion that is open throughout the election process where the community can disclose and discuss the positive and negative actions of prospective moderators.  While this could result in a somewhat convoluted post, it provides a couple of very specific advantages to held with the fairness of the process

1. All complaints and concerns will be concentrated in one place.
2. Responses to such concerns from the candidates (via comments) can be linked to the specific concern.

This will keep the discussion in one place, rather than spread out in multiple places (split between the election page, and various meta posts.  It will also make it easier to highlight candidates who have some very questionable actions so prospective voters can review the specific actions of concern and make their own judgement.

My goal isn't to politicize the process, but I just want to make sure everyone gets a fair "trial" by the community rather than a single individual being  judged (where the judgement is fair or not) where other candidates avoid it because no one disclosed any suspect actions.

Comment: Election chat room seems a better place for localized concerns such as this one.

Comment: I disagree.  Chat is good for any real-time discussion, but still seems too chaotic for users who don't frequent chat.  It also seems difficult to group discussions on specific issues.  The goal here is to make concerns about candidates more visible to the voting community.

Comment: Well, didn't that question give you a cue what can go wrong with this kind of intense scrutiny?  Everybody slips once in a while, such slips should not be the be all and end all.  You'd have to wonder how many excellent candidates did not run because they goofed up several years ago and rather not see it dug up again.  We do get meat-and-potatoes candidates because of this, never another Will again.

Comment: @HansPassant better to make a single place for all than many posts.  A single (sactioned) post gives every candidate equal footing and exposure.  The post in question attacked a single user for a single action, and that is hardly fair.

Comment: I see a moderator candidate voted to reopen the question I linked, which calls into question his actions.  Do we need another question to discuss that action? (see my point).  I don't want to politicize the process, but I also want to make sure we are electing the best candidates without biasing the community unfairly.

Comment: Aren't comments on the moderator nominations good places to raise questions about previous actions? That's been used before to bring up specific troubling incidents and give the moderator candidates a chance to respond to them. If we made [comments visible in all stages of the election](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222078/comments-on-moderator-nomination-statements-should-be-visible-in-all-stages-of-t) and brought back voting on those comments, this would present that information where voters could see it.

Comment: @BradLarson certainly an option.  A meta post may not be the ideal spot, but my goal was to make sure we can highlight concerns as impartially as possible, and using those comments would certainly help, especially if commenting was open throughout the entire election, not just in the nomination phase

Comment: @BradLarson I'm not sure there is space always in a comment, and the wading-through dross would be worse then than on a specific post on a specific question aimed at being a target for discussion of such things. With voting, better than nothing, without voting, pointless.