# 2016 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Stack Overflow is scheduled for [an election starting next week, November 7th](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8). In connection with that election, we will be hosting a Q&A here for candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

This is similar to [the Q&A sessions we've done in previous elections](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309753/fall-2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), but this time we'll be collecting questions a week in advance to the actual election running.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337571/2016-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, November 7th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day because naturally it's right after Daylight Savings Time, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- If your question submission includes a link, please either use a raw URL or use the `[text](url)` syntax.
- At the end of the collection phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing (up to) 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

---

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: All the best to the future candidates.

Comment: Can a user below 18 be a candidate?

Comment: @dorukayhan See [Evaluating the risks of allowing teen moderators on the SE network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126919/310998) on MSE.

Comment: @dorukayhan Yes. There are like half a dozen SO moderators who are/were under the age of 18 when elected.

Comment: With edit limits in place now, my question from last year is pretty well irrelevant. I'll just have to think of another good one. :) Good luck to all those who run!

Comment: @dorukayhan See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221571/274942) and the answers below. There's basically no way to check age, and there isn't necessarily a causal relationship between age and moderator ability.

Comment: Ohh, I'm so curious! I can see from the first link that 3 moderator positions are available. Will this all be new positions or will some of the current moderators step down?

Comment: @honk typically if any moderators are stepping down  it's announced in the official meta post welcoming the newly elected moderators. Guess you're going to have to live with the suspense for a bit :-P

Comment: Can someone fix the community bulletin, sometimes it shows only 2 featured items + hot meta post, at other times it shows all featured, no hot meta posts... IT DRIVES ME CRAZY THE INCONSISTENCY.

Comment: Why do we need a moderator?

Comment: @ManojKumar see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role

Comment: How long does it take for new moderators to get into the flow? 6-8 weeks?

Comment: I just noticed that the links at the bottom of the [election page](http://stackoverflow.com/election/8) are for last year’s election.

Comment: @JF Yeh, came up to fix that just now. The Election text there is persistent across a site's life, so it has to be manually changed for new elections. I typically do it when the election starts, which... doesn't exactly work when I link to the election *before* it starts. Since pretty much none of the links other than the Meta link work until the election starts, I'll just be taking down the links and then put up new ones next Monday.

Comment: @FilipHaglund It took me about two weeks to get fully confident, but I already knew all the tools from my other diamond sites. I'd expect somewhere between three and six weeks, depending on the person and how much time they have. The current team (and others from across the network) help new folks with any questions they have.

Comment: I really hate to speculate about people's voting, but it _looks like_ there's a fair bit of "the correct answer to the suggested question is no/yes" corresponding with down/up voting on the answers here. I'd strongly suggest that the voting should reflect **whether you think the suggestion makes a good thing to ask a candidate**, not whether you agree with the suggester's (implied or assumed) stance or reasons for making the suggestion, or with what your preferred answer to the suggested question might be.

Comment: A bunch of questions posted as answers, to an announcement posted as a question. All of it about moderation. Isn't this just a sight to behold?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: _"We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or **irrelevant to moderation** or the election."_ <-- That's why I downvoted some suggested questions, here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell good luck trying to adjust meta voting patterns. :P

Comment: @Cerbrus Agreed; that reason is hand-in-hand with what I proposed.

Answer (score 134):

A 10k+ user regularly has their comments flagged as "rude or offensive" or "not constructive", to the tune of 4-5 flags a day. No comment by itself is particularly offensive, but their general tone causes them to be flagged by multiple users.

You've contacted them privately about this, but they believe that they aren't doing anything wrong and that people are being too sensitive. The flags keep coming in on their comments. What, if anything, do you do next?

Comment: The correct answer is [read the manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ycwi.png)

Comment: @Machavity I would buy that.

Comment: Great question. I've encountered several users who I don't particularly care for, but I can't flag any of their posts because they're not actually objectively breaking rules/being offensive. There's no flag for "bad attitude", after all.

Comment: Interesting would be to learn how rep matters: <5K; 20K+; 50K+; 100k+.

Comment: the amount of rep a user has is pretty much irrelevant to this question and its potential answers, is it not? Its just that a particular "known" 10k user was the trigger for putting it here.

Comment: @Gimby - The "10k+" bit is to indicate someone who has contributed quite a bit to the site or might be considered a subject matter expert, as opposed to a new user or someone without many quality contributions. This also isn't about a specific user, as it's a situation we have to deal with on a weekly basis. It's also been made more visible as a result of the automatic flags we started getting [after this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284058/135615).

Comment: @BradLarson still reads to me that it is dealing with aholes that will always be aholes which is not tied to particular rep counts, but if me having "only" ~3k rep makes a difference in how I need to be moderated, I begrudgingly accept your experience in this matter ;)

Comment: A very useful question if one believes that there is a cultural bias in perception of rudeness.

Answer (score 104):

How would you, as a moderator, deal with a situation where a group of users unanimously disagree with your ruling while you're 100% sure you based your decision on the standing policy?

What if your ruling was in a chatroom?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "What if your ruling was in a chatroom?" Do you mean that the ruling *concerned* a chat-related policy? Do you mean that the ruling was "issued" in a chat room? Or do you just mean that you were tarred and feathered publicly in a chat room?

Comment: @CodyGray I mean the ruling was issued in a chat room and as a consequence then the moderator tarred and feathered. That was my intent.

Comment: @rene something like that would never happen, surely? :p

Comment: Oh, well, I thought getting tarred and feathered on chat rooms, Meta, Twitter, etc. was all part of the fun of being a moderator.

Comment: @JonClements Not since the accident.

Comment: OK, everyone's had their fun making jokes about particular incidents, but let's keep comments focused on whether or not this is an appropriate question for moderator candidates to answer.

Comment: So what if they unanimously disagree? It's your ruling, you're confident it was right, stand your ground. If there are issues, surely the users can contact other moderators/staff to get a second opinion?

Answer (score 86):

Not everyone agrees with every Stack Exchange policy, guideline, section of scope, etc. As a moderator, do you think you'll be able to effectively moderate and enforce Stack Overflow policies you may personally disagree with, but which the community strongly supports - or, as Aaroninus suggested, perhaps which you *and* the community disagree with?

Comment: Or even better, the ones you _and_ the community disagree with.

Comment: Or even better, do you think that there is a role for [moderator-led community nullification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_nullification) when it comes to the official Stack Exchange policies? In other words, why imply that the job of a *community-elected* moderator is to enforce the official Stack Exchange policies without thinking for themselves, @aaron? They have employees for that.

Comment: And which policies do you personally disagree with?

Comment: @Aaroninus That's a good point; I added that in.

Comment: @UKMonkey I don't have any specific policy in mind, if that's what you're asking about. I have, though, in my experience moderating other Stack Exchange sites, had cases where I disagreed with a community decision, and found it difficult to agree with, but which I still enforced.

Answer (score 79):

A user vandalises their post and enters a "rollback war", trying to change it to simply read "QUESTION REMUVED FOR PRIVACY". They had also submitted (rejected) suggested edits to do likewise to the answers.

By the time you see it they've also flagged or commented on the question:

> Please delete this ASAP, it's super urgent that I remove this because my university honor code demands that I do and I'm going to get kicked out

The question was pretty poor to begin with, but received 3 decent answers and had been edited a little before the vandalism started.

What do you do?

Comment: Some tips for the candidates.  I've seen those users marked "Suspended for Rule Violations".

Comment: I'm curious what the official stance on this is, for after the elections :D

Comment: Note that comments about these questions should be about whether or not they are appropriate to ask a moderator candidate, not about what your specific answer would be.

Comment: Suggested reading: [how does deleting work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/197901)

Answer (score 72):

Moderation sometimes entails seeing some questionable content. Are you willing to take that risk? If you'll be moderating at your workplace, do you have a corporate filter that will take issue with this?

Comment: Somehow, I get the feeling there's a meaty story behind this one...

Comment: @Mogsdad - Trolls regularly post some pretty offensive content, which we typically have to deal with. [Here's one example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333185/19679), although thankfully [the blacklist on link shorteners](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts) has reduced the number of times I've clicked a link in a post and been directed to a porn site. As a moderator, you will be exposed to some bad stuff on a regular basis.

Comment: How come "porn" is related to "bad" in this case? I'm just wondering... :D I would say that "bad stuff" is stuff that is deemed illegal - granted, SO is available all over the world, but for the sake of this argument, let's at least consider mostly western countries - is there really that much really bad content on SO?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie *"bad stuff" is stuff that is deemed illegal* Wrong. 'Bad stuff' encompasses far more than that - there is much that isn't illegal but is disturbing, triggery, etc. And yeah, there's quite a bit on the site that few ever see.

Comment: Meh. That some people have issues shouldn't deem thing inappropriate or "bad". Granted, pictures of genitalia has nothing to do on the site, but it's hardly the end of use world. And "triggers/trigger warnings" is the biggest bullshit this side of 2000.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie a lot of the "bad stuff" is stuff that could get you fired from your job if you're found to be accessing it (if it's not automatically blocked - and logged anyway). *That's* the issue here, not that it's disturbing, triggery etc, per se.

Comment: I live in a country where getting fired isn't something that happens because of a single, or even several "happenings" like this. Accidentally accessing something "forbidden" won't get you fired. Might get you a warning, but if you explain why, it probably won't even be logged on your sheet. Granted, I live in Norway, where we actually have laws that protect workers more than employers.

Answer (score 69):

- Please explain, in your words, the difference between these flags:
  NAA and VLQ.
- How would you act on a "NAA" answer which is flagged as VLQ, or vice versa?

Comment: While simple, I think a proper explanation here illustrates the candidate is basically aware of how moderation on SO works.

Comment: I think there's more to moderation than these 2 flags

Comment: @TimCastelijns: of course, I'm not saying that's all there is to it. There have been VLQ vs NAA discussions for ages, though. The response to this question _will_ make it clear how aware the candidates are on how these flags work.

Comment: I think this question is interesting because there doesn't seem to be an agreed-upon ground truth answer, or if there is, it hasn't been communicated well to normal users (such as me).

Comment: Is it then not misleading to ask about the difference between these two flags if the intent is to show how they individually work? I would ask to provide two examples of when to apply these individual flags - and two examples when not.

Comment: @Gimby: Either way, isn't the result of the candidate's answers the same?

Comment: @Cerbrus If the result is to judge how one would moderate improper use of these flags... I guess not.

Answer (score 58):

You impose a temporary ban (say 1 week) on a user for what you judged as reasonable and valid reasons (the user gets notified by email of your action and the reason).

The user replies to your email acknowledging the transgression, says they won't do it again and asks for the ban to be lifted. The user sounds genuine.

Do you:

- do nothing (no reply, no ban removal)
- remove the ban
- reply, but don't remove the ban - if so what do you tell the user

Explain your reasoning.

---

The context of this question applies to longer bans too. If it helps get the juices flowing, consider the situation of a *second* offence for the *same* behaviour, which has a default ban period of 1 month.

Comment: Why would anyone remove the ban? It's only a temporary ban. If the mod made a mistake I could see it, but it's only a week!

Comment: @oldtechaa this is for the candidates to answer (not you, and not here)

Comment: That's true, but this question seems too easy.

Comment: @oldtechaa well this is not theoretical either; it happens moderately often. It's something the mods have to deal with, so it's good to think about how and why mods communicate with the user community and any implications.

Comment: Strongly related: [Make moderator messages anonymous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283725/178816)

Comment: Answer with "what's it worth to ya?" and a Western Union branch number.

Comment: @Pekka웃 hmmm... I wonder if ransom.stackexchange.com is taken?

Comment: For bonus points: if the user was suspended as a result of interactions with other user(s), what would you tell the other user(s) if they noticed the ban was lifted?

Comment: I'd find it more interesting if the second offense was for a _different_ behaviour. If it's the same behavior, you can point out that they haven't improved since their last ban. If it's a different transgression, it's more difficult to judge if they're honest.

Comment: @S.L.Barth in the context of the mod tooling "first" and "second" start counting independently for each offence type, so a *second* offence means the *same* behaviour *again*, and a *different* bad behaviour would be a *first* offence for *that* behaviour.

Answer (score 50):

Bit of an edit from [here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309767/2607247) Mods get a lot of criticism, and while I haven't seen this recently, I have seen something similar in the past.

> A user has been criticizing your moderation decisions on Meta. This
>   has been occurring frequently over the course of a couple weeks. Some
>   of these posts are very constructively made, with examples and
>   reasoning, while some are more rants. While any mistakes you've made
>   that have come to light were corrected when brought up, it seems that
>   almost every day the user is finding something you've done to draw
>   attention to.
>
> The user is a high rep user and generally does not cause trouble, but
>   does seem to have an issue with your moderation style. How do you
>   handle this situation?

Answer (score 48):

My favorite question from last election:

> Do you have any Meta posts that you're particularly proud of, or that you feel best demonstrate your moderation style?

Comment: It's nice to know someone cares.

Answer (score 35):

*I would want to ask [the same question as last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309753/fall-2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/309766#309766):*

I'm mostly interested in close votes that could be seen as opinion themselves. One person's "unclear" might be another persons "good enough". Therefore,

> Your future close-votes will be binding and hold more weight. You will be able to close questions on your own, without the assistance of 4 other community members. With that in mind, will you cast **more** or **fewer** close-votes than today?

If you don't like the wording, the following improvement was suggested, which I think is fine, too:

> Being a moderator you will able to close questions on your own and override other community votes. Will this change how you vote to close questions?

Answer (score 28):

When faced with the decision of whether to delete a post, how do you determine whether the post "makes the internet a better place", as in [this answer to About significance of questions and whether or not they should be deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317571/215552)? Other moderators and employees seem to believe that if a question has been closed, it should eventually be deleted, as in [this answer to the Meta Stack Exchange question "off-topic questions should be deleted rather than closed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86056/194720). Or do you have some other determining factor(s) for deletion?

As @rene brought up in a comment, if you are reluctant to cast the binding vote, what about when you are asked to reverse deletions performed by the community, as in [George Stocker's answer to Assisting with godaddy deletions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333768/215552)? Or in the case of repeated delete/undelete cycles as in [Why are we able to vote to delete or undelete over and over again?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283555/215552)

Comment: I assume most moderators are very reluctant to cast their binding vote. So that will probably be the answer of all candidates. But this can become different if they are asked or tasked with reversing community deletes, for example [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333768/578411). Maybe edit that aspect into your post.

Comment: Related question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337230/792066

Answer (score 23):

As moderator, you are put into a hard place deciding between deleting or locking "popular content", that may or not adhere to current content policy. Do you believe in this dichotomy? How would you be able to sort out this situations?

Answer (score 23):

[Taken from the last election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309847/3956566), but still relevant:

> A user flags a post or comment as rude or offensive to a minority group, or as a member of a minority group. You know little about the issues facing this minority group and the post would not be offensive to the majority of users.
>
> What do you do?

Answer (score 22):

Not everyone here ventures into the chat rooms, and not many people know what goes on there.  However, as a moderator, one of your duties involves the moderation of the chat rooms.  If you've never been in a chat room before and you were called to resolve an issue with either the room or its users, what would be the *first* thing you would do?

Note:  "thing" isn't limited to moderator action in this context.

Comment: I would wet myself ...

Comment: @rene:  Don't ruin my completely irrational and absolutely not based on anything whatsoever Rambo-like image I had of you...

Comment: @rene: Do I understand it correctly, that you will throw your hat in the ring this year? ;)

Comment: @rene: Good advice, I think! Sadly.

Comment: _Looks at the Lounge<c++>_

Answer (score 22):

The opportunity to interact with your fellow SO users in a greater capacity is undeniably attractive, but it doesn't come without cost. As a moderator you would have an incredibly high level of visibility. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283725/271348) shows that such visibility - coupled with a disagreement with the wrong user - can be cause for serious, real-world harassment. From the post:

> [My actions as a moderator have] resulted in some pretty intense
>   social media stalking on my Facebook and Twitter, ranging from
>   personal insults to attacks on my professional LinkedIn profile. Other
>   moderators have had disgruntled users repeatedly phone their place of
>   work trying to get them fired.

Are you prepared to handle such threats? How would you react if this happened to you?

Answer (score 15):

Robo-reviewing is a major problem on Stack Overflow, because it actively encourages bad content.

As a moderator, you will be able to temporarily suspend users from review. You will also be able to temporarily suspend users from editing.

How do you intend to use your power to temporarily suspend users from review, and from editing? What kinds of reviewing do you consider good, and what kinds of reviewing do you consider bad? Similarly, what kinds of edits do you consider good, and what kinds of edits do you consider bad?

How much evidence do you believe to be required, to justify a review suspension or edit suspension?

Answer (score 9):

You come across a typical question that's asked on a daily basis, one that you know has a good duplicate target on SO.

You see the question has been answered by a *high* rep user with a gold badge in the relevant tag. (So he could've just hammered it instead.)

What, if anything, do you do?

<sub>Note: I'm talking about questions that have a dupe target as their first google search result. The famous canonical ones that get asked again and again.</sub>

Comment: Absolutely agreed. I see this happen way too often, even >200k  users I have seen doing that.

Comment: ^ Which is my inspiration for this question.

Comment: @Cerbrus you think they got to 200k by closing things as dupes? :P

Comment: @canon: I'm not going to touch that with a 10-foot-pole.

Answer (score 7):

There's a sudden glut of chat flags and, upon investigation, you discover several people apparently arguing and flagging messages in a private room. To top it all off, they're not arguing in English either.

How do you handle the situation?

Comment: Didn't we already settle the "languages other than English" question for Stack Overflow chat?

Comment: For discussion, yes. It doesn't mean that people don't chat in other languages. And as a mod, you would have to deal with that

Comment: What I meant was, isn't the standard policy that all chatting on Stack Overflow should be in English for moderation purposes, and that the use of other languages is not allowed? In practice, of course, this means "use at your own risk", because if a moderator is called in and sees non-English language, she will assume a violation and place the offending user in a timed suspension from chat. (But I don't know, maybe I'm revealing my own bias and actually answering the question, rather than engaging in a meta-discussion about its value.)

Comment: I think you're missing the point. I know full well what the policy is *supposed* to be. But if people are using chat in other languages anyways (which they are), and they get into a flag war (which has happened) a moderator is basically expected to step in and help rectify the situation. If your answer to this would be "ban all the non-English speakers from chat" then that's what I'm wanting to know from potential new mods.

Answer (score 6):

An answer is brought to your attention by a meta post. The answer is ancient, accepted, and has hundreds of upvotes. It works. It's also inefficient, ill-advised, and **demonstrably dangerous**...

The meta OP is concerned that future visitors will trust the hefty score and check-mark and feels that the few informed down-votes will forever lose to the endless stream of casual up-votes. Indeed, after a week of concerted scrutiny and 100 downvotes from meta, the answer still has an overwhelmingly positive score and continues to earn upvotes.

How do you respond?

Comment: Did ever anyone respond to this situation? I only know of the meta effect which had a considerable influence there but that is not specific to moderators.

Comment: There might be a good moderator candidate question buried somewhere in here, but as you've presented it, this isn't it. When an issue is brought to Meta, it's presented for *the entire community* to consider and respond to, not moderators specifically. And this is the type of issue that it seems to me *should* be handled by the community, not unanimously by a moderator. So unless there's some specific reason why a moderator needs to be involved, and why they should be involved in their official moderator capacity, like a *flag* being raised on that answer, this isn't interesting or useful.

Comment: @CodyGray A moderator's response doesn't have to be _"take unilateral  moderator action"_. There's more to being a moderator than dropping hammers.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I asked a question on Meta: [How to handle multiple duplicate and low quality answers on popular questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336750/3853934) and I haven't received any answers.

What is your solution to this problem? Would you delete such answers?

Comment: Could this be attributed to a limitation of the site itself?  Older questions/content can grow with a lot of similar answers, and not everyone has the default "highest voted answer first" sort on their profile, so it's at least understandable to an extent why duplicate answers exist on popular questions.

Answer (score -3):

How will you handle questions flagged for migration on sites you are not active on?

Comment: There is a standard policy for this, and it's not a particularly contentious issue as far as I'm aware. I'd bet money that any active moderator, and every competent candidate, will say that, for questions that are of high quality and not extremely old, they would ask the moderators on the proposed target site if they would be interested in having the question. So at best, putting this on the questionnaire would just indicate whether the person knows what the standard policies are. Active Meta participation would show the same.

Comment: @CodyGray Recent [meta discussions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285467/236364) put migration at the forefront with approaching migrations in a different mindset. I garuntee within the next year there will be a broadening on how migration works. As SO has the most traffic how SO handles migrations is extremely important.

Comment: Hmm, a broadening? Not so sure. Looks pretty clear to me that Jon et al. are trying to build a wall and get Stack Overflow to pay for it. But at least the question should provide a link to that discussion as context.

Comment: The post is pretty clear when you read the whole thing. Here's a quote that's the center of the proposal:  "Most of the time when we talk about migrating questions, it’s in the context of rescuing content otherwise doomed to deletion. But we already have a ready solution to that problem: historical locks. Now that old questions can only be migrated by employees, migration just isn’t a practical tool for preserving content. So I’d like to propose an alternate theory of migration:

Migrate questions when it saves the asker the effort to reask._"

Answer (score -4):

Context: this is in relation to [this inflammatory question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310795/why-did-a-user-running-for-a-moderator-position-approve-this-edit) asked during last elections. What is your view on a moderator failing to correctly review a fairly obvious bad post?

Do you think a moderator's actions should be exemplary, at all times?

What do you think of a moderator making bad review decisions? (once / multiple / several times)

Comment: Do moderators even get review audits?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Yes, and some SE employees have mentioned they've failed some.

Comment: Asking about review audits changes the nature of your question slightly. There have been several cases, and will continue to be cases, where review audits are erroneous, and therefore "failing" them actually indicates that you are thinking with your brain and making the correct decision.

Comment: Right. I care less about the audits and more about the correctly reviewing part of this.

Comment: @CodyGray I am [well aware](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299184/576767) of that failling audits paradox.

Comment: @CodyGray _"There have been several..."_ -- ummm... "lots" would be a better description. All the upvoted garbage is eligible to be an audit. Also some old posts that used to be OK but are now off topic come up occasionally as well.

Comment: To err is human. I would mostly look at the error rate and use statistics. If it's oustandingly high...

Answer (score -6):

- What is your definition of "spam"? What would it take to convince you to mark a post as "spam", with all of its associated penalties?
- More generally, under what circumstances would you use your moderator powers to unilaterally delete (remove) a post, assuming that it had been flagged by at least one community member? In other words, what specific problems would a post need to have before you would feel comfortable deleting it outright?

(What I'm aiming at here is some insight on how you, as a moderator candidate, would approach the processing of flags and how you would approach the task of cleaning up spam, junk, and other low-quality content from the site. This is something that I think we can *all* agree is a very important task, yet also something where thresholds/definitions/standards vary widely.)

Comment: "What are all of the situations in which you'd ever delete a post?" seems *way* too broad to be useful.

Answer (score -8):

A considerably active and useful (high-rep) user gets banned for voting irregularities, not only for the first time. The behavior is also noticed to be repetitive and the particular use does not seem to be "learning" from previous incidents. However,

- The user is not flagged for any other offensive action (comments/ vandalism/ self-promotion).
- The user has been recognized for many good (great) contributions over the period of his/her membership.

This time, if a ban kicks in for voting irregularities, what should be your verdict for the particular account holder?

- Permanently ban the account (Con: we may lose a valuable and active contributor)
- Keep the account active, just keep on increasing the ban timeout (Con: More voting irregularities to be followed, expected).
- Any other measure to handle this scenario.

Comment: _"A considerably active and useful (high-rep) user gets banned for voting irregularities, not only for the first time."_ Does this actually happen? Are there high-rep users that are stupid enough to mess with the votes?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, this does happen, that was the source of my question. I cannot link to the profile, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score -9):

I would like to ask an important question, taken from [Fall 2015 Moderator Elections](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309768/215552) which I really like a lot. Things have changed a lot with some new rules and new features as well as a lot of new technologies to work on now. In order to get quick success on this network, some people use tactics and practices which are not good and appreciable. As a Moderator, you must ensure and maintain the *quality* and *credibility* here, so:

> Q: A user with less than 2,000 rep is on an edit spree, changing nothing more in all the posts they're editing than one or two small word(s), and their edit is either incomplete or is not an improvement of the post each time. They're up to 45 similar/identical edits in the course of an hour, and a majority of these are being approved by reviewers that aren't paying attention.
>
> How do you handle this editor and the reviewers? How would you handle a similar situation with a user who has full editing privileges?

Comment: I didn't pull this one over for the reason @yellowantphil stated. Edit suggestion rate limits were added to help with low quality edit sprees, so it's much, much less likely to happen. I think there are more important questions to ask this time around.

Comment: I was not aware regarding the limit. Thanks a lot for pointing this to me as well as for the others who were willing to ask something similar :)

Comment: I would just mention that portions of the internet community take words in all capitals as shouting, and would rather see bold and italic used for emphasis. The question you posted is a quotation from someone else's words, so it's best to use the blockquote formatting, rather than header formatting. Just a hint for later posts.

Answer (score -10):

In what direction would you like to help steer SO moderation? How would you prioritize differently?

Fill in the blanks:

> Our current moderators are doing great work. Nevertheless, in my opinion, there is a bit too much of _________ and not quite enough focus on __________. In my tenure as moderator, I would put the spotlight on ________ and not so much on _________.

Comment: Why the _"as opposed to"_? Why do you _have to_ disagree with something going on on SO?

Comment: You don't have to disagree, but if you're going to put increased focus on *x*, then there will naturally be a decrease in the amount of focus you are able to put on *y*. (Or you'll burn out like a flash of light.)

Comment: @Cerbrus What CodyGray says. I'm trying to discourage populist but unfeasible answers of the type "we should do more of X and Y plus more of everything we already do". In other words, I'm asking how the candidate would prioritise differently.  By definition, given a finite amount of disposable time, prioritising something means de-prioritising something else. But true, a legitimate answer could be, "I agree exactly with the perfect equilibrium of beauty that is our current status quo and will work towards maintaining it."

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: It is possible to prioritize something without thinking there's too much focus on the thing you're putting less time into. The fact that it's not as important as the thing you're prioritizing doesn't necessarily mean there's too much of the lower priority thing.

Comment: @Cerbrus Okay, I guess you can put it that way. But do you get what I'm driving at? Could you formulate it more elegantly than I did? Or, is it conceivable that candidates may have a different point of view?

Comment: I'd keep it simple: _"In my opinion, there is not quite enough focus on __________. In my tenure as moderator, I would put the spotlight on that subject."_ I personally don't see the point in having them pick something they don't want to put that much effort into.

Comment: I guess. But wouldn't that be a useful piece of information for the voter? e.g. "I would prioritise X and wouldn't place much emphasis on closing questions." Okay, that's something I can vote for, or against, depending on my preference for X (getting more attention), but also "closing questions" (getting less).

Comment: The question is quite good. Maybe formulate it simply as: "What will your priorities be? What is less important in your opinion?"

Answer (score -12):

What's your view on code only answers? Do these warrant flags? If so, what flag and should they be deleted?

Comment: I'm not going to delete this, as it shows us what the community doesn't want also and will save a similar answer being posted. I note there are a lot of deleted downvoted answers.

Answer (score -13):

What do you think is the moderator's role in the task of engaging novices in the SO community?

Consider that this type of user usually makes mistakes in the daily use of the site and that the experienced users may not have patience with these mistakes.

Comment: It's not typically the role of a moderator to proactively engage users. Their job is more to moderate actions that have already been taken and posts that have already been posted.

Comment: It's a fair question, even if a leading one. A reply could well be "there is no such role; I will have too many other things to do".

Answer (score -14):

If you have run for moderator in a previous election, what do you think kept you from winning and how have you improved since?

Regardless of whether you've run before, how would you like to grow in the next year and how do you think moderating SO fits into that?

Comment: How would candidates know why people did not vote for them the last time around?

Comment: In all fairness, I lost last years election because I ran under my Sterling Archer persona.

Comment: also for the first half of the election your profile picture was him with his "got ____" tshirt on.

Comment: @nvoigt they aren't supposed to magically know, they're supposed to take an educated guess and tell us how they're better this year. It's supposed to be one of those leading questions.

Comment: I lost last election because it was rigged by crooked stack overflow.

Comment: I lost last election because the sheeple did not recognize my greatness in their stupor of ignorance. Having kept a close eye on the community, I now think their collective intelligence and awareness *may* have evolved sufficiently over the past year so I decided to give them another chance.

Answer (score -20):

Let's talk about [review queues](//stackoverflow.com/review).

- Once you are elected, how long would it take for you to get used to the fact that your reviews are binding (and [you can decline flags via reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333899/how-is-it-possible-for-a-moderator-to-decline-a-should-be-closed-flag))?
- Will you participate in [Close Votes](//stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)? *I'm not asking what you think about [SO Close Vote Reviewers](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) - since your close votes are binding as well as your reviews, you don't have to team up with other users in order to make a dent in this gigantic queue.*
- There seem to be three types of manually raised custom flags in the moderator-only flag queue - those that report important issues that actually need mod intervention (e.g *"Multiple unregistered users posted now-deleted non-English answers to this question. Something fishy is going on here"*), those that report everyday issues that are moderation-related but can be handled by the community or already covered by canned flags (e.g *"This post is too damn rude"* or *"This is a well-written feature request that was posted on the main site - please migrate to Meta"*), and those that aren't about moderation at all (e.g *"Please answer my question"*). Which type of flags would you prefer to focus on?

Comment: First point: How can anyone know that, without experiencing it?

Comment: The first one sounds like the only people who could meaningfully answer that would be people that a) have been doing lots of reviews on so, b) have been doing lots of reviews on another site and c) have been elected moderator to another site. That to me seems a little narrow.

Comment: @Cerbrus By guessing?

Comment: @dorukayhan: what would that achieve?

Answer (score -28):

For which you will give more preference - 1) Keeping Site clean by following strict policies of stack overflow like putting downvotes for small mistakes and deleting questions  2)Main focus on helping pepoles & helping them to become good developer....

Comment: #2 is not the point of being a moderator; that's the role of a user. So hopefully they will focus on #1 as that's why we have moderators to begin with.