# Why Caucus badge awarded multiple times in a day for few users?

Tags: support, badges, moderator-election

When seeing the [Caucus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus) badge page, I have two questions:

1. The [2016 Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8) is going to be start in few days, but how few of them received the badge in October?
2. How few of the users received the same badge multiple times in a single day?

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Caucus badge]

Comment: Regarding your first question, I wonder at what point the election counts as started, since [Question Collection](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337191/2016-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-question-collection?cb=1) is happening right now.

Comment: @Steve when there is a dedicated election page, instead of just a Meta topic

Comment: All of those are for past elections. It's probably just user merges, etc.

Comment: @hichris123 agreed. Looking to [this user's activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7002281/ivan-buttinoni?tab=activity) shows a lot of badges on Oct 17, while nothing really important happened to the user that day. So he probably inherited badges from another account.

Answer (score 2):

None of these are for the 2016 election. The 2016 election will be at https://stackoverflow.com/election/8 as you've linked in your post.

If you visit the *election* link in each row you'll see that they all point to previous elections (like https://stackoverflow.com/election/7 (the 2015 election)).