# Is a comment saying that somebody refuses to help due to politics and nationality "unfriendly or unkind?"

Tags: discussion, comments, unfriendly-or-unkind, discrimination

This morning I ran across a question where a member of the SO community commented their refusal to answer the question on the grounds that they will not help anyone from Russia.

[image: Image of three comments: "Got the solution but boycotting Russia" - [name masked out]. "[name masked out]Why should I be responsible for the actions of my president? Why should I be rejected for all this when I'm under 18 and I just can't go to the rally? Do not engage in Russophobia, behave adequately." – [name masked out]. "Sorry about that, not helping you doesn't amuse me. You aren't responsible in this case and Ukranian children too. Don't take it personally, it's temporary. I'm not Russophobic, I just think that everyone has to block Russia in every way to stop Poutine. Good luck anyway." – [name masked out]]

I flagged the comment as:

> It's unfriendly or unkind.

Was this the correct thing to do?  Does SO have a stance on politically motivated comments?

Comment: Maybe relevant here is that there is almost no restrictions on political messages on the profile page and the user name, if I remember the discussion correctly. For example "XXX stands with Ukraine" seems to be a political comment that we are fine with.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the question "was this the correct thing to do?" doesn't depend on what SO's stance on politically motivated comments is; the question should just be: is the comment unfriendly or unkind? If you think it is, then per SO's policy, you should flag it as unfriendly or unkind whether or not it is politically motivated. Whether it is *good* to follow SO's policy in this matter is a separate issue, and that seems to be the contentious point in the debate here, but I don't see anyone arguing that SO's policy doesn't say to flag it if you think it's unfriendly or unkind.

Comment: For this attitude to have any semblance of fairness, one would also need to always check the answerer's country before reading an answer from them, and refrain from reading it if they're from Russia. I doubt anyone's going to do that. :/

Comment: @Trilarion Re _"For example "XXX stands with Ukraine" seems to be a political comment that we are fine with"_ (in a profile or user ID): having that as a comment on your profile page, or your user ID, is qualitatively different to gratuitously posting to an individual that you won't help them because they are Russian. I'd note that the poster vocally refusing to help had absolutely nothing about Ukraine or Russia in their Profile. We are going down a very dangerous road if we permit rude and unkind comments to Russians on this board, and making a mockery of our "be nice" policy.

Comment: Obviously, that comment is not helpful. It’s neither adding technical information nor suggesting improvements. In fact, it’s literally telling the questioner that there’s nothing they can do to convince the commenter to answer. So the only difference between the commenter just not answering and not answering but leaving the comment, is to make the questioner feel bad about it. We delete comments even for being just “obsolete”, but this comment, designated to make the addressee feel bad, is matching the “unfriendly or unkind” criteria 100%.

Comment: Nationalism, politics don't belong on a development-centric site. That also goes for "Black Lives Matter" of the Go language. If I was mod I'd delete/flag all such activity. Also, "we" are not at war, but even if we were such things would be unacceptable.

Comment: After reading through the bulk of the discussions here, there's a lot that could be said, but the only thing I feel like adding is that I am deeply disappointed about how quick some are to justify (their or others') "othering" of users. It's deeply upsetting to me to see some people try to distort prejudice against users of any sort into some sort of a "good" thing. _We all lose_ when people act against one another for things outside of their control; I don't know why it's so hard for some to see that.

Comment: First answer was both unfriendly & offtopic. Second one is just offtopic. Didn't need to comment at all if that is all he had to say. Good flag.

Comment: btw, darn 5 mn window, politics asides, someone commenting "I have the answer but won't tell you" should  at least be flagged for being unfriendly.

Comment: @zcoop98 "We all lose when people act against one another for things outside of their control; I don't know why it's so hard for some to see that." But it isn't totally outside of our control. In the end, everything is connected with everything. Doesn't mean I think this comment was appropriate, but the nice, clean world of development image that is created here, is at least partly an illusion.

Comment: If you are okay with this, please do feel free not to use answers written by Russian people. Just close your eyes and scroll on. Don't let a line of Russian-written code enter your codebase. Be sure to delete OSS written by Russians from your project's dependencies, just so we know you are not some hypocrites and your brave activism is not just for show.

Comment: What really offends me about that post is the unnecessary smearing of a Canadian delicacy.

Comment: Yes, that's horribly unfriendly. The Russian people are a good an honest people just like anyone else and play no part in the asinine invasion by Putin into Ukraine. There are no politics between honest working men and women just trying to better themselves and provide for their family. (now if the questions was from Sergey Lavrov or Putin himself -- that may be appropriate...)

Comment: In addition to everything folks have pointed out about the appropriateness of the comment, that's also just not a boycott

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "The Russian people are a good an honest people just like anyone else and play no part in the asinine invasion by Putin into Ukraine." That is an oversimplification and not true in this generality. Putin alone cannot conquer Ukraine or anything else. He must have lots of helpers everywhere and they are not the victims. Evil men couldn't exist without lots of much less evil but still not particularly good men.

Comment: @Trilarion don't forget Russia has a firm grip on the media. The average Russian dude has no idea that it's actually an invasion.

Comment: @Cerbrus speaking of, we just had a prominent semi-liberal radiostations simply shut down for not cheering the war effort (as well as at least 6 other media), not to mention that those openly protesting just get arrested - so when I see people saying we ain't doing "enough", I just want to laugh and suggest them go visit us for once and see what it's reaĺy like

Comment: @Cerbrus "The average Russian dude has no idea that it's actually an invasion." That again is an oversimplification and probably not true. The average Russian dude may not know what exactly happens and why but rumors will probably have it that the Russian army invaded Ukraine. Even in Russia rumors should spread with light speed. I'm quite sure that the invasion is a known fact within Russia by now.

Comment: It is certainly unfriendly and unkind. Those that want to convey a message will have more effect by refraining from such nasty comments, while at the same time showing support for Ukraine. I do this by changing my profile picture to the Ukraine flag. In my dreams I see many doing that on this platform.

Comment: @trincot " I do this by changing my profile picture to the Ukraine flag. In my dreams I see many doing that on this platform." And that helps? The OP got more attention with a single comment.

Comment: @Trilarion, I am not saying my profile picture has a significant impact, but I don't believe unfriendly comments give a good impression of what I stand for. Attention is nice, but the ends do not justify all means.

Comment: The whole discussion here is about whether or not it's acceptable to say _"I'm not gonna help you because of <politics>"_. Anything we say about how to get that message across otherwise is, imho, off-topic.

Comment: This recent SE question/announcement is relevant to the discussion: [Stack Exchange Q&A access will not be restricted in Russia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376743)

Comment: @Trilarion - Of course it is an over simplification. How detailed can you get in 500 char? But the premise stands. It's not a campaign with wide-spread public support in Russia. Sure you will have some percentage of the population that supports the invasion, just like the couple percent of nutbags in the US that support it as well. Bottom line, the refusal to answer was unfriendly as you cannot paint an entire population with the misdeeds of an insecure dictator and the handful of folks that support him.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's better to further discuss that for example on politics.SE but just here: I think it's more than a handful of folks supporting Putin. That wouldn't work. As I said, you need lots of men on all levels to run a regime.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

Yes, I would even say that you can use the "harassment, bigotry or abuse" flag. This is not an appropriate comment for Stack Overflow.

When answering questions, the person who authored the question doesn't matter. If the user is prejudiced against one nation or another, they should keep it to themselves. Nobody is forced to participate on Stack Overflow.

Comments that ostracize users based on their name, perceived nationality, or race are against our [CoC](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Such comments should be flagged and deleted. If a user shows repeated behaviour, a moderator must step in.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with prejudice. It's essentially one person trying to implement their own personal micro-sanctions against Russia. You might disagree with that person on, say, whether this is a sensible move, or whether it's appropriately targeted, or whether they should leave a comment about it, but it doesn't sound motivated by prejudice any more than the official sanctions.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Feel free to disagree, but for me this is a similar stance to "I don't want to be in the same room with the person from Russia because I don't agree with Russian government's decisions and I think all Russian citizens are to blame for that"

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica How could pre-judging the asker based on their nationality be anything other than prejudice? If they wished to withhold their answer, they could have done it silently.  They have only shamed themselves.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica You can explain away virtually any hostile action as "poorly thought out, poorly targeted sanctions". Motivations aren't the issue; actions are the issue.

Comment: This comment thread probably isn't the place for a long, philosophical debate, but what the commenter did is absolutely a micro-sanction, and I can't disagree with it, and I'm seriously considering doing the same in another context.  Why should the Russian user be "held responsible"? Because he's from a state that is now and absolutely should be an international pariah.  That he's not old enough to vote makes the situation less fair for him, but — just as every single last citizen of Ukraine is currently experiencing in an up-close and personal way — life isn't always fair.

Comment: @mickmackusa: They don't seem to be pre-judging the asker. This doesn't seem to be about the asker at all. Cutting off Stack Overflow answers to Russia is very similar to, say, cutting off Russia from SWIFT, or embargoing Russian gas, or other current or proposed sanctions. There's a more clear innocent individual on the other end here, but there are also innocent individuals on the other end of almost any sanction.

Comment: @user2357112 & Steve, I am really worried about your attitude. This is how terrorism starts. People start hating people from other nations because they invade other countries and cause destruction and horror. In the past, a lot of nations started hating USA for invading other countries which led to hatred of their civilians ([see 9/11 attacks for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_11_attacks#Motives)). I don't condone violence and war, but for the same reason, I don't hate people from other countries for actions of their government. Hatred leads to violence and war.

Comment: @Dharman: You're taking it as given that the people on the other side of this discussion from you are motivated by hatred.

Comment: @Dharman I don't disagree with anything you said, and your refusal to hate is commendable.  However, Alexander Putin is counting on the fact that large numbers of people worldwide will conclude that there's nothing they can do to stop him, so I won't stand in the way of anyone who is trying — no matter how simplistically, futilely, or inappropriately — to do *something*.

Comment: @Dharman: It's not like cutting Russia off from SWIFT (a sanction currently in progress) is an action with no harm to Russian citizens, but that doesn't mean the Western world leaders making that happen all hate Russian people.

Comment: The counterargument seems to boil down to "yes it's unfriendly but we shouldn't have to be friendly in this case". Well, the rules here say that you do have to be friendly. I don't see anyone taking the position that this comment actually is friendly to the Russian user in question.

Comment: As for prejudice, yes, the comment under discussion is prejudicial because it pre-supposes that the person in question is not doing enough to voice their displeasure at the actions of the Russian president, such that they need to be pressured into doing more. Again, the counterargument seems to be that it's justifiable to make that pre-judgement, not that such a pre-judgement isn't being made in this instance.

Comment: @kaya3: Their profile says "Москва, Россия", or in English, "Moscow, Russia". No assumptions there. Regarding point 2, you're assuming it's about the individual at all, which seems to be the main point of contention here. The argument here isn't "people who hate Russians" vs "people who stand against hatred". It's "people who see this action as an attempt to act against Russia" vs "people who see this action as motivated by a judgment of the individual who asked the question".

Comment: (I make no argument regarding whether this micro-sanction is a good idea. I'm just arguing that it's an attempt at a sanction, motivated similarly to the official sanctions, not an act of hate.)

Comment: Yes, I edited my comment after checking the question via the link. I disagree with your summary of who this argument is between; we can think the comment is inappropriate without thinking anything about the private motivations of the person who wrote the comment. I recognise that the comment is an attempt to act against the Russian president Vladimir Putin, while also thinking the comment is unfriendly and prejudicial.

Comment: @kaya3: "we can think the comment is inappropriate without thinking anything about the private motivations of the person who wrote the comment" - but your comment seems to make claims of specific pre-judgments you think the boycotter was motivated by. You said that the boycotter "pre-supposes that the person in question is not doing enough to voice their displeasure at the actions of the Russian president, such that they need to be pressured into doing more" - that looks like a claim that the boycotter is judging and attempting to pressure the individual.

Comment: How else would refusing to answer SO questions written by ordinary Russians have any effect on Vladimir Putin? The only way the boycotter's comment can achieve anything towards his stated goal of stopping Putin is if his comment encourages the Russian person to do more to work against Putin. This is not a presumption about the commenter's private motivations, it follows straightforwardly from what he wrote. And it is prejudicial because a person being Russian does not imply that they need encouragement in that regard. A good number of Russians *are* protesting, at great risk to themselves.

Comment: And to be clear, even if that straightforward inference is wrong and the boycotter's motivations *are* something else that I cannot fathom, that doesn't make his comment appropriate. As I said, we can think it's inappropriate without guessing at his private motivations. You seem to have a definition of "prejudice" which cannot be applied without knowing a person's private motivations, but that is not a definition of prejudice that I recognise or accept. Most of us consider that a blanket policy of refusing to help all people of a specific nationality is, ipso facto, prejudicial.

Comment: @kaya3 *The only way the boycotter's comment can achieve anything...* No.  In the real world (in which we sadly live), a majority of people believe (or are told) there's nothing they can do, and Vladimir Putin gets away with this.  In a better world, perhaps, *every single person in it* rises up and does something unignorable.  Nobody buys Russian vodka. GoFundMe campaigns spring up to subsidize rising fuel costs.  Russia gets banned from the Olympics for the next 20 years.  And even on Stack Overflow, users inject unabashedly political comments, and the community rewards them for it.

Comment: @SteveSummit I think you have misread or misunderstood my comment. I am certainly not saying there is nothing ordinary people can do to stop Putin. I am saying that the only *mechanism* by which the boycotter's actions in this case can help to stop Putin is the mechanism I described. Whether that mechanism might be effective is not something I have taken a position on, let alone whether some *other* action available to the boycotter might be effective via a different mechanism. If you can think of a different mechanism by which refusing to help Russians on SO can stop Putin, I'm all ears.

Comment: @kaya3: My definition of "prejudice" can be found in a [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prejudice): "unreasonable feelings, opinions, or attitudes, especially of a hostile nature, regarding an ethnic, racial, social, or religious group". Prejudice is about "feelings, opinions, or attitudes", which are all motivations. Perhaps you don't accept that, but it's in the dictionary.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica An attitude is not something privately hidden in a person's mind, the boycotter's attitude is expressed plainly in his comment. We don't have to know his internal motivations to know that his attitude towards Russians is that he doesn't want to help them.

Comment: A blanket refusal to provide Stack Overflow answers to Russians isn't all that different from a blanket refusal to buy gas from Russians, which is one of the sanctions major Ukrainian leaders have been pushing for. That one mostly hasn't happened because [in the short term, it'd hurt the rest of the world more than Russia](https://time.com/6151493/russia-oil-gas-embargo-sanctions-ukraine/). Cutting off Stack Overflow answers to Russia could be a similarly motivated (but much less effective) attempt to hit the Russian economy.

Comment: I haven't seen anyone differentiate "because he's Russian" from "because he's currently in Russia", and the two seem to be used fairly interchangeably. To me, the former doesn't sound all that different from saying "because he's white" or "because he's a man": other things people have no choice about and can be unfairly mistreated over because of how others in that group act. It would be somewhat less objectionable to go with the latter (which can still be argued is unfair, but it's more in the spirit of sanctions). But that still doesn't make the comment appropriate for SO.

Comment: @kaya3 The mechanism (and I admit it's a hypothetical) by which the boycotter's actions help to stop Putin is that if enough people do it, a story about it goes viral — "Even on Stack Overflow, users inject unabashedly political comments, and the community rewards them for it" — and that helps *everyone in the world* do more, not just the specific user the boycotter commented against.  But it's abundantly clear that, on balance, the Stack Overflow community is not going to make any kind of an exception in this case, so I have got to bow out.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: It's hard to express a lot of nuance in a Stack Overflow comment character limit, and "currently in Russia" isn't right anyway - for example, I don't think anyone in the discussion wants to lump tourists and other visitors together with Russian citizens.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, it's a similarly motivated attempt to hit the Russian economy. With the goal of encouraging the Russians impacted to protest harder against Putin's invasion of Ukraine. Based on the assumption that the Russians impacted are those who need encouragement. Now imagine if the boycotter makes that comment to another Russian user, and it turns out that Russian user has some family in Ukraine who they are worried about, and other family in Russia who have been arrested for protesting against the invasion of Ukraine. If the boycotter knew that additional ...

Comment: @kaya3: "With the goal of encouraging the Russians impacted to protest harder against Putin's invasion of Ukraine." - or in the hopes that Putin will care about the direct economic effects, or to weaken Russia's overall power, or for other possible reasons. It doesn't have to be about getting people to protest.

Comment: ... information, would he still refuse to help the Russian individual? It seems to me that the comment only makes sense if there is a presumption that the recipient of the comment is somebody who needs to be more negatively impacted by the invasion and its consequences, and that's just not true of all Russians even if you think more negative impact for some or most Russians is desirable.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica "I don't think anyone in the discussion wants to lump tourists and other visitors together with Russian citizens" - why not? Tourists and most other visitors have made a very conscious decision to be in Russia, which is a much more active choice to support Russia compared to just continuing to live in the place you were born. (Russian citizens do get to vote and such, which visitors can't do, but one person is extraordinarily unlikely to make a difference, even if Russia were a democracy where free speech is respected... which it isn't.)

Comment: @mickmackusa Because you're operating from a false premise: the commenter isn't judging the *asker*. The commenter is judging the nation's leadership.

Comment: This answer alienates people by equating a political opinion with bigotry. Is that a CoC violation?

Comment: @jpmc26 If you want it to be a CoC violation to point out bigotry, then you seem to basically be asserting that you want to live in a world where no-one is allowed to criticise the harmful words or actions of anyone else. If you're happy to allow the harmful words and actions, then that position just wouldn't make any sense. If you want to disallow the harmful words and actions as well, then you're faced with the rather significant problem of being unable to discuss what is and isn't harmful, which removes the possibility of consensus and transparency from the moderation of harmful content.

Comment: @NotThatGuy "you want to live in a world where no-one is allowed to criticise the harmful words or actions of anyone else" That's exactly what the CoC attempts to do... except its authors are specifically only applying that to their social/political in-group.

Comment: @jpmc26 No, the CoC attempts to prevent people from causing harm to others. Pointing out potential harm in a reasonable way does not, and will never, fall into a sensible definition of that. This whole dance done by people who oppose ... being nice to others, I guess, where you try to assert an extension of those same considerations of being nice to mean people has always been fallacious and nonsensical.

Comment: @kaya I agree with almost everything you have written here, but I'd point out that _"refusing to answer Stack Overflow questions **written by ordinary Russians**"_ presupposes that those asking questions really are _"ordinary Russians"_. It would be naive to assume that the Russian poster is _"ordinary"_ or  _"under 18"_. Maybe, maybe not. But regardless of that, it is clearly against the CoC here to be rude or unkind to them regardless of one's political views.

Comment: @jpmc26 I suggest you read up on "The Paradox of Tolerance" - that's a well-worn debate and there's no need to have it yet again here.

Comment: @SteveSummit A news story like that would only make SO look bad. It can't raise awareness: people already know what is happening in Russia. And it isn't a sanction because there is no mechanism by which this harms the resources of those actually causing the problem. Yes, other sanctions often do affect the average Russian citizen, but this is an unfortunate byproduct, not the intent. Boycotting answering Russians is not some calculated way to harm those in power. It's just the usual discrimination that happens when nations go to war. Why would anti-bigotry policies make an exception for that?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica As I said, this isn't a sanction, as there is no way by which this reduces the resources of the people in power in Russia. That is not the same as the Russian gas boycott, which targets the rich oligarchs of the country, the ones who are effectively part of the government. Yes, it's true that sanctions like this will harm the ordinary Russian citizen, but that is an unfortunately byproduct. It's still bigotry to directly try to target them--the same bigotry that tends to happen in war, where the actions of those in power are conflated to belong to the people.

Comment: @kaya3 I suggest you recognize that "tolerance" is self contradictory as an absolute moral value. I've encountered the attempt to frame it as a paradox, but the reality is that a value system based on tolerance is logically incoherent. Those who attempt to claim tolerance as a virtue are in actuality insisting on agreement with a separate set of values and refuse to tolerate any dissent from it. Typically, it's an identitarian worldview that demands affirmation of certain lifestyles that have been historically considered immoral.

Comment: @trlkly A government is not an independent entity from a country's citizens. Russia's government is composed of its citizens, and the citizens are (generally) willingly submitting to the edicts of their leaders. If the population of Russia has failed to curb tyranny in its leaders, they bear the responsibility for that and the vast majority of responsibility for eliminating it. Attempting to hold them accountable is not bigotry.

Comment: @NotThatGuy You're not pointing out potential harm. You're ascribing nefarious motives to a user on the basis they want to do something to demonstrate their opposition to an actual military invasion. As for the CoC, absolutely not. It was crafted specifically to give a reason for the silencing of particular social and political opinions, while simultaneously demonizing anyone holding them and being totally inconsiderate to the harm caused to them. Something designed to enforce kindness doesn't cause an incident like what happened to Monica, the polar opposite of kindness and reasonableness.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Let me clarify: you could easily say the comment is inappropriate and misguided without insisting that its author is a bigot. You can easily oppose the comment without vilifying its author. But you instead have chosen to insist that it is pure bigotry and cannot possibly be a misguided attempt at doing some minor good. You're not trying to be understanding. You're trying to ostracize people by deeming them inherently evil. You are actively being unkind, and you feel fully justified in doing so. *Your own actions* demonstrate the ugly truth about the CoC.

Comment: Wanted to add another misconception I saw here: Hate isn't the same as rage. As an extreme example, a concentration camp officer gassing people with a smile on his face is still being utterly hateful. Hate can be quite "cold" and seem almost like apathy.

Comment: @jpmc26: _"you could easily say the comment is inappropriate and misguided without insisting that its author is a bigot"_ How is _"That comment is misguided"_ any different from _"That comment is bigoted"_? Both those statements are evaluating the comment, and by your logic, only the latter is suddenly applying a negative judgement to the author, while the former _doesn't_? That's a double standard, mate.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yeah, this really isn't the place for you to go on this kind of tirade against tolerance and "lifestyles that were historically considered immoral" - presumably you are talking about me and a lot of my friends and family. Well, I don't tolerate people who think I shouldn't be tolerated on the basis of who I am, and I have no moral qualms whatsoever about not tolerating those people. Neither does the Stack Overflow community in general. So if your point is just to say, "you're intolerant of intolerance, gotcha!" as if that is any kind of insight, the answer is "yes, yes I am".

Comment: @jpmc26 So yeah, you basically seem to be saying we're not allowed to call words what they are to not offend those who said them. And that just circles back to what I said before: you seem to fallaciously want people to evade consequences for the harmful things they've said in order to avoid causing harm to them. "[The CoC] was crafted specifically to give a reason for the silencing of particular social and political opinions" - those "opinions" you're referring to is bigotry, so... yeah, pretty much.

Comment: @jpmc26 Had you simply said "This isn't bigotry because ...", while I probably still would've disagreed with you, I likely wouldn't have found that to be too objectionable. Also, that would've been a whole lot more constructive and reasonable than objecting to the idea of even discussing what is and isn't bigotry at all.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Tolerance means finding a peaceable way to continue an interaction despite irreconcilable disagreement. That's not at all what you're doing. You're demanding that a particular set of opinions with which you disagree is not allowed to be uttered because you've deemed them to be inherently evil. It's quite the opposite of tolerance. The comment in question is *not* bigotry, at all. Your insistence is nothing more than an effort to drum up a mob against it, the opposite of tolerance.

Comment: @Cerbrus "How is 'That comment is misguided' any different from 'That comment is bigoted'?" The latter asserts nefarious motives, hateful thinking, and malicious desires and drums up a raging mob. The former acknowledges good intentions and has a calming effect. They're not even close to the same thing.

Comment: @NotThatGuy The people who made those judgements were the same people who made the CoC what it is, and they crafted the CoC specifically the reflect the identitarian world view that produced those judgements. Monica might refrain from making the connection between the two, but that doesn't mean I have to. I suppose I am being slightly repetitive, but only because you're repeating the same unjustified claims I've already refuted without providing any justification for them. That said, I've also ensured I provided new points in opposition to the ways you've tried to reframe your own position.

Comment: @jpmc26 Like I said, there's no reason to pretend this conversation is still in any way constructive.

Comment: @NotThatGuy No, I grasped it. You just didn't grasp mine. 1. Rephrasing is common in debate. It's a way of trying to get past a person's misconceptions. 2. You're doing it, too, so you're being a hypocrite. 3. You've repeatedly asserted that the comment is bigotry, despite the fact that it almost certainly is not motivated by any kind of negative or derogatory feelings or thoughts toward Russian people as an entire group, as I described before, and you failed to provide any justification for continuing to make that assertion.

Comment: @NotThatGuy You said, "So yeah, you basically seem to be saying we're not allowed to call words what they are to not offend those who said them." Does that statement not support calling the comment in question bigotry?

Comment: @NotThatGuy Also, it's becoming clear to me that you missed the Socratic nature of my original comment. The purpose of it was to demonstrate the inherent inconsistency in trying to build a moral framework around the values you're trying to assert. Your value system would prevent you from taking the actions you wish to take if actually applied logically, meaning the values you claim are either not the actual values you're using or you're not reasoning about them logically.

Comment: ^ I'm with @NotThatGuy. You keep repeating your opinion as if that changes anything, jpmc26

Comment: I'm not intolerant of people who disagree with me. If you want to be homophobic then be homophobic, just do it in the privacy of your own home, don't force it down our throats, OK?

Comment: @Dharman - What you describe is exactly what American businesses are doing to their customers in Russia by suspending their sales. American companies are initiating political policies by suspending their sales, banning or suspending channels, all before they are legally required. I completely agree with you, it’s sort of like the request I read, to suspend the SO RU community that doesn’t hurt the political elite in Russia (RUSO is irrelevant to them).If Russia was suspended from SWIFT, that would be required by policy, enforced by an organization like the UN. The OG comment was inappropriate.

Comment: @kaya3 How is that any more tolerant than saying, "I'm not intolerant of people who disagree with me. If you want to be homosexual then be homosexual, just do it in the privacy of your own home, don't force it down our throats, OK?" Wouldn't you consider the unwillingness to be exposed to it bigotry?

Comment: @jpmc26 Because there's nothing wrong with being gay, whereas there is something wrong with discriminating against people for being gay. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: @kaya3 Exactly. You're not being tolerant of people who disagree with that. You're saying your values are correct and there's no room for disagreement.

Comment: I'm not trying to be tolerant of those people.

Comment: @kaya3 Then you're not tolerant, so what's wrong with admitting you don't consider tolerance a fundamental value? Why try to advocate for tolerance when you don't practice it?

Comment: I'm also not tolerant of bullying, theft, or lots of other things. The problem here is that you just don't understand what "tolerance" means as a value.

Comment: If your beef with me is really just that I'm not a moral relativist and you think I should be, well, I will make a note of your opinion in my book of Very Important Opinions. Is there anything else I can do for you today?

Comment: @kaya3 No, *you* don't. I already explained the definition. Tolerance is about finding a peaceable way to interact with people in spite of fundamental disagreement. Tolerance by definition cannot exist without a known conflict of beliefs. You're using the term to describe something other than what it means, and you're doing so because you want to ascribe the moral connotations of "tolerance" to yourself and deny it to others despite not actually practicing it. I just want you to be clear and honest with yourself and others.

Comment: @kaya3 I don't want you to be a moral relativist. I just want you to accept and be willing to admit that you're not, others don't have to be, either, and that others can have different value systems and live by them in public even though you don't like it.

Comment: If the different value system you want to live by is that you don't want gay people to exist in public and you want to *not* be called a bigot for saying so, then no, you cannot "live by" those values alongside me. Not calling bigots bigots is not tolerance, it's appeasement.

Comment: @kaya3 Bigotry is not defined by *what* you believe. It's a method (a logically invalid one) of arriving at a conclusion. Your attitude can be described as bigotry against people with traditional sexual values, because you're assuming all disagreement with homosexuality takes the specific form you describe, comes from hatred, and/or is based on irrational thinking. So again, you're using terms incorrectly because you want to ascribe a specific moral connotation to yourself and deny it to others, despite not practicing those values.

Comment: Please, if you really want somewhere you can say bigoted things and not be called a bigot, you need to find a safe space for bigots - try /pol/ or Stormfront. Stack Overflow is not a safe space for bigots, if you say bigoted things here you will be called a bigot, *and that is a good thing*.

Comment: @jpmc26 there are also people who believe that nazism is the right ideology, it does not make them people with "alternative views", it makes them bigots in the most straightforward sense of the word. Not much difference with what you are going out of your way to defend here.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine ... See, that right there is the proof that your attitude *is* bigotry. You're equating, "I think homosexuality is wrong, but that doesn't justify violence," with an ideology that put people in gas chambers. They're not even remotely the same thing, and the refusal to listen to people enough to understand the difference is one of the most blatant forms of prejudice (literally the act of pre-judging someone) in history. It's the very definition of "othering" people.

Comment: @jpmc26 "I already explained the definition". "Tolerance by definition cannot...". "you're using terms incorrectly". You seem to be using your own definitions as objective fact when this is simply not how English works, and that's highly detrimental to constructive discussion.

Comment: @jpmc26 any value that asserts that a person X is less than or should be *treated less than* a person Y if they *are* Z (not what they believe, but are) has the same mechanism. I am not equating anything except for that. That mechanism is called bigotry, and you can try all the sophistry in the world to try to assert that there is a paradox, but there is no wriggling out of the definition of what being bigoted is. That said, I see you will be repeating the same thing over and over no matter the arguments - if you like to defend the *actions* in question, I just feel pity for you - good luck.

Comment: @NotThatGuy https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tolerance "sympathy or indulgence for beliefs or practices differing from or conflicting with one's own" At the very least, the dictionary recognizes what I'm saying.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine "any value that asserts that a person X is less than or should be treated less than a person Y if they are Z (not what they believe, but are) has the same mechanism." That clearly isn't the value system I described, so yes, you're being prejudiced by assuming that it is. Believing that a person's acts are wrong is not the same thing as believing they are or should be treated as inferior. And in fact, you are *practicing* the act of treating people that way based on disagreement with your beliefs.

Comment: @jpmc26 "people with traditional sexual values" - tradition is not an excuse for discriminating against people, or otherwise objecting to the way they are, because they were born a certain way.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I didn't say that it is. The term is merely descriptive of *what* values we're talking about, not indicative of how they can be justified. I'm not interested in debating how they can be here; I'm just saying there *are* reasoned, non-prejudicial ways of arriving at that conclusion. I'm not even asking you to change your mind about sexual values; I'm just asking you to recognize that there are people who disagree with you and do not possess hatred, malice, or irrationality toward those who don't go along with your beliefs. Some people simply don't think it's set at birth.

Comment: I find it _very_ intolerant that you can't tolerate the fact that other people have different opinions of what "tolerance" means, @jpmc26. You're insulting our intentions, villainizing us when we describe bigoted comments as "bigotry". Practice what you preach, dude.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't preach "tolerance," fundamentally anyway. (I would say that tolerance does arise from other values in many cases.) I've said over and over that it's not possible to build a consistent moral framework around it. I'm just holding you all to your own value system, or at least asking you to come to terms with and admit what your actual value system is in practice.

Comment: _"Tolerance means finding a peaceable way to continue an interaction despite irreconcilable disagreement.", "You're not being tolerant of people who disagree with that."_  And you dumped a _merriam-webster_ definition in here... Yea, you're not preaching tolerance.

Comment: @jpmc26 You keep flaunting your self-perceived moral and/or intellectual superiority, yet you've done little more here than demonstrate a lacking on both counts by supporting objectionable things and seemingly failing to understand most of what was said here. If you spend less time making claims about what other people mean and believe and what words mean to villainize those people, and you spend more time asking them what they mean and believe and how they define words to understand those people, you'd probably start having discussions that are infinitely more constructive.

Answer (score 164):

To be blunt, I feel that [this earlier answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416244/1079354) covers the general CoC policy.  To reiterate it: **stating that you are intentionally not helping someone because of any perceived attribute about that person is bigotry,** and is absolutely subject to being punished under the CoC.  Flag any comments that do so.

There's a lot of people who are super-charged about the happenings in the world. I feel like there's a lot of frustration and a whole sense of "there must be something I can do about this," and there likely is—there's a host of things you can do to get involved in this effort. You should look to consult the appropriate authorities for suggestions: for instance, getting in touch with someone in your government to see if they have some suggestions would be a start.

But I'm quite disappointed that this needs to be reinforced here and now:

## You don't get to "other" someone on Stack Overflow.  Period.

If Stack Overflow Inc. decides to block certain nations from their site, that's some decision they get to make, but it's not something that we—who are bound by the CoC—get to "just do."

So this hot mess about "micro-sanctions" needs to be dealt with by a moderator in the most "give this person a wonderful time-out" fashion.

So… anyone who engages in behavior that actively others someone on the site—flag it as a violation of the CoC.

Comment: Exactly. I am amazed that anyone here feels entitled to make negative comments towards another poster on SO with the (bogus) arguments that it is somehow a "justifiable violation", or that it is not personal, or that it is not bigotry. None of us are free to ignore the CoC simply because we disagree with it.

Comment: @skomisa Well then you have to first be amazed that people have not read the code of conduct and don't even know it exists.

Comment: Bigotry - "obstinate or unreasonable attachment to a belief, opinion, or faction".  What is obstinate or unreasonable about a SO user boycotting Russian users?  It may be against SO rules, you may disagree with it but it's not bigotry. Russia is an international pariah.

Comment: it is unreasonable to shame SO users simply because they are from or reside in Russia, regardless of what their country/government has done. Chances are you're only attacking someone who agrees with you but can't do anything about it.

Comment: @AlanDev-boycottRussia: Boycotting is _fine_. Getting in someone's face and telling them _"Nanana I know the answer but I'm not gonna give it to you because of where you're from"_ is petty, childish and bullying. In sort, a CoC violation.

Comment: @AlanDev-boycottRussia:  Go ahead and boycott them.  But the *instant* you type something about that here on the Stack Exchange network, your comment will be subject to the CoC.  That's the *only* contentious point I'm making here; you are absolutely under no obligation to engage with anyone for any reason, but the instant you do, your engagements are subject to the established code of conduct.

Comment: "You don't get to 'other' someone on Stack Overflow. Period." Then you have to stop accusing people of bigotry.

Comment: @jpmc26: That's not what "Othering" means. We can accuse thieves of being a thief. We can accuse bigots of bigotry. We _can't_ accuse people form a specific country of being "less" than someone else. That _is_ bigotry.

Comment: @Cerbrus First, when you accuse someone bigotry, you are absolutely implying they are "less" than someone else. In modern Western culture, a bigot is considered to be so ignorant and evil that they *deserve* to be held in utter contempt. So yes, that's what you're doing. Secondly, the comment says *nothing* that implies that the question author is less than anyone. At *most,* it implies the Russian people are not fulfilling their responsibility to ensure their government remains just, which, if anything, implies they have worth by asserting they're capable of fulfilling that responsibility.

Comment: @AlanDev-boycottRussia I appreciate how you left out the (very relevant) *second half* of the definition you quoted: "...in particular, prejudice against a person or people on the basis of their membership of a particular group"

Comment: @forresthopkinsa Well spotted! That piece of deceitful cherry picking deserves some kind of medal. In a way you have to admire the shamelessness of someone who finds a quote that completely refutes their argument, carefully elides the part that proves them wrong, and triumphantly posts the distortion that remains.

Comment: @forresthopkinsa The second part of the definition is not relevant because the first part is violated. It is *entirely* reasonable to take action against a nation (including their citizens) as a whole when that country's leadership is invading another country merely to take possession of its land and resources. The citizens have failed to ensure they are led by just leaders in such a case, and so accountability is reasonable, even if you disagree with it. There's no cherry picking here, just focus on the aspect relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @Makoto "That's the only contentious point I'm making here..." Alan is contending with your claim that this is an example of bigotry, so your assertion that whether the comment is subject to the CoC is *not* the only contentious point. In fact, Alan doesn't seem to be challenging that point at all or even the notion that the comment should be deleted, only the classification of the comment as bigotry. He's probably doing so because throwing around claims of bigotry tends to create rage mobs.

Answer (score 129):

Let's not forget that we're building a repository of Q&A for the community at large. Today one might be helping a Russian person get unstuck, tomorrow it might be someone else getting unstuck by the same question.

Ultimately, this resource is populated by *volunteers*, who will end up helping good and bad people alike, on their own will. If someone really doesn't want to answer questions from Russian askers due to the horrible actions of a dictator, that is their prerogative.

Still, two wrongs don't make a right. Flag such comments for removal.

---

All of this notwithstanding the various ways each of us can help in these troubled times. Take care when sharing information online; look for legitimate organizations to donate to; raise awareness to local entities that can bring some kind of change. These things are up to you, not to a programming Q&A platform.

Comment: If someone asks a question that's *actually* of the quality we want for a long-term repository, you have a good point. However, let's be realistic: how many questions actually fall into that category? Most of the posts here are so one-of that you may help some Russian developer build their alternative to SWIFT to bypass sanctions, while nobody else ever reads your post. This is a very unusually impactful moment and we must consider the impact of our actions precisely, not just philosophically.

Comment: @DEATHtoPUTIN-GLORYtoUKR Like the sands of a beach, only a few of them will become pearls. Still, yes, I strive for quality, like many other curators here so. Can't speak for those who don't care that much. On that other point, we all know how this kind of knowledge is a double edged sword.

Comment: @GLORYTOUKRAINEPutinMustGo Let’s not forget that the everyday Russian people are suffering massively for this. They effectively received no government help at all for COVID, and just when their economy was starting to come back, this happens throwing decades down the toilet. Consider that most of their people don’t actually support Putin’s decision to invade and are just trying to survive! (Even if every single person in Russia supported Putin, how would you identify one? There are VPNs & people can pick any name they want (including Russian-Americans who aren’t even in Russia, etc.))

Comment: "Let's not forget that we're building a repository of Q&A for the community at large.". You mean "we're creating content for free that is being sold by StackOverflow inc.". Some people tend to forget that there is a company here, not some benevolent "community". A company that will Monica you at will, except they can't handle the PR disaster anymore so they'll probably be real careful from now on.

Answer (score 78):

> Was this the correct thing to do?

Yes, it was. The comment was clearly made in violation of the current [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) under the "no bigotry" ruling. Speech with the sole intention to alienate a person based on their attribute (regardless of what that attribute is) is, [by definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bigotry), bigotry. Just to remind of the wording from the CoC:

> No bigotry.
> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples.

A comment designed to make a person of a certain nationality unwelcome is no less bigoted than one aimed at a person of a certain race, no matter the rationalization (not to mention that even thinking that any such action will, in the slightest, help bring the conflict to an end is utterly absurd).

> Does SO have a stance on politically motivated comments?

Actually, they have. It's right there, in the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> This site is all about getting answers. **It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.**

If a comment is not directly or tangentially related to the content of the post, it is *at best* noise distracting from the goal of this network of sites: that is, to build a repository of high-quality questions and answers to practical (or theoretical, depending on the site) problems. Anything else has no place on Stack Overflow (meta sites being a notable exception).

Comment: You nailed it. I'd only add that SO might consider explicitly adding **nationality** to the list you quoted from the CoC. That is: _"based on race, gender, sexual orientation, **nationality** or religion — and those are just a few examples"_. Why? Because it makes it even harder for contrarians to argue the fiction that targeting users based on their nationality isn't bigotry.

Comment: @skomisa the longer you make that list, the more reason you give people to say _"but __X__ isn't mentioned so it's fine!"_ I'd advice _against_ adding any more specificity to that list...

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't follow your argument. As more sources of bigotry are explicitly defined, opportunities to make the (bogus) argument _"but X isn't mentioned so it's fine!"_ necessarily decrease. But [the open ended wording on the CoC is sloppy](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). There needs to be an unequivocal statement that leaves no wiggle room, regardless of the form of bigotry: **We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people.** would cover it nicely, and they almost have that now.

Comment: @skomisa I agree - when fetching the quote, I was slightly surprized to not see nationality in the explicit list (it's not like one has to dig deep to find that this kind of bigotry is highly widespread). Frankly, I am still in a bit of a shock that the whole discussion happened in the first place - that anyone could think that bigotry could be "justified" depending on *circumstances*.

Comment: @skomisa I feel _"and those are just a few examples"_ covers all other cases just fine. There has to be some room for interpretation, so the mods can apply that outside of the explicitly mentioned examples. If you add more examples of what's wrong, you decrease the importance of the situations that aren't mentioned.

Answer (score 62):

If you want to be political in your profile, we generally allow that. Your profile is mostly yours (still subject to the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), obviously). If you want to protest governmental actions there [have at it](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe-stands-with-ukraine). We have users who still support [Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/244695), for that matter. Politics are generally fine there.

If you don't want to help users who might be in Russia or have Russian usernames *just don't help them*. Nobody is forcing you to help anyone on the platform.

Where this crossed a line was a user said this in comments (this is my paraphrase to get the point across)

> I don't like the actions of Russia currently. Your name and profile say you're from Russia. I could answer your question but, because I don't like your country, I won't, and neither should anyone else.

That's not acceptable, regardless of the subject. Maybe the country of Russia is engaged in evil currently (I certainly won't dispute that), but *this is how you perpetuate the problem*. Blaming a whole class of people for the actions of their country is unacceptable. If they had said the same things, but because of their race, religion, gender, etc. instead, I doubt we'd even be discussing whether or not to flag it.

The TL;DR here is saying (or implying) that we can't (or shouldn't) help someone on Stack Overflow because we don't like something about who the user is (or where they are located) is bigotry, and a clear violation of the Code of Conduct. Protest the country, not the user.

Comment: I've been suspended multiple times for saying _"Israel is an Apartheid State"_ in my profile, or on my site-name. I wouldn't say _"generally allowed"_. But by any means it's certainly _more_ allowed then in comments. And everyone here is right to say that stuff should stay out of comments/questions/answers. (Just so you don't give a false sense of security.)

Comment: @NOWARWITHRUSSIA: This answer specifically mentions that it is OK to protest specific _governmental actions_. Protesting entire governments? I'd say that is still OK. But an entire nation? That gets close to protesting against a specific _nationality_, and the consensus seems that the latter is not OK.

Comment: @NOWARWITHRUSSIA It's worth noting, in that case, that you set that username *network-wide* and [you have a lot of accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/42701/evan-carroll?tab=accounts). I can see why, say, [Judaism.SE] might suspend you for that (I don't know if they did and each community has its own rules and moderators). You were not suspended on SO for that username, nor is your current political username an issue. My point is you can be political in your username and profile as long as you don't run afoul of the CoC.

Comment: So, I could have a SO profile name: "Supports Russia, nuclear war and complete eradication of homosapiens"  and I won't be deplatformed?

Comment: @TheMaster We actually have had to remove several usernames like that recently. "Supports Russia" would be fine. "nuclear war" is iffy, and "eradicating all humans" would be trolling and/or calling for violence. Calling for violence in any form is a clear CoC violation

Comment: @Machavity I don't know where you're going with that. Mi Yodeya suspending a jew for standing against Israel is no more or less heinous than a Catholic StackExchange suspending a Catholic for speaking against the systemic cover-up of child molestation. You'd have to have a very superficial understanding of Judaism to claim that my in-group excuses critiques of racism, occupation, and apartheid: that's Zionism, not Judaism.

Comment: As they should be.

Comment: @MSalters Certainly you would protest against Nazi Germany, Saudi Arabia, ISIS, and Fascist Italy because the states themselves embrace ideas and philosophies that are contradictory to a civil, humane, and democratic society. Speaking against a state is by any means is not speaking against the people of the territory, and a CoC is focused on protecting people. Presumably, "Stop Russian Aggression" would be ok (even though the Russian state contests that they're the aggressor -- they're wrong), but "Stop Israeli Apartheid" is not ok?

Comment: You can protest them all you want. What you can't do is attack users on this platform. It is a fairly simple concept.

Comment: @KevinB I **never** attacked a user. I criticized a state.

Comment: Then your complaint isn't relevant to this discussion

Comment: @KevinB Allow me to correct you: the discussion **I started,** without you, was in response to _"If you want to be political in your profile, we generally allow that. Your profile is mostly yours (still subject to the Code of Conduct, obviously). If you want to protest governmental actions there have at it."_ I protested government actions and **my profile and my nickname were mod-cleared and I was suspended**. I never insulted anyone neither Jew nor Israeli -- just critiques of state policy, apartheid, Zionism. But if this discussion is no longer about _that_, then carry on. It's all yours.

Comment: The discussion you started isn't relevant to this question or this answer. If you think the statement that was removed from your profile was incorrectly removed, that's a discussion for another question.

Comment: You keep your changing your stance. Is it that you don't like the discussion I started that you injected yourself in, or that my commentary isn't relevant to the discussion I started? My caveat is that there is **much** less leeway given to profiles and nicknames for criticizing state policy than this answer would lead one to believe. And for that reason, I would advise treading with caution. If you think that's not relevant, fine -- we clearly disagree.

Comment: @NOWARWITHRUSSIA this isn't a discussion forum, you've been here 12 years so you should know that by now. There is nothing wrong with the question you're posing, all KevinB is saying is that you should post a new question about it and I agree with them.

Comment: I'm confused. I find the user below very active and helpful on the topic of SwiftUI. The only "questionable" thing I see is 'Boycott Russia' in the profile. Is that why this person was suspended? Maybe I missed something. https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi

Comment: @Marcy no, political profiles are allowed as long as they follow the CoC (this one specifically is fine). It is likely an unrelated issue.

Answer (score 32):

Yes.

If someone had commented a month ago or two years ago or... that they would refuse to help someone from China because of the atrocities committed by the CCP, or if someone today was of the opinion that Putin was justified and commented that they refused to help a Ukranian because of the country's resistance to Putin, I don't think there'd be much question.

The comment was unkind.

Answer (score 13):

You did the right thing by flagging the response. SO is not the right platform to share personal/political opinions.

I have been so proud of the technical community, the people of different nationalities that I work with in my office, we may have many political differences, but when I work as an Engineer/programmer, my priorities are only related to my work.

People from my team have never let our personal biases or opinions seep into our work because we know our purpose at work. Similarly, SO is created with a specific purpose to cater to the needs of a specific community (I believe it is irrespective of their social/political identity). Let's keep it that way.

I won't call out anyone as right or wrong for having any opinion, we can always have such discussions on Facebook, Instagram, YouTube comments. But let's keep some places untouched by hate and politics.

Answer (score 12):

First,

> Is a comment saying that somebody refuses to help due to politics and nationality "unfriendly or unkind?"

**Yes, absolutely.** You did well to report it.

As Dharman already [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416244/507738), it violates the Code of Conduct. But also:

- Not posting an answer also affects the rest of the community, because other community members may as well have found the answer the commenter would have written, useful.
- The comment is excluding a person because of nationality, which is discrimination.
- As Holger [already mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416242/is-a-comment-saying-that-somebody-refuses-to-help-due-to-politics-and-nationalit?cb=1#comment897028_416242), the comment does not add any value.

Further, if you really feel you don't want to answer a question because the asker belongs to a certain group (which I object), then just [ignore it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416289/507738) and don't place a comment at all.

Answer (score 7):

> Does SO have a stance on politically motivated comments?

Aside from whether it's "unkind" and so on, it's highly off-topic as a comment.

You can maybe talk about politics in a chat room, and say what you will in your profile -- but not in a comment on the main site.

Comment: Well your opinion might be OK as a comment, though others have already made the same point. But you are _explicitly_ choosing to duck answering the actual question that was asked! I'm not understanding why you chose to post this as answer at all.

Comment: The question is whether SO has a stance on comments and I'm saying that yes it does, i.e. that comments must be on-topic etc., and that a "political" comment such as this one isn't on-topic -- see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) in the Help -- and as such a moderator will want to delete (and users should refrain from posting) that kind of comment.

Comment: Nonsense - the question is absolutely not _"whether SO has a stance on comments"_. The question is asked very explicitly in the title: _"Is a comment saying that somebody refuses to help due to politics and nationality "unfriendly or unkind?"_. It is then asked again in the question: _"I flagged the comment as: It's unfriendly or unkind. Was this the correct thing to do?"_. Your answer ignores the question that was asked. The answer can only be yes or no (with an explanation of course).

Comment: "Aside from whether it's unkind" (as I wrote), it was correct to flag the comment.

Comment: That's like answering _"How do I add 1 to 2 in <language>"_ with _"Aside from the addition, you can use <tech> to communicate the result to some client."_ It doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -47):

Yes, it looks like you did it right. But as [@Larnu said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416242/is-a-comment-saying-that-somebody-refuses-to-help-due-to-politics-and-nationalit#comment896787_416245):

> Then put a note in your profile stating that you dont support Russia and won't be contributing to any questions from those from Russia

the problem is not, as [@Dharman said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416244/11573842), with:

> the person who authored the question doesn't matter

but with the fact that this was written in the *comment*, not *profile*.

**Taking into account that in SO, profiles can be political**, we could ask: what to do if somebody will write in the comment "I know the answer, but because of the statement in my profile, I won't help you"? And I think that you can only mark it as "spam". This is not unfriendly, unkind, harassment, bigotry or abuse **if the reason can exist in the profile**. And as @Larnu showed, it can exist in the profile.

I must add something regarding "targeting specific person". Please remember that this problem is similar to law - law is not targeting a specific person, but a characteristic. The user can clearly write this in profile. Of course, we can later check if this is true - if this user really targets characteristics, not the person. But if this user will write a comment directed at some specific person, this is not evidence of targeting a person and not characteristic. We would need to show that this user wrote a comment to some person with specific characteristics and didn't write to another person which had this characteristic but could do this (i.e. answered the question without a similar comment).

For reference:

[Should political (possibly offensive) content be allowed in user's profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270347/should-political-possibly-offensive-content-be-allowed-in-users-profile)

Comment: If you put a statement in your profile saying you refuse to help Russian users then that's not harrassment of any specific person, but if you comment on a specific person's question to say the same thing (whether or not you say it directly or point at the same statement written elsewhere), it is targeted at that individual user. So I don't think your argument is convincing at all.

Comment: @kaya3 No, as long as you would write this comment to all users which have some specific characteristic, this is not specific for some person. This is the same as with the law - if you punish all people who are thieves, even if it concerns on specific people (they have names etc.) this is not specific for some person, but for specific characteristic.

Comment: "*No, as long as you would write this comment to all users which have some specific characteristic, this is not specific for some person.*" if that's the case, do expect a modflag for flooding the site with useless comments.

Comment: Yes, of course, this is what I said - it is spam.

Comment: Which isn't friendly. And I'd certainly consider a wide spread of such comments as harassment and abuse.

Comment: @gss you seem to ignore the part "No bigotry" from the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), I would count that as a Rude or Abusive flag if anyone makes such comments.

Comment: *"No, as long as you would write this comment to all users which have some specific characteristic, this is not specific for some person"* - your argument seems to be that as long as somebody harrasses everyone in a certain group then it's not harrassment. I disagree, on the basis of the meaning of the word "harrassment".

Comment: Ok, but it looks like you are igonoring the fact that profiles can be political. It is very clear in this site.

Comment: No, I'm not ignoring that at all. I'm saying that there is no loophole saying it is OK to harrass somebody by writing a comment telling them to read a statement written in your profile, as opposed to harrassing that person by making the same statement in the comment itself. You can put it on your profile without harrassing individual users by telling them to go read your profile.

Comment: Nobody is overlooking that. You're just trying to make a claim that profiles and comments are the same. They aren't.

Comment: No, you are wrong. I clearly said that you can't write the same in the profile and in the comment.

Comment: @gss so let's frame the situation differently. the profile of user A states "i am an evangelical Christian, and follow the word of god" they then comment on a question by a user B who has a rainbow or similar pride symbol in their profile picture. User A's comment reads "I can answer this question but choose not to, see my profile for details". Is that really not harassing the person just with 1 extra step. the only reason you would make such a comment is to hope to bring attention to this factor you believe people who also not answer this question the bases of.

Comment: @Nifim perhaps I should improve my answer. Generally, I think it should be possible to have political profile and let others know about your profile and this should be seen only as spam / off topic, because you don't have to check the profile. I mean - I feel it is controversial, but for me the solution would be to prohibit political profiles. Otherwise we would have the situation when profiles can be political, but then you can't say about them (in some context), because it can be harassing. That's a nonsense for me. If something can exists, then it can exists very openly.

Answer (score -49):

No. It should be flagged as, "It's no longer needed." It contributes nothing to the content of the post, so it doesn't belong there. It's not bigotry; it is in no way, shape, or form a personal judgement or insult against this individual user. It's a personal, political motivation for the user's choice not to engage in the question. You don't have to *like* the motivation, but SO has no rules (and cannot have any) about **inaction** on the platform. Inaction does not need to be explained, though, and is best done silently. If a user wishes to make note of their reason for inaction, the only remotely appropriate place to do so would be their profile.

Comment: _"I know the answer but I'm not telling you because of where you're from"_ <-- how is that _not_ rude? That's literal racism and bullying. I mean, you don't have to rub that into someone's face. Just don't post the answer if that makes you feel better.

Comment: This is degrading rapidly.  Do we feel this is going some place?

Comment: @StephenRauch I don't see how it's degrading. It's going exactly as it started: one guy trying to equate making a statement about their opposition to military with bigotry and another guy explaining why it's not. I've not made any insults. Just pointed out how ridiculous it is and backed that up with explanation.

Comment: @Cerbrus You need only look at how you and many others respond to the accusation in this question to see that you're wrong. You have shown no consideration for the accused commenter here, have you? Where's your kindness toward them?

Comment: Well, more like nationalism (just as with any bigotry on any basis), but the mechanism is the same, I tend to agree. That said, can we all please stop the in-fighting and remember that we are volunteers on an international platform with the goal of building up knowledge, not imposing our views on others (and that primarily includes gloating about not helping in the face of a random user), whatever it might be? Please?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine ... My answer literally says that the comment should be flagged and removed. The only people starting "infighting" are the ones who are insisting we have to treat this as bigotry, which means we'll be insulting, ostracizing, and severely punishing the commenter.

Comment: @jpmc26: There are 2 things going on here. 1: That commenter doesn't wanna help Russians. 2: That commenter is commenting to make someone feel bad for where they're from, and the actions of their dictator. 1 is _fine_. 2 is just a _blatant_ CoC violation. You can protest the country's actions without being an *** to other users.

Comment: Also, having a _single_ comment removed for harassment isn't exactly _severely punishing the commenter_. It's just a deleted comment...

Comment: @Cerbrus Marking them as a "bigot" is certainly a severe punishment, especially in the eyes of moderators.

Comment: I think you're overestimating the impact of a single deleted comment

Comment: @Cerbrus I think you're underestimating how much moderators abuse their power to target users they have deemed to be bigots.

Comment: @jpmc26: If you _really_ think that is a _real_ problem here, I'd suggest you compile your evidence and make a case on Meta (in a different question), as that's a different discussion.

Comment: @Cerbrus You're also underestimating the impact of this thread on the user's morale. Like I said, no consideration or kindness toward the commenter here.

Comment: @jpmc26 I am sorry to say that, but *because they are one*. They took it upon themselves to gloat that they know a solution but will not share it based on the *perceived nationality* of *a user* - this is bigotry. You can try to wriggle the definition with rhetorics about punishing dictatorships, but it does not make the comment less bigoted, and such things should be dealt with accordingly.

Comment: @Cerbrus Isn't assigning nefarious motives a CoC violation? How can you say that they did to make someone feel bad? It's vastly more likely they did it because they think it's important to raise awareness or because they want to motivate more Russians to oppose Putin. Obviously, that wouldn't be the best way to do so, but the point here is you're insulting this user by assuming the worst possible motive for their actions.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine See immediately above reply to Cerbrus.

Comment: _"Nanananana I'm not gonna tell you the answer I know"_ is preschool-level petty / gloating. There is no way it is not intended maliciously.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not sure you realize how ridiculous it is to equate pre-school level immaturity with actual racism, much less with the willful intention to do harm. A pre-schooler does immature things because they're *not capable* of reasoning clearly about their response, not because they actually want to hurt people.

Comment: That's.... exactly my point. The comment is childish. SO users should be mature enough not to post that kind of petty gloating messages...

Comment: @Cerbrus I didn't say they shouldn't. Obviously, since my answer says the comment should still be flagged. Perhaps your visceral reaction to what you've deemed bigotry is clouding *your* judgement and rationality here. What I did say is *you* can't go around insulting people by accusing them of willfully trying to cause harm when they almost certainly weren't.

Comment: _"visceral reaction"_? I'm just saying that telling someone they don't deserve an answer because of their nationality is bigotry... That's not visceral, that's just applying the CoC. I _can_ accuse the commenter of bigotry, just like I _can_ accuse a thief of theft.

Comment: @Cerbrus The comment doesn't say anything about what anyone deserves. That's *your* prejudice putting meaning into the commenter's words. What it does say is the user has decided they are going to take a particular action as their personal stand against war and tyranny. You don't have to agree with it, but you don't get to unilaterally decide it's motivated by any kind of bigotry.

Comment: At this point @jpmc26 I'm not sure what you are arguing about anymore...

Comment: So @jpmc26 say a Russian was in a burning building, you feel its okay to say ”I'm not helping you even though I could because your country is engaged in an unjust war with the Ukraine.” If that sounds insane, you'd be right because it is.

Comment: Simply saying nothing and also not helping would be less insane, yes? so it's not at all about the "helping" bit? I mean, running into a burning building at all is insane

Comment: @KevinB fair point, but I'd still prefer them not burning to death. Obviously, on a Q&A site the stakes aren't quite as high.

Comment: My point is, it's... not about the act of refusing service being absurd, from your point of view, it's the... seeming "need" to inform others of your opinion that isn't at all relevant to  the problem at hand, and in this case can be considered rude/abusive. You can deny service all you want without being rude, people do it every day.

Comment: @user692942 Someone being stuck in a burning building is so drastically different from needing help with a programming problem that the two simply aren't comparable. We save lives because we respect human life as intrinsically worthwhile; that is not a consideration for SO questions, or indeed any form that helping someone with general programming might take. Indeed, if we are to consider the inherent worth of life as at all relevant, it could only be used here to *defend* the comment since Russia, as a country, is actively killing Ukrainians. But I don't believe that argument is correct.

Comment: @KevinB I don't agree it's rude or abusive. It's just saying that the country is doing something horrific and that the user has decided to take a particular stand. That's why I said it should be flagged with a different flag, based solely on the fact it's not substantive content.

Answer (score -86):

I'm going to throw this up here, in the manner of spaghetti against a wall, and see what kind of reaction (i.e. voting) it gets.

As was mentioned in a comment to Dharman's answer, what the commenter did can be considered a "micro-sanction".  Personally, I don't disagree with it at all, and I'm seriously considering doing the same thing in another context.

Why should the Russian user be "held responsible"? Because he's from a state that is now and absolutely should be an international pariah. That he's not old enough to vote makes the situation less fair for him, but — just as every single last citizen of Ukraine is currently experiencing in an up-close, personal, and occasionally fatal way — life isn't always fair.

So, yes, a comment which ostracizes users based on their perceived nationality may be technically a violation of the CoC.  It might also be an eminently justifiable violation.  (It might also be no violation at all, in a hypothetical world where the CoC contained an explicit exception concerning hypothetical international intellectual sanctions against pariah nations.)

Comment: There's no need to comment it though; if you want to micro sanction users from Russia simply don't contribute to their questions. Don't hang the carrot in front of them and tell them they can't have it. There's a big difference between ignoring the content of a user and telling the user you know the answer but aren't going to provide it to them.

Comment: @Lamu But quietly declining to answer such a question has no effect at all, so it doesn't really fulfill the purpose of a sanction.  A public sanction is a form of communication: it sends a strong message about what's considered acceptable.  I could say (but I won't) that arguments *against* public sanctions are a form of communication, too, in that they could be read as signaling support for the target of the sanction.

Comment: Then put a note in your profile stating that you dont support Russia and won't be contributing to any questions from those from Russia. The comments aren't for conversation on [main] and telling a user you won't answer their questions, but know what the answer is, is at *best" politically conversational, and at worst rude.

Comment: @Larnu Your points are well taken, and I suspect we will have to agree to disagree.  I would say that, at best, such comments are a positive signal of exceptional worldwide reaction to an exceptionally heinous act.  Are they disruptive and out of place, not what comments on Stack Overflow are supposed to be for?  Absolutely.  But, for better or worse, the entire world is (and must be) convulsed by the situation in Ukraine, and I don't see any reason why Stack Overflow should be an exception to that convulsion.

Comment: Should every political dispute deserve license to be injected into Stack Overflow comments?  No, of course not.  But this is, truly, an exceptional situation.

Comment: What is it that makes this situation *exceptional*? Is it the color of the skin of the people who die? If not, then what? Situations like this and worse than this happen all around the world. Just open your eyes to see them. Don't act surprised.

Comment: @forpas It is exceptional for the leader of a nuclear-armed superpower, with a seat on the UN Security council, (a leader who is, not that it matters, Caucasian) to repeatedly and defiantly say "F**k You" to the rest of the world.  What I hear people in this thread saying (and, yes, I realize I'm getting emotional about this, and that it's nowhere near this simple) is, "Yeah, that's pretty bad, but it's not bad enough for us to make an exception in the case of  the boycotter 's well-intentioned comment, even though I guess it does violate the Code of Conduct."

Comment: So... what happened to Stack Exchange's motto, "focus on the content, not the user"?

Comment: Really? Is it the first time that you see *the leader of a nuclear-armed superpower, with a seat on the UN Security council, (a leader who is, not that it matters, Caucasian) to repeatedly and defiantly say "F..k You" to the rest of the world*? Isn't this what all the leaders of a nuclear-armed superpower do? Are you that young to know or that blind to see? Or is it that selective sensitivity to what you consider exceptional?

Comment: Though I don't agree with the post, I also don't agree with the delete votes here. The fact that this is the opposite view point to the many who have visited this question doesn't make it a answer worthy of deletion; it remaining is actually probably better for the community, as people know that the community does *not* agree with this stance.

Comment: This is an atrocious take.  You could literally replace "Russia" with a race, religion, ethnicity or belief system and you'd be able to justify your attempted message in the same way.  Suffice to say, this is Stack Overflow; you're under absolutely no obligation to help anyone you don't want to, but the *instant* you decide to make a comment about why you're not doing it, you'd best believe you're subject to the CoC of the site - and yes, this is expressly forbidden.

Comment: @forpas Re _"What is it that makes this situation exceptional? Is it the color of the skin of the people who die?"_, well said. I had wondered the same thing myself. There have been many conflicts in recent years that have resulted in horrendous misery, suffering and death - far, far worse than anything that has yet occurred in Ukraine. The claim that Ukraine is an _"exceptional situation"_, and deserving of special consideration on Stack Overflow after only four days of fighting, is both offensive and objectively incorrect.

Comment: "I'm going to throw this up here, in the manner of spaghetti against a wall, and see what kind of reaction (i.e. voting) it gets." - I seriously respect that. It is exactly these kind of posts where we learn what people absolutely do not want and why. I colleague of mine said that "if it is time to share ideas to solve a problem, you might as well just say something stupid because it gets people to start talking". Similarly, it is important to say things people absolutely disagree with - because it gets them talking. People in agreement don't have much to talk about, just nod.

Comment: This is just foolish, a person as control of their profile... if those who want to place a "sanction" on answering questions gets to a point where it actually impacts the number of answers a user receives. Those user will just change their avatar or name or location AS NONE OF THAT MATTERS! this is a Q&A site you dont need to know anything personal about the asker.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks.  I did say I was just trying to gauge opinion, and yet — the *way* people have expressed their opinion here, as if there's something wrong with me for even suggesting that the answer to this question's title might be something other than an unqualified "yes", has been... disheartening.

Comment: People _do_ find it disheartening that one of SO's high-rep users (that's _not_ an appeal to your pride, by the way) would suggest that "a comment saying that somebody refuses to help due to politics and nationality" is _not_ "unfriendly or unkind", when that comment is a violation of the CoC. "Life isn't fair" is not an excuse to be rude to people, especially for something they can't help, when they're already under oppression. Your answer has a total score of -59, lots of people disagree with your answer; well, life isn't always fair .

Comment: @SteveSummit Without getting bogged down in the specifics, I think you invited and instigated the opprobrium that came your way because of the inflammatory manner in which you presented your views. Initially I (incorrectly) thought that you were deliberately trolling because your presentation was so one-eyed. Even so, I suspect your views would have been better tolerated if you hadn't insisted on needlessly tossing chum in the water at every opportunity.

Comment: "Life isn't fair so I'm going to make it even more unfair on purpose" is one of the most morally repugnant attitudes it's possible to have.

Comment: I believe it's important to adress the point someone is trying to make rather than the one he is making. I don't agree with the method but the notion of trying to inconvience the average russian citizens enough to cause action is not inherently faulty. I know many germans that due to covid restrictions got their vaccinations even though they never initially planned to do so due to xyz. So there is recent subjective evidence for me for this to work.

Problem I see here though is that this kind of inconvenience leads to defensive behaviour so it probably achieves the opposite D:

Comment: Suggestion:  Rephrasing the idea of "_holding the user responsible_".  Because the idea behind sanctions/boycotts/etc. wouldn't to hold, say, the question-asker "_responsible_" so much as to apply pressure in the direction.

Comment: Can we have an apolitical, international forum for programmers? At least be consistent in this silliness. If Western commentators outraged by Ukraine war really did so on principle, why is it we never see such calls against US, Israeli, British, French, German programmers? Please take off the mask (Like those BBC, CBS reporters did). And let SO be SO, a fraternity of programmers. Not a place to peddle Western political agenda.

Comment: @NSNoob yes, we can. Just do not use knowledge from this forum to kill people or to do other political things. Do you know if knowledge in SO is using to kill people in Ukraine or for other political things?

Comment: You're free to impose your microsanctions if you want, but the Stack Exchange network is not the platform for it if you violate its terms of usage in doing so.