# Is there an objective moderation standard regarding political messaging in user profiles?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, moderation, etiquette, code-of-conduct

As already discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267368/185593) or [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270347/should-political-possibly-offensive-content-be-allowed-in-users-profile) on bringing up politics on Stack Overflow profiles, I noted @Brad-Larson's remark on the difference between what's acceptable on profiles vs. what's acceptable in usernames and avatars:

> Avatars and usernames are visible on every post a user makes, and
> people coming here to read programming questions and answers see them.
> A user profile is something you have to make a conscious decision to
> view. Therefore, we're more strict with the former vs. the latter.

Is there any objective moderation of usernames or profiles, for regular users or elected diamond moderators, or any other objective method of controlling the contents of profiles?

For example, the quoted text below is a message in the profile of an elected moderator, with the username "Russia must remove Putin":

> ### Dear Russian People
>
> Vladimir Putin has not only invaded Ukraine, but
> he has begun an assault on the people in Ukraine's capital, Kiev
>
> [...]
>
> To prevent this from happening, **you must take to the streets or any
> channel you have the most influence with, and do everything in your
> power to contribute to the removal of Vladimir Putin.**
>
> Warmly and Sincerely,

[emphasis mine]

There doesn't seem to be any way to flag a user profile picture, username, or a user's "about info" to moderators, and it would be nice if the Stack Exchange team would consider this.

Is political messaging of this nature acceptable in a user profile? I'm asking this, because by contrast the restrictions about the "Z" letter seem much more drastic, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377241)

> we do not plan to allow statements in direct support for the
> invasion of Ukraine because they fall under the intimidation and
> harassment policy in our CoC

Where that "harassment" policy mention things about invasions, I don't really see, and this appears to be instead the political view of some of the moderators team, rather than an established policy.

Comment: Like other users, Moderators are free to change their display names.

Comment: "free" doesn't mean "everything goes". There are terms of service and the code of conduct. In tandem, they define appropriatness on the platform. Additionally, moderation policies are defined by community consensus, and the current consensus is: political statements in profiles and usernames are totally fine as long as they follow the CoC and ToS.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine so, usernames similar to yours with political messages follow the CoC and ToS?

Comment: Personally I do think moderators, at least, ought to keep their elected/identifiable name in their username when changing it, as authority figures. But that's just my personal opinion, and I'm sure many here disagree.

Comment: @TylerH well I agree with you, but I simply recognise that we don't own the site so it is not up to us to decide. If the site owners would have problems with not only changing the name but also including a political message in it... it is in their ballpark to act on it.

Comment: I would remark also such a spam like @OlegValteriswithUkraine profie "For non-monetary help: Host Ukrainians and Help Locally" with links to funding of some organizations

Comment: That isn't "spam" , @serhio . And I would certainly say there is nothing wrong with a user having links on their profile to places you can give charitable donations.

Comment: @Larnu SO, if I in my profile will link my personal account for helping funding me, it will be OK?

Comment: Yes, @serhio . Many users have links in their profiles to where you can "buy them a coffee". Others to sites where if you appreciate the time someone has taken to help you, they ask that you give a charity money, instead of "paying" them.

Comment: Let's leave the political debates out of this, please. Comments removed in what was a rapidly descending discussion

Comment: A couple of related posts on MSE: "[Are excessively long display names for political messaging allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339999/271271)" and "[Is there any official guidance on the usage of imagery containing the Russian military marking Z?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377240/271271)"

Comment: Even blurred out, I don't think the screenshot of a specific moderator's profile page should be added back after it was removed by a CM, FWIW

Comment: @Larnu, please explain your edit, what rule was broken with my picture?

Comment: Agreed, it's as good as calling out who the user is, and it's been explicitly stated that that isn't ok by a CM in a below answer; and hence why I've rolled it back.

Comment: @Larnu, what then is the subject if I can't even make an illusion on the problem?

Comment: I don't see what the issue is with including the profile page with the name of the user redacted. It's an example of the kind of content that the question is asking about, and without an example, the question is very vague and unclear. If a mod (or staff, if they want to intervene for some reason) still wants the redacted version of the profile page to not be included in the question, they can go ahead and remove it.

Comment: Oops, I rolled back at the same time that you included the text version of the profile page. That's fine as well, as an example, so I've rolled back to that instead.

Comment: @cigien, however, the name of the profile is also suggestive, because it this name that appears in the posts and comments. How could we remove the name, if the content of that name is part of the question itself

Comment: @serhio I agree. I don't have any issues even with the original version of your post. I'd be more inclined to redact identifying information if it was a regular user, but given that the username and profiles were about an elected moderator, I think it's fine. I would defer to a site mod to remove it if they felt it's inappropriate, but for some reason a staff member felt it necessary that they step in.

Answer (score 24):

Regarding the use of political speech in usernames, while we have no official policy as of now, our current guidance echoes what other commenters have stated: We moderate user names via the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and ToS to deem what is appropriate.

If you or any user has concerns regarding a username, or moderator action, you are more than welcome to report directly to Community Managers by utilizing our [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https://stackoverflow.co) link, and a Community Manager will look into the circumstances of the situation and get back to you. Hope this helps.

Comment: To add to what Bella said, [we've discussed this indirectly before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416289/2370483)

Comment: [This statement from Animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349167/13095326) and [this statement from Cesar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361488/730130) are also relevant.

Comment: so, if a user goes agains the rules, like political discussion, this one is blocked by moderators in several minutes. But when moderators broke rules, like call for presidents overthrowing, they don't even should be mentionned. And reports to Contact Us against a moderator would have any reaction or answer. I edited the OP in order do not mention the name.

Comment: @Bella_Blue, please explain what steps would be taked, if any, against the mentionned profile calling for violences on StackExchange/SO profiles. Where are the limits, if any on what can be posted on a profile on SE sites? Code of Conduct does not have references on that.

Comment: @serhio The last paragraph of Bella's answer explains what steps you should take.

Comment: @TylerH, I know what I should do, what I ask is what THEY would do

Comment: I have to say that the redaction of the user profile feels rather heavy handed. It's not like the OP posted a link to a mod's profile while asking about other actions of the mod. The username/profile *is* the point of this question, and removing it seems counter-productive, as it makes the question unclear. Also, where does it say we can't talk about mod's profile pages on Meta?

Comment: *"...it is not the place to call moderators ... out by name."* Err, what? That's *precisely* what Meta is for. This is utter nonsense, and, if true, represents a total policy shift over what I signed up for and what Meta used to be for.

Comment: How does this policy square with [this other policy you recently announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377241)? What a tangled web of contradictions that is weaved. You *do* have an official policy on the use of political speech, and, as best I can tell, there are no specific exceptions for user names. I suppose instead what you mean is that you personally agree with the call to remove Putin, so you feel that this isn't harassment or inappropriate. Unfortunately, that kind of bias isn't a policy, and it isn't sustainable.

Comment: @cigien bella and I talked about this, and we agree: the idea is that you shouldn't be making a *personal* meta post attacking somebody and turn it into harassment. Asking questions about what a specific moderator or user did is fine, and honestly, the profile being removed does make the question more unclear. I'm responding because she's in a meeting and can't be here right now.

Comment: That said, we're fine with the edits being rolled back and having things added back in to make the question clearer: as long as it doesn't turn into a personal attack/make it about a specific person rather than their actions/their profile. cc @serhio

Comment: @CodyGray having one policy on one particular subject (Z Imagery) is far from having official policy on the use of political speech. We actually don't have a comprehensive policy on political speech on profiles. We have a long history of one off-decisions on a case-by-case basis and responses on specific cases from CMs. That's not a written policy on political speech in profiles.

Comment: @CesarM Thanks for the clarification (and the edit to this answer). I've gone ahead and edited the question to clarify it (and to mention the mod's username, as that contains a political message, and is relevant to the question). I don't see the question in its current form as attacking a specific user, so it seems fine to me, but let me know if it's crossing the line in some way.

Answer (score 10):

## Just be reasonable.

Through the answers in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok), it is already clear that most forms of political communication are allowed. What usually draws a line is when that political message constitutes attacks, insults, harassment, or abuse towards a person or a group. In short, one should follow our [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). But in all damn cases, we must be reasonable and admit that decisions may not always seem consistent, because a community isn't always consistent in their stance. Expecting an objective specification for the line between what is OK and what isn't... is too much to ask.

Since a quote from Brad Larson was brought up, let me also bring a few more quotes:

> My take on it is that if the avatar is not directly insulting or attacking another, it's not for us to moderate.

> There is a fine line between what is and is not appropriate, and each case would need to be examined on its own merits

For instance, someone communicating that they "stand with Ukraine" is fine. We have had a case of someone saying "Israel is an apartheid state", and moderators from some of the Stack Exchange sites have decided that it crosses that line because it attacks the people of an entire state. Regardless, any of these cases could become a problem when pushing the political message to places other than the biography. But I digress.

Of course, this line might not always be fully clear. If you ask what about the message of this moderator, who is rallying people against Putin, I'd say it's... pretty mild? Especially when contrasted with the attacks that the person in question has committed to Ukraine and in consequence to the rest of the world.

The paradox of tolerance cannot be put out of the equation in any community, and I've yet to be convinced that we are better off suppressing these political messages against Putin. It sounds more like a slippery slope towards changing the policy against political messages altogether, which would be a mistake.

Comment: so an appeal to take on the streets and remove a president is nothing to do with violence? and it's perfectly democratic and SO programming compatible?

Comment: @serhio Again: pretty mild for someone who is unlikely to be on Stack Overflow and has contributed to substantially more atrocities in modern times.

Comment: Programming has nothing to do with the matter, here, @serhio . We aren't talking about the content of a question/answer , so "on topicness" is irrelevant. My display name has nothing to do with programming, so are you saying that isn't allowed? (Again, this is *not* me saying that any of the usernames you are highlighting *should* be allowed; I have explicitly stated I am providing no opinion on them in another comment).

Comment: " If you ask what about the message of this moderator, who is rallying people against Putin, I'd say it's... pretty mild?" - Even if it wasn't - a random stranger putting a message in their username is not going to cause people to bring out the torches and pitchforks. Not even when they have a diamond next to their name. It's all fluff, to be honest. But we have no rules about fluff in user names or user CP's, quite the contrary you have quite a bit of freedom there.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger I think the relevance about 'someone being on Stack Overflow' is about pretending to be someone else (e.g. in the case of a user using the name "Barack Obama"). The username "Vladimir Putin" isn't being used here, just calling for his removal from office. If there's a reasonable expectation that a famous person (technically a 'public figure', not necessarily famous) could be on here then you're closer to traveling into defamation territory by using their name, which is what Tim's concern was about in the linked Meta Q.

Comment: @Larnu SO is a programming Q&A. Political messages has nothing to do with the profiles on a technical ingeneering community. The profile  names appear in the subjects and in technical discussions so can irritate users asking for technical questions.

Comment: @serhio If you find a user's username to be sufficiently irritating/distracting/offensive, please flag one of their posts or comments for moderator attention and raise the issue. They _do_ take users concerns seriously, so if they consider your concern to be legitimate and serious enough, they will usually change the user's name. Just know that there _is_ a standard to meet; it's not just "flag whatever I don't like and it'll be removed".

Comment: @serhio you forget that your profile isn't just linked to [so], it's linked to the entirety of the sites within the Stack Overflow community. If the user in question is a member of [politics.se] would you therefore then say that their profile is "on topic"...? Again, "On Topicness" has *nothing* to do with it, as profiles aren't related to the site *you* consume it on.

Comment: @TylerH By the way by the way, I think there is no way to flag a user profile picture, a user name, or a user about info to moderators and it would be nice the StackExchange team to think about. It can't be removed if can't be flagged

Comment: @serhio you can raise a flag on *any* of the user's posts.

Comment: @serhio For the issue of flagging a profile, please see: "[Why is there no report flag in a profile?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368585/3773011)", "[Flag user profile](/q/285204/3773011)", "[How should I flag a user account if it has no posts to flag?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/128618/271271)", or a variety of others. You also can contact Stack Overflow, the company, by using the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact) link at the bottom of every page, which you might be more comfortable with when it's an issue with a moderator.

Comment: @Makyen there is nothing against moderators politically acting for the "good" cause, good president or party, for variety of reasons; and also there is a lot of things against users that would use a "inconvinient" president name, for different various things. Just the former has the power to block the latter, and the latter has no instruments even to flag the former... The "Contact Us" is a one direction monologue, like a black hole. You can throw something there, but rarely would obtain back something...

Comment: Just be reasonable... Not a common occurrence in politics, but the societies that manage to pull it off tend to do a lot better than those that do not.

Comment: "Just be reasonable" is like you said nothing... it has any objective meaning

Comment: _"like you said nothing"_ Says the user [trying to make a point in an unreasonable manner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421465/politics-in-usernames).

Comment: So, umm, if someone has "Stands with Russia" in their profile, it's considered fine, right?

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan Per the Stack Overflow terms of use, that in itself is fine. It would not stop people from looking at that someone funny, but that is outside the purview of what the platform is imposing. The most important part is that it does not violate the code of conduct.

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike Makes sense, thank you.