# Declined flag explanation - how to handle a user profile where one part of the "About Me" section is offensive but the rest isn't?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, offensive, custom-flags

I recently mod-flagged a post because the poster's "About Me" section included the phrase "[expletive] you Stack Overflow".

The exact flag text I used was: "User profile is offensive". I suspect that I should have been more specific about what the problem was and that the diamond who handled it may have missed that point (it was in the middle of slightly "ranty" but otherwise legitimate text), but I'm not sure. It's also possible that they just disagreed with me that that phrase made their "About Me" section offensive.

What's the appropriate thing to do here? Re-flag with a more specific explanation, or just leave it alone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with user who use abusive words in "About Me" section?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251442/how-to-deal-with-user-who-use-abusive-words-in-about-me-section) - *"However, note that the About Me page is given a lot more leeway in what constitutes 'offensive' language. Anything not outright spam or illegal generally goes. It is the one place a user can vent, within reason."*

Comment: I.e., leave alone, there's nothing wrong here.

Comment: There's a wide grey area in what does and doesn't fly in About Me's... it seems most common to live and let live unless there's something there that inches into the territory of "outright offensive". While [expletives aren't generally tolerated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233) on the site as a whole, it seems like the about me's are usually, but not always, an exception.